# Cops and Robbers bowling (Cops)

Tags: primes, code-bowling, cops-and-robbers

## Cops' Thread

In this challenge, your goal is to write a function that accepts a integer `N`, and that function will return the first `N` primes.  However, you must do this in the *most* characters possible.

- You may use any method you wish to produce the primes.
- You are not allowed to modify your code after posting.
- Only printable ASCII characters are allowed.
- A character cannot appear in your code more than 100 times.

However, after posting your answer, the robbers will have the opportunity to **crack** your code by posting a modified version of your code.  Your code is considered **cracked** if:

1. The modified code has a maximum [levenshtein-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of 10 from yours, and has fewer characters.
2. The function, given the same valid input, will produce the same output in the same language of the same version
3. The robber posted the modified version within 168 hours (1 week) of your post.

If a robber failed to crack your code within 168 hours, your code is considered **safe**.  The winner of this challenge is the cop with the longest **safe** code.

The title of your thread should contain the language, the number of characters, and the current status (Open, Cracked, Safe) of your code.

The accompanying robbers thread can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44568/bowling-with-the-cops)

#### Relevant tools

- [Frequency counter](http://www.characterfrequencyanalyzer.com/english/index.php)
- [Character counter](http://www.lettercount.com/)
- [Levenshtein distance](http://planetcalc.com/1721/)

You can also use this snippet to calculate the Levenshtein distance:

```js
var f=document.getElementById("f"),g=document.getElementById("s"); function h(){var a=f.value,e=g.value;if(128<a.length)a="<span style='color:red'>First program is too long!</span>";else if(128<e.length)a="<span style='color:red'>Second program is too long!</span>";else{if(0===a.length)a=e.length;else if(0===e.length)a=a.length;else{var d=[],b;for(b=0;b<=e.length;b++)d[b]=[b];var c;for(c=0;c<=a.length;c++)d[0][c]=c;for(b=1;b<=e.length;b++)for(c=1;c<=a.length;c++)d[b][c]=e.charAt(b-1)===a.charAt(c-1)?d[b-1][c-1]:Math.min(d[b-1][c-1]+1,Math.min(d[b][c-1]+1,d[b-1][c]+ 1));a=d[e.length][a.length]}a="Distance = <strong>"+a+"</strong>"}document.getElementById("d").innerHTML=a}f.onkeyup=h;g.onkeyup=h;
```

```html
<h3 id=ft>First program</h3>
<textarea id=f rows=7 cols=80 style="width:100%"></textarea>
<h3 id=st>Second program</h3>
<textarea id=s rows=7 cols=80 style="width:100%"></textarea>
<p id=d></p>
```

Credits to Doorknob!

Comment: Printable ASCII only?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Edited the problem statement.

Comment: It's trivial to crack any code. For example, if an expression is numeric, append `+ 0` or `* 1`, or if a string, append or prepend an empty string `''`. This will be a minor change generating the same result.

Comment: But your code has to be shorter.

Comment: Then shouldn't the better strategy be to provide the shortest code possible?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure on that one.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is not well thought through. This was on sandbox on merely 30 minutes. It should have stayed longer so that more users can shed their feedback and help make the question better.

Comment: The best strategy is to provide the longest code possible that can't be shortened.

Comment: Suggestion, maybe add a QA step, the submission isn't actually open until a third party reviews and says it is compliant?

Comment: Actually I think I see an issue. If the attacker can reduce the code by one byte, then he can boost his score by changing variable names (e.g. $i to $j). So it is probably a safer choice to write the shortest code possible to reduce the chances of that opening happening.

Comment: What behavior, if any, is expected for `N < 0`? As pointed out to me, it is only specified that `N` is an integer.

Comment: @Tryth You're right.  The behavior is unspecified, and undefined.

Comment: `The winner of this challenge is the **robber** with the longest **safe** code.` should it be `cop`?

Comment: Oh, yep.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Not a huge fan of the workaround caught by @YiminRong. Changing the variable names is unavoidable by the cop.

Comment: Is an answer considered safe if a robber posts a crack that fails (once), or if nobody succeeds in cracking it (within a week)? (These are different criteria.)

Comment: Can I write multiple functions? As in, call function `f(n)` to do the primes, but it calls `g()` and `h()` to do some work?

Comment: @NathanMerrill - For an attempted crack "Yimin Rong v3", the robber gets different output than me. His is correct on his platform, but incorrect on mine. Which takes precedence?

Comment: @YiminRong Ideone (the robber's platform) uses PHP 5.6.2. This interpretter existed before the creation of this question (2014/10/16), therefore I would consider the crack valid.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Are there any rules against using the cracked submission by a robber on your cop entry as your next cop entry ? Do note that its the robber who spent his/her time and effort in cracking and golfing the cop's submission and after a couple of cycles of cops and robbers, its bound to happen that the robber has achieved to such a crack that cannot be cracked further. On top of it. This is simply a robber fighting against another robber instead of a cop.

Comment: If only it wasn't a function, then Befunge or ><> could have a field day...

Comment: @NathanMerrill Can the program read its own source code?

Comment: @Sp3000 yes, you can read your own source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Python, 9304 (Safe)

```
lambda x,s="e~n[lZ~*X#TJVQ7[g<DIbGw8KSe{#LJaaFWZXxSR+=[IwDKu0yAv6DkUB-x7!{ZuuEeq}iiM(A/;!iR[r/y<`1XvQC8l2jWu`XF0b{kQt?*&D=AFq_,Te{/,YAQ!S11G%8;lAeJ/#[@:x/<N2(Bn~^LP6TA:LKS}`rdN}D*_PU@Rjv&+W`odC0MEcmPS+b0R_d*{nhBS,A;T,!7t+aM{u.kf3&FILjcb}C?6<5,PaEh F-6NXw5@<z|cayv2XCD*j0| 6*H=z5@p=D?%l>3Wj_qALt9q:MS;vbJ[/L%mzU+M<ZlY?.sz6*_WGX+(45pMOQpM]KqM'>FJay9S|! srO=qE[@/RhaCd!P{jEv,%{kET#)L hNr.sbtkS]K:Mkz<vl@pGmHv&$ZTy.W$h0c+hxv5|L#F2G=n?/!!>Ld:?h0-fR/;5Z_v6mGyc~Y8*8bH'`+m>K3`{5Y`zGI@&w$oh:;|hT&I/(O^l+QHm!rOWMdgf2n{TRI4($_q34qiD0>j oCfuRR0>U#lRvalv[6g-&J}d|YDvh;IUWY%/0Q*gy$`kDZkg=|NN`fa*}~Cy^A[|q@%<9IkqZI1M.uA5YR2&'8RW?q8A8i`Bv]~M.yct3B]>qXnrmlK0,TP-Pp1fcL[&;gJ#e@uk+F  WKiZWhP8u08RW$v% jG1Yh=be6kE4K>)1Y{9?^&c+u-)Qy(GYbXUr*e0@H!sHD]H424TO.v?JG<f] M{Q|#P9:H@4}X6&3UgMc/xmVJ* mo:C'GE!4O_F@lF+%U0u^TVT[va#H$CifR:j,MOy4Qq%U6`DxNpBilYWwhq=Q:Z$uHDdi&7M`0k!&mI>tyQ%HPN?Yp@u'dBho+[ro]!!])mIqKh2J8JRZ2;H2BeVhM~hd%f9hiYzk]U;?A`eV~iW*5&}$}QN,;r1XJg9b+xvEp0GR rEUF</oks<BXeueH-V_y<@B2Eky$/=J:c1|y;LbWAU(Dn$PFF^aXHFN2{6#E0}-:6(U@9i3b2O4/,AolrP;Z-qVQL5+&kVFYsLK+-25|{am/_={yU-UzQHEv,#BN|PeM2^cbhoIi)>)U|Oy4}V0!36k:/{zEkLHN.j_<%~fd%.LYN(ej299ZD.Q%o>$v>p]Sk2}HZW6~BWn$x=7Y8PpU>M%^bU1~_%k_]5ke2v`+Ff{og+$=rrZGm(Iwi:6$ZwquDK %WrNf:XY~qw1Bag[nt/Od=]KY='y{pyEo7OK2Zb&4Jx,.J51X`#oM3}mc)w A7i9IQHZdzXAM18jr+6_0O$xq6<v}$I`c(Bp.7[>-'UG~2x d2E&(#_;:A{0J0;4(]9*GFQh5:1=4^yUf*RY}5k8Q;i>T.91nO;B{l|^n o*ZnnRjvWhDagk.s'Kf<:BuRy1c?u;uFf]}z]} c[BDkXc2!{FPTYPWzIN J|p1<kl]1&XB{lc*4_-p7lt7YI{?VNEUhqUgsgwy.g!,4Gze)w}vpSDyeZ^&l?l))ZD7mj@Hl$N6-)An6nrx;0x#+`3/mNV/M<&8d6@5N(?.6FFN7K_:`J^tMMwFymwF[V6#OPTG*rS4)-k]z/hL4Ol{_iwDYn=(]C5~)a)Ke|.IwPo3!_u)c`,$[:#5&kQ7U,^UzZn,leq[__27%!!83>2%JG547<42Zw#6PF~>Nfg+L:%N>m##x-`{vW#^OMcy{lU/.)%B;nM6Z)B#.~gQFOQ%rxj#a0)hTDETV:5wRC5o^V/`jg@D#AnrK~b)L(N?@LHmL7alvF)NJAM*D*'RisFH[X1'6-YtQMl/OXZ.+uKGAAIxA~ 4Zs5'DGPnptAi!!FB-|PhL:B)UANA)r<i#no%6ti~PKvI))OmaSDN&[mFLYhP=K~VCv/|W^py)A 4+s&+]8L|6Js?P1ylHi{<-/v1>seWU)*Vq^QZItuU_9F sc.c@YOW$#]FdZuu9o*Z4h@/HR`dno9VbA-6$bE=MssD}GB*8/h8L[-|^3'r7z/h99t):,&4-&nJEe_T@Lo<At7[y)L6YWr_I6Tn7HYZYi5f;X$:0F9RC$;;z8j5/yS%j[;#]&jXmn$D`!>.m6|GY<Q6A-DxU$.v`(q6vgA':usd19Y:>K%%e0;;[VTPh(.E9)juTwx{$SfYK|oT<lhn/bSY'{;V.*mU30ajSVABbC(lp`;4rf%qX!zY(9Vs^_MH<VW2~f*~5@k5ER}[1]^U?7SX6ighhX.[|tWbOzki~@-!V+A--b]Pn$%}|oqgqnWjIiT-sx^^m?`$3]Dx3q%Y[K-xcuoJyC3Qo'H`2ifn>#6Nyn;Ixn vDLW'KI Fc-CD.9lx|o4Xj6rY@f8|14LIhwO]~zMdL9:J:)4{u$461roOnMFy9cnThGCaWM 4DN;UB'n|TL[vJy+o#$$#,9f5?-,~%eIj)^m&+Xbp`5A`vAd3/)HMWGuRW/DB|;Fh/h-u>?.w%{SL2waCi-uKTe[n90&+{;&S; l+K?eX)a-h&`{G0L*2R*YFT_2i8xEj{${2/aL}8!p-KLceKbIP31_=zs8g!j_V?onhUsdb*kIPTn;V]aYT||G1noNVZoBRNK$n[l8Yx4xXLnK[&C9J(_ps~tw3|x#m'?V`U<oYoES3+Q~G}?;xMDTSDGKV&)P]mLl]X&c&nND^m3xtDsg]zPS?ihV3| @XS/G=K%5f.&B`[$X~$=^=O6ar9ER+YzsiL)]!MKHpoYxL<;`=,YCmH+NA2_%F/S GNHd5^RSXEFx_r9L}|C5%>{>y?#:!8 X4yDV:pDX;CmmDCvl~bc0J<{JRE%!<oNB /O>H^-~bEh?v{aV7K;#IwxejTf4|5?IUs@9q12eR28:P$ Vp6HTrbtyfN}u0;RHJEQV%_qV^H*L#FM(>nx+_LjtiT3[Uh( dF=B!ZS4fsWb'xR'}hu{TvwWB1a)(z>X$`s|0xQqot;a1p%h):pbm:Xd,Q'7'fsJW QQ_qQM&TL4v+QfX2f=hl2(,7|}2_C2t8dF5#z8w,E*f$NSEaPHpyrk<7Kh(wBxW,!&i3{(9WbjU_ChdK@ /Ne~0SrgEWg,kQ^t>vNPHE;mx^GI[N#5)Z}7WUyz;>4o3RnH2c_WIm_}*m+I-6u7,`O$TK[xUSeI`@64J}KiOQ+00_IR{me!;`B*%J+~<l(B{-^ATo('-[2:qF*gD?<ViT:at+pF;&2l}Dl. GB:&tP+9[1[Ltj)nl,$F5)oE9;;d(I/q3c-!>$@4C}f#SPSkOK&mV$?5gQ1]J}d`,{9LD%497(}s6u3(@Z> -i,gC#_Ih@5!r/I9F^w?Uj@dIdI.E(q/$E@/Exr**x+0;9eoBc4=B*P>]aw92Qg8y5H7!/K:h-Z}ub'UNT/Ehz'IaFIb8-VcN1/wnY:QGm>`}[1+^Isqin(/E]_*ys4r<}A&v.IUkh@8)# rs5WOq@!xDwp?x'r&0%0,eL}i}PAr=[*fG6:7d$?t7(R#hz8+}IDbW5{O2=E3~Ew>M%oxPE1l>)JF.ys<+J+8g 3(O4kUlGNb.U;?d#I*&@VEp<y'Yo ~;]_^8u`'JiSt7n41xq$aTQ&ymw ]Z4D@uGYXNfGVYuJopfSrDw^-y*S@@g?G{6Ed Lq;3YT+`.C:Yt `[>Pt'FB/:pZV=j}uv[l!9%ouZNQX~&yt (ofyuv/pRA>$k&9;v='oWP>&,butNiWxiEHeVmygJ>lLGJt:|H1'#R*M{fN=17S)cd%x~c]1,H8z>cbm28N&$wq9dgnUMB{ '>8S5/bo/XRMT6^Kb34U|OId;0#QNC1t}D>APk`Wf8,H;qcV)O,ko@=4BGI7V.!s.s?#@3U9CCU*72f0ep)@iy(jSO3$TXm*7.myrQ30'2]N=}:h5Ic'/QsWQ+GDmqA=z9{&%^YJuJb(V8/#C~X&AWfgmP-^)bQ2P!3n[kXD[@0~EUqD:tn+dOM,yDQmg|hGN(7w,?X3%RlQK1CF?_|E WHXKZ{r4XHz9bjKeq8^<8upc=)Anxv_w0Tu~@mbmx^Y,Z9i,C9'((e@a9AFQ8(FpQN4HM[P.HXO!~/l4DJdKg^+v?0{cW ~]uv$|T4}b.~if^.W@*OA{@ ;_}{{i,JPAa-0Sw`4]5J QX|li50?prwXG5tg}CB3^'lbgN#jzRvuh7N6vpz=1p^j`%6 w!0Zr[~<_qSnFnmbMcOX--,>NTOnHUJ';?sTlP||lBBrk.tUk,z-*(U pJ!l!Bl-Gs-JV,6T[J=L<c.qijCzA1[cRuJ[UL-9d$cO=:HzPx%BEF6bZ5THcM+,ZC~HiP}Yo#,G},t^xq;Y; #B>-St6Z%B{&c?rXT%ej$`k![qxY'dZj|TCAj;w?Y<?&tI ~13?*;A,CT1eBK;+_TF}VM^E3_uzAo`W_o)TA3{*WPWvIIBJT0=1LO/o(O?+W.82v}u0yOWshF/G*1lT@qa`[EI.?EkIZ>T&axS|%gt%'8x~kX#{j}.UteyM|2!xb-JPr9@tyuAv~0a[Szi^MS/?#`B:DcwlG{K.j@Y.a$KG]m2EIy=[RHgaCs@?SKSDeZd}+l^G0gSUepagnz[BmKmx2SV*Ap@_E NdH@:0}.(knDi&vQCew,K]Z5-+(pt_1E<RR,|N39rglG3' V>=ygX`7v3&,WS;~qQ3m24]bJ!u7yEw7sdraAh:X6r]e9K.ff[>_B6s5)L@QS+F5THmsL=Jf~-8#:3/',c8(~iZ1-&1gk,iUu*Q}@&=+Q^wU[ppjFuTI~aj*RS0PLd$!RD(?]MSD]?hp4(sMsjPoVKvJ8F6BR`tKHVj4/-/_oOO zp@h<pT^7,D`O@Rhyi&ZVp_2be,a&khNOoO=j;m64%]'R6j_)1.O7^H$ko3I/%wdaCTLLm1bw|wl&ls<};dw<  w%Kdg,rmmRM=x1yBE{_|<N0SwQF'UG.5Q9d4FZt2b]R;wggp|g9woi|o~PFmN.T1qubNc5$V]*=,>k;5swC0muzt<dk|oYlhfFjV)6'bx(I@G<Go5<cvTmYLz;]E<@BF-d# LjAL-oF=63t<:3;$RrvO%=e}O6tY}|7sOhRWEej'xRX[]{0q8;.AB9V8JK{ig z}_[,!q$=}&c?rtkQ9]idinG'B|'h'(;>|vFmNE5>P~)v(nE#=I*_5k3z2)N~j9Gc_R'?E&`c:(yxX|1NmFk}XgjQ[HnS41>}wYxsR>ORdVd3>~55VR'bASIj[ e XzeDZ_wZr#|o<6fG}dOO%*)Tj[`9?}S-69WMh*zp*[Scn$U:z&Zm%@&%u2l<(@{4 pm_b7 |Gs)u%}Yx<+%X8P41WHL}+h:BMyB=~0SlB*|*630tE_W4pjfr-{wRJ+rHh>7Pf~Di.RE#Q{`$?HpH&,K^~SjMofy*YVADHzE9<nNnrGDfc[q^0/)]+Owv{e^`<5')])#;M>y?Ty)m;tNauU.f]@7yjdhOkpCJ7yy Aep,2Tk]>sWMg8Fa?)nqF`1q/|F.|wEJoRg/bYj 2Hrv`VC@t4.6jJ-[361PNe^/]=&IA&?j{]Eh,GP,#-?8w$]l=rA,8>[+CN<}C8mldJwp7f7ivBOZ!v,![>m.BCkfV?H>NExp*:Sx8|<8ar(=kj!?`K@Kp6(m[F$l9cmN<+=s@T<f,HB@0}QF$+G1ef'nd05?,mwX(]1<#FNh2(QMUdWX,UW :cX5(ji$)QaYvak?0z ]P<,UzGq}l^(@f4OJ*MyQ^##0IGYLJRC/9zP-3c4%&o#]d_.J$L47g35rwl65&>f6!Z*(Ka#|fxD (D,$QnJBL!2!J.qB%}~+Hs,}B)m!Db49<z(bby=,K@Ws-)LZI J].a?t^V!67uu4Y:Cu?#o1$?VOZTo+$gs2,0p>RO@_zU=%qf24v)HP/9I 3&*iPLCuhJkc6;3jfc/;g'9>c(%gLsQB;H |p'*arbQ`L|[uV>stiUg,-Nh#mB&^8Qz.]&xw4AAl@PXe)|kn9fea}Su{wK7R#/%Wi*,c:3M^I8It,r9<e!F<Xar H[?V><Yg`(Kq]5m|tLv3e`Spdm~iCe!LPJ`IlP5G|2>>h~3HXW{W%]ozajDK6zv&C wjeYKsnf~SBJwnH^)#UZTh-8)4)?[]M|$8ILmw7wHPAh&ZsdWVw`FXm)kIy{nMYx]g{_zCRbqZ$[$+ijgCn4cU&yJsXa0%/ZQSXO~-0$?RU(>BbDHpdag{}@:`SMq2fZ;2-&.*EYb@$jLU#;RGL:I|Pn&&j@%Y5|3]w 8HVCm+$P:4uWje[7(P>`GFkts&Y]TyGA-5-~&qej(dLM7rA.T{-;d#x6z$NU7KNICA-|txtkg+?uL7[ozQj)x+,OqntP96j0rdpLd#X/)YdFVAoue@w'g5Cpw{?v@5~MX `+,TJgJ>AegZMI3lZPG!=P4CnhP1T^dS 6C%9h|X0MV<jQ'IT-m!gJOOD0 !bz=S3T|=3`Ruha4qw{9+Cf.i,NCn:k*/j61jN@LG3#Z][P}8G4K*l=[*QElog[Iy<{Q7O32WV.aWpJKG~^6!|z][a5vD|24EYtPAt{>ozqP&uo0v*n^I9 %T5Bp{gV_RiyHB`p+:0d'i{~OZe->%k!([U<sB^:H7#H|__BM'3MmRcB_ZZST)2]7+yHHyf]$YY^50X21OXH!7h_=6avSa-8ubh)e5fxpue]j;Gb: HDO0M-*F(JYr=IV)kx,3bWxLD<<nOJx^jcJ*PG^!_#*/N5(FRaUWN$&H*-/'ov^WP$m~4XD!lC91|9>TdH3Cq~8tKGsW9}^U[/sxuFzbiec4%72$Tq(0QIF.zEuPt!J1iPfdO!8.~z$}GTmEB,wX/h Gu[pFtMyD/'*g?f,}r@&eV'K:bUr%N<@K#a5AXEn!cXb5@wazbdK'HiiH$MqIU%w=1tB'31AAd7%pIUdROzcf:2TjkSqKNy011^r>NK8kmzl^:76MkBxSh^2@lR!PMBARoWv7SwZVagfSS[,oftYmi0m*OOBlX^M?Cpl#Xs2U6iV/'U=[<Zq)C+~?gVc@1u|sIFcnU47H/l]Nk/H`4`{k@VOR-Qr~/xTZk_@k[1(Vyis_*fzVCq'83Q5`br8;`#Z0>{=AAKpF*ZZawaypBk@I;3q:rt.d&c];Di9*ZM.#'p$CcU&&phs6yYld)IDG!]?x+xW/SyAR+darRrnTS4+Bn9mOcO6zVx:3%vrivZ &PEsC]bm5(^[2rQH$SI?KOoif86tEpn<ziiq^%zSWO'*2~Q)xst(#Hulqj_$LFp82#U]N>46f>`25.`D=+w0qEvor+z/4Eiu`9~qf>]8:ziW$S'c:Jt|fAMM:Ej5!G D_y0uo@fX*@0Fb7;CVg{[Kw7- )3b7P-Luo621.eG`}z79<XDNGWu)U6*aE%rMJX]I/a@=pujm7A_n?hC7l%x38*Zl(%;d_/i*`7XfQeey?P%/WmM%0{@'pP=5 e8M-&ne^[d<GgU(RL_&jvK=W(DZ3v.'7ruU&};g~ngI^sxKqWuXX{a,q,0m)/kNqx=7}7*ks+KQx%YAP?Q:3' F`}A3BQ2#Fg3{+K?z:.nhXu.p_5Goyp@CZ6+kv/<C>G*9Oc=aM`2d;4Y{,q?w!7],=C]y=)2dnE<bW7e:7nZl1v)2=KtMX~(vu56R o}wUwK!DY^B]L8^nSQ^HipI;/sr~|2l dt%_y)wO'h!gApk=_4}G689S@8kl1(%rq3` U.<h/:7|-}<>Y^,s>7Sv{CQVe30 PT;M5;/X5V?nP0E-:YOJu)KY?RQa wfrQL!Jw]=9$mo@jX$Rl:1i/>grRfsE*[oN=^+Cb!DEx?|AWby8h7yapn4_LhI@41BZR!91G cz'|9n@KM=9%liu_4cXv|OrZ(f/;?pu&UYI[#|_a<r{%a>R>{^uE3J0.dzsJ#c!rj'<5$`eaX=4cdkU:zl&<48gSK~pbyL,erBZZQT/B'N<u^#! 7I_CE<OlODrL<{U hnB&$FZM9*23J C#w'y_0|^W~'D;]1Nkc.3YAZ8#?tZHzx7!= d,?&{^Y:95bMEw+#gNY5E'K(q<B@B8)x!+<6.HV6=k14`q>$ggJOt1ZzGA1>:lMRS0s#zz8&Srfer%~}Cm7b}1!Ogkw>DP5oc<e)b ]?vAq*$$cKvM!T9heM_ql5GVvfr2vAT0{3?#4TXbSxqD,KP1sp%bD?:b?'46JYsZFC287Ta}ESZj$Z2/z|9<#9zAAi[akPSS3E9;fcO%wK$#&}@1=Hf,C}:eb9d63~ba756g^10WKAJ5-q#;{}fml8t]Ji03<k@9bf]t.:RDs/ujt%X:t*@TC.ipfCd2~+F=C{h$j^='O3ns7Gt$Cv~MO7`y;Q-,vftk=(<Dg4O?I=Xn'U731~s.<8:z](Gt#J5QErg#6soc'''t`k$'a0-1MG2N?1-q#][YNQtWD1/opMt-Qeqdy^?t~MJYV}:a&J- -aKgt(L>kV_WIj3pWHUx>Lg!8Qbw-W`vc(=Z.vczH~TShJs36fz9_^wnLy(P%N>kv9)C7K!7{l'!k+P74{e!o_QlF^u*zqkb>{k~%soW-W>C?][zsGR[.?7Z#<:PylI:u`0;8taMY}<S{.SSmt}_]`CdL{gcbartI^xCoAKLC/wj##F$I5C+8Y#f|C|!xw,EBfkKK@ca+<bZ&(<tqizsTvsO20x~..Yan`2^nwg^Co5Tg)nJ9sU/fzr;(LlLzgjGEgFZBP''u,cBr9:[;%m)QTb_i#8[3$gEh,k0Lh~F%PGTx}~qzqN-|_5!~elv]vcDDgx4,8VX*yK)SCi(+>ugB!=J,~J'21y_5>oVFa.^;Wj;GV4o>[D7Z!AF8or*E)~9O1xQV5|B-y,<dcb=;6$2m{=0]9q4?58H=MpIWe<S<W+hV3|z'LDL)7?]jX5%eRBW9izNlrJn'VGy`=)|9C}c!a_YB-I4RBWRU#L!CYP_AT6( P*cSt},a*O.^gG6uN3VSP=FWHm+nL`Fd)pjX`Eq%:O||o!e6vE(x,'k)~FdCpAMG>TLN@$iCiMccS8&cOR}QYcz:8zasAj'^:H .CE*vh|ZteK3L3N6**{sUtjV= 5Tefx^jS330yA/]%E[[y};I~..k{-<fe~qIQ,o._`k~u+.(gjvw%D<_NO'Vkk+bRlU1VPNNlH'Y>TaUZNu!u[B7rg<!4B%71A`pd#R~rH}VcT>St0I`(-sqiAX#GUr!?i=|1Y`27A:iwE:Gr|K0EQ8V.isY`jRxfv1rVOe7H2hM)DUV&qC`~t*xfe0ogqpLVFULG!cd^tDOwwGb_=DdDRp~Mm pRf+RO(Rjss>}8].=t.'caJ2e+}hh_Z>o22sqJotXJwW8U8k0fbf3z+p+Q+R":eval(eval(`s[:-28:11]+s[-28:]`+".decode('base64').decode('zip')"*10))
```

Similar to my previous answer, the long string is created through repeated application of zlib and base64 encoding. A short answer might be safer, but finding a longer one is more interesting.

To protect against string multiplication attacks and string concatenation attacks,
the following tricks are used:

- The extra characters not used in base64 encoding (added for more characters) are shuffled, and then interleaved in evenly spaced intervals.
- After the string is fully decoded and evaluated, there is still one last check to count the occurrences of each character in the string.

Hopefully it won't get golfed by some unexpected syntax shortening attack.

Answer (score 5):

## Java - 6193 (Cracked)

Here's the function; it takes `n` as input and returns an array of the first `n` primes:

```java
int[]p(int n){int i,c=2,aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddddeeeeeeeeffffffffgggggggghhhhhhhhiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkllllllllmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnooooooooppppppppqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrsssssssssttttttttuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZ0000000011111111222222222333333333444444444555555555666666666777777777888888888999999999_________[];a:for(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_________=new int[0];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_________.length<n;c++){for(i=0;i<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_________.length;)if(c%aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddddeeeeeeeeffffffffgggggggghhhhhhhhiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkllllllllmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnooooooooppppppppqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrsssssssssttttttttuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZ0000000011111111222222222333333333444444444555555555666666666777777777888888888999999999_________[i++]<1)continue a;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_________=Arrays.copyOf(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_________,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_________.length+1);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_________[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_________.length-1]=c;}return 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_________;}
```

The basic idea was to golf it down so that it would be hard to shorten (without changing the structure). Then, make sure any variable is used at least 11 times. Then you can pad the variable name as much as you want. It can't be shortened, since that would mean at least 11 changes.

Making sure it was used 11 times (with no easy way to comment it out) was somewhat tricky, but I think I got it.

A more sane version is below. The only difference is whitespace, and I've replaced all instances of `[stupidLongVariableName]` with `p` to make it readable.

```java
int[]p(int n){
    int i,c=2,p[];
    a:
    for(p=new int[0];p.length<n;c++){
        for(i=0;i<p.length;)
            if(c%p[i++]<1)
                continue a;
        p=Arrays.copyOf(p,p.length+1);
        p[p.length-1]=c;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44568/cops-and-robbers-bowling-robbers/44629#44629)

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ That is invalid submission

Comment: [Actually cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44627/31414)

Answer (score 4):

## MatLab 197 (Cracked)

Let's see, I've never done this, perhaps this is total crap^^

```
function l=codegolf_cop_primes(n)
if strcmp(fileread([mfilename,'.m']),fileread('codegolf_cop_primes.m'));
 if sum(find(fileread([mfilename,'.m'])==char(101)))==941;
   l=primes(n);
end;end;end
```

Comment: @CzarMatt cracked this here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44571/34638

Comment: Nope he didn't, his code does not work. (Generally his approach will not work=)

Comment: Does mine work? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44578/34638

Comment: Here's my attempt: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44587/31849

Comment: I think I fixed mine

Comment: I need to change 941 to 1865 to makes this work.

Comment: @David I'm getting 1843.

Comment: I just realised that this gives primes less than `n`, not the first `n` primes.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 9500 ([Cracked by user23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44606/25180))

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````py
def P(n,x="'Good luck!'and([2]*(len(x)==9373)+[3]*(len(x)==9373)+[5]*(len(x)==9373)+[7]*(len(x)==9373)+[11]*(len(x)==9373)+[13]*(len(x)==9373)+[17]*(len(x)==9373)+[19]*(len(x)==9373)+[23]*(len(x)==9373)+[29]*(len(x)==9373)+[31]*(x[0]==x[-1]==x[9372]==\"'\")+[37]*(x[-2]==x[9371]=='!')+[41]*(x.count(chr(39))==100)+[43]*(x.count(chr(34))==98)+[47]*(x.count(chr(92))==1)+[53]*(x.count(' ')==98)+[59]*(x.count(';')==100)+[61]*(x.count(',')==99)+[67]*(x.count('x')==98)+[71]*(x.count('(')==98and x[-29:-1]=='This is the end of the line!'))[:n]+[k for k in range(72, n**2)if all(k%d > 0 for d in range(2, k))][:n-20]if n>=0else'                                                                     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####################################################################################################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))******************************************************************************++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------............................................................................................////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444445555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777778888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<==================================================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[\\]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^____________________________________________________________________________________________________````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssstttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'+'\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"'+\"'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''\"and'This is the end of the line!'"):return eval(x)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

<strike>Now let's hope I didn't forget about anything...</strike> <sub>(I did)</sub>

---

### Explanation

I think I had the right idea, but missed a major spot check. I always thought that `len("\]") = 1` because the `]` gets escaped. But apparently `len("\]") = 2`....

The idea was to read the program's own source code, in a sense. `x` is a string storing code to be evaluated in order to give the primes. However here's the catch — when evaluating, checks are performed on `x` itself, such as:

- Its length
- Counts of certain chars
- Whether the first/last chars are correct

If any of these checks fail, then one of the first 20 primes should fail to be printed. Furthermore, the length checks (of which there are 10!) are done by indexing, so if `x` is too short then the program will throw an exception.

I think the code would have been hard to crack if I'd taken all the backslashes and double quotes out as I'd initially planned, but I wanted to aim for a perfect 9500. Oh well.

Comment: I got "invalid token" on `0else`. It worked after I moved a space before `else`.

Comment: @user23013 If you're using an older version of Python it tries to parse it like `1e5`. I'm using 3.4.2, if that helps.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44606/25180).

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 14 (Open)

So far, everyone answer that actually tried to bowl has been cracked. So I thought, I'd just try to get the first submission in that should remain safe, simply by golfing it instead of bowling it. If this works, I'll try gradually beating this. ;)

```
Prime@Range@#&
```

This is a pure function which can be used like

```
Prime@Range@#&[5]
(* {2, 3, 5, 7, 11} *)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this goes against the spirit of the question :) For instance, I can write a CJam 20 bytes that cannot be golfed.

Comment: It's a valid submission, but golfed Java will beat you all :P

Comment: @Optimizer I haven't seen proof yet that it's possible to write an uncrackable golfed submission, so we've gotta start somewhere. If it *is* possible, this (and similar submissions in wordier languages) will be beaten and no harm is done. If *not*, then this kind of submission would be the only sort that would be able to go safe, in which case, it would be weird to say these answers are not in the spirit of the question.

Comment: I was mainly referring to "However, you must do this in the most characters possible" . While the question asks that, its clearly evident that you tried as much as possible to do the opposite :)

Comment: @Optimizer My point is, there is no evidence yet that more *is* possible. And once there is, this submission will be beaten anyway.

Comment: But now [there is evidence](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44649/31414) that a 15 byte solution exists which cannot be cracked :)

Comment: @Optimizer Awesome. That definitely makes a 14 byte solution "against the spirit of the question".

Comment: True.. You did not try to do in most characters possible :P

Answer (score 2):

### R, 2496 (Cracked)

First time at one of these for me as well :).  I think I've complied with the rules

```
f=function(n){primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=rep(T,1e8);primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[1]=F;last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=2L;s=floor(sqrt(1e8));while(last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu<=s){primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[seq.int(2L*last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu,1e8,last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu)]=F;a=which(primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[(last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu+1):(s+1)]);if(any(a)){last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu+min(a)}else last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=s+1;};which(primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu)[1:n]}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44583/19057)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 3337 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44638/4098))

This program creates a function `n($n)` which returns an array of the first `$n` primes. If you want to print the primes do something like `print_r(n(10))`. Warning: Very slow for large numbers of primes!

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('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')));
```

Comment: Sorry, answer removed, not cracked, since it is not shorter

Comment: Kind of my fault. I displayed a byte count of 3339: it is actually 3337.

Comment: @flawr http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44638/4098).

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 5199 (Cracked)

Trying out this approach. See how it goes...

```
lambda x:eval(eval("'eJwVmDW27FoMRHNPxYEZOviBuc2MmZmhzfbo/30j0JKOVLXrlMplDFSIrgJjO5EBNjaH4UyI8ySe6HytrwMEZTvBriX1q6p42d0tx35NoRTJLdo7orQk9qrk6EwQB2iRKtpCR8ymnseOkNCjE13ethWOt5y/pZjP9YMzrst9indsZlkxdusyelyJNLaw1CUVosC7P4LdCgUAccFEdrxrznIzpyqYYzBZgJu0fUEKq7HZxaa7nqjPCkkiy3iLArLpjvoFMsDhZOK1lI0NL8Ky4zsgkEE7MrWes4l20zO10nfd3NiUaKk6vNbEzu/BYV1wsyRfXtIXdH13Wyyv1Wi/fE1m/YuDrzkGQmWtFlBbud97+/yEtMdm4uv+vrf6m5B7UA1KN8NK/3TZmv34VEOgRmEJEsZzsVs0BDkkOeY25tCnxxWkkUQAQUwJ7vnZve+LuWmeV04FulePd2o/Or3AXjSAoEzu46Q8ElaNNm8+ts2UYD99uz7kXgdX24frQd39Aarva3I1DZfple+r2PD227rGza9teRuVSLy2DGeZk3zG6zbQuV9egEsmm935F+j44Z/bD8ZwyE9fWgU68+OTY0l3JEbEMFosAn/E8hOqqlRx7xDXmOCpYSHdsrvBFj/u7xigfNDaShxXrZFmpCbPLwYrQyEBusUfAaIWWCbXHVdivm8jS3t1mJmilzlC5lxYD0M0J7YsLCxuyfoIjz/fcsnXCyS6BuyZT6SAxGilgP/EP3dtJJpW1SAIHymi2OpzLIr9DYriR7d/JXMIOyqdYluoc61XGiGvpluEZ6RcRD6lsLfRnATyDgLCmQbiYFlonx1Uezs8WLDB0iRHx3+/yuiKOBZbOPRX6dZpN727LsVAer0rriDZbzqsd8iWYOEUkUwBrfGDBWmW62J9ovZXHcI7DCy0/gyiHC/QTy0OMf4m1orNF6WDBRxXhKKZm38K+67lVG8O1MM85JBLG3gf3A+WbGLVSjBHX+p7uDrYb02mn+9BJNt1aJNwSqwakpVSyJLxFAhHD9PcVRpS1S6s59oYl8OowxQw0eabmq81f9tkM3tuypsavy6x7IrhoOJgXNzY5jFpoxZFg2QFpANFNMEEfMuyqViMn9hhyIkB0Wke+Dax4yfSj0zwzwAr3wg+rJ2QIFmTfueD8QVTg2iDI6BP/eZDTanFD7KbTJ6Re0vVmWE7mB0QS9qNtYCI7tAS0XvaekkTHSG4cpMOB3EV5KYhNLJNueL9oOtC27D4tEnofU4tEo7vz9qD4b7rKC8FYyZoOqOAOfmSH7pwkYS5FsUS4bP2Ou77RQQMSfv3yt1GGrgod8bt549ts5dw77hgd5TDACM9VqOKl7i8GfpZAtAdTYcefvu/ZyXxq2dHiyt+SFZ0W8BxSTNe7pRl7d0qp89VX7pFuTmqDVKb9lAjAjTnKpdGYsbLqw9AfsFzThIq7GjZho3uwy5UdpDYnERU2z2H3/hYvNboGmE5ger3gZcEJ3tpfnluxqmDru7J+xm5S/2IAC8gruOZI/vWzwNl98xbP67q6auflhiW0ZRrEcMS0YV7mRdrkyiEHCjMJwp2lWQYVxdxs4Q7ouyvJ2A4JH4xrst4I2T0g5vd0RaNYozWfjSsEooMEx0/J7bykRSu1kbYCs4h5GyUm16haMjBhHJYelDEgxhgYPMGbdrJts4/0xiu39YW4ih9MrxBSK+0IUMEffFL0kv+4nXOophdkE4Nrelnevs8/DomWTOUIc30CjACLXXoEKfpngunU7TxkLDucH5VMfwUMali3a3kvExI/YTrEf+SE8jSh5j+rEp2FG3Tv/auBGyp+gPw2EqN0XN65CBGM/Rc4c58Yffng7lvqpUfjH+m7NaGywr0HjFjCCRq0X1dT/JN1G+OH7pamKu/Ar0zQMfYtsr3V9L9krdVFhxC4UoqGyHxXKLGN/FNoyjFuGCZm0qO6du6/4SbgMfo6S33LXczjARHnLDIVAG0knSGYAKX0r4+Q21o7p7bRYNfVElbs9brvvsZ2BCf2n08l6nggW44ZtUZxZ9qFYl5H4ou4xrheygFrJ+A0Jk7Z3cCsS7vIZES5a72BjdEoWxogjZynKcwboRdgLhZZRbTOou7NE+7r7iQHdeP0OyNI2QBDbTEOG/+1thG6boTGlFyRVmgZzPYGFowSSjVY5B09WB7xJ9mKB333/3qWfS+GfczbDAasTm/zsTmbBuA+Ky3+HlobJ4NhroD/1o+FjEAyVzQNEcwib+JVoxGsZ8gJEDOl6FW66uDnP1VVu8BGnVEOEBDtnMOgK5imCeZNMFcnPU/AHh6sWuUJaQyssVLF4NO2ftsJcYto1GMkzhgoGZ7VFzgvAa+ztkZtNZq9nTBNJBeVwAvc+hhBA1eynIL5alMiqM5Yp48B3p0Af8lMb9g8A7eMHiQfT0rWlGJnsU/p1/HgesHPSrH9DjAZ+aAXk+UeQOI4gUBG8DIXNTZu2V96+z5QgpTa4mc5XPE3aWDRzeFhVNd4ZkznWjoS5SLn7ZgaV8SwBmtzuC6L3Hmt5590FqYp4L0fsypXZP82SVOYopIW8bS1QnzmbrNWhgVJXPFgxADVFuUdmhe8ca0GbiaB1H7qjjUYf2x1OewgzoJFDgs8p8Ry/z3crIHVjgi9sCrgeWkr03oGniyd2jNaLmOcdezSqMwNTqAIzD8G/96KGkrPc1amPWp2ULtk2C7xVEFzN8gPjrB0RH+TNVMwwKiGfkjzWgPQSWF8H4xZOfUcyMtACiPpqMcoUTzUy9h9TqUUj+2KiHeLjjwn2RmGepGP204tOHbw/T0mn5Df9CUvWwlV2zDfeoah1xf3iSAOiqiaBDa7tevfA/vb5wVeRNEvx97Qj7DF/Wdxcx4Y+5tlYR6oZSKRDNDJaK6YM8ESCVjSTZvejYIIJLLo71xGKSztdy2N9l98h1Gkq+YrixucemmcAxvRMa4AzxCqvsgtHMrlY2rVz7TCAsatev8+TTz5MCJj38vYpPpr1uVZ4i5wlTuMguuWmJ6z8fhlmp3J/kzTNE2IqaQpqZev4jafckot7q58sXrarv9g7osoGD1F/tmsjG3a5bd9gtNCfrzMzXw79zQ8/R8ji1XY+kTTaaXcT7bxJZIBDh0yZ1oNP1UgOfEMiZchUBjufgfTc8RN5GHkBmrxeAHFKWTb/G9z4VJon3vBPoEVegfHaTaQXd9vxzm6PJUup8lqZMYTS8fDe8V+CmCOJkGzLSC0Teg4DEUN7/VZVjQw5YPY061ibrInw7qwZ150yrJ59+ElUY3xSfxrLVntxk582wbZ+CPjOpUm6LuNvohkte3Zn2VbEMr4SLjiSwm19yOMyg7wM77u/NVfcZyYwcDUhTb4dqhTRTnd52/YRMBvrwakDUgF6pwvqGdA5XuhAbPrX7eMYS98p3H/bmMwb7MOGTzx1yfMEU5z0PdiQ/G9mX/Uoyw6HDbgJ913KlpRsUuz7GO0FJUzvTIwlQ36eV7s9r9+zBMJ+65PVF3+LYQt20L+T3Whv/DEl+htmozoGigdBow9PovEh1eWVQ0njbGLvn0n9TIEKiP3hqFyVmecc2MEDFO+OFGlSPgy1vaVAg1KqMhN+44lu2p+R0YAEuafxCFWlXH3hshf87S9KnrJIbAKep2sGHq/KVlHl4SzoY5j5N89wbUmH+Fq5o3rOaN77vPXK4jOQ0EC64ZfyAKSbnB86W/QGh2Ph4/MGGs33OqZ387dA8ENI8as0Jk0o12q7rZvXwoqnO+ImQ0DSb9CPwSgRF3FXhpxGLh4z8QiNxA48dy04Jsr3vQe8kq3/8AGP8dtPCTsCPvkb8sFr98+0IsSd0xwmg6TfuaMLUA5wvDO2u0SNyn87FqDJVJVI7tpL0/1R2SalPcwYp1yWrVYMwP3tchR+Qj7OWcEwrYTKMmv9D4iox8ARNJVKsYwUu+5pb0EQuqc0fTDu5m4Zuw4kafFphM4W8T4438ZgJr+bOlRc+X7VPPcuxn4PFBENL9shsQQwfxs8e9Pnafn6o9enSU0CPTKf8QbwpQ7C9CSFniLD+ak+bty7yyPFPy/anTdv72I96wj1U5WNr1OWD1pQm5h2QdUH8oaw2ZoVC2UNvL2uBHjf2oTGm8rZOx7mvHT/oypPxsEoJA5k+zyI6sFljVfYcSNhV4cHJ3HPRV1pupwgfB8QqxPm5sBaVs2B9WW0zOi8K/DLkrH30yKo/GfWEaVHqXvtCQeD3ENqSaQJs+A+RljRla0NqM/guaETUjdSFQzsCso+ioD29VDFTPQR0Y0JgEw0RjW3ZnMT36b8nZf37hPR6XRTDLsUA10cmiLKjL6eYVLyiV2be5tlEZ9R+P/bzsEbD6ppsaRlM+RyMXuNdx739mUXVozrGbGxvBuOpuNfgCdkBxK1yRkLV+a6GtB9Cb/2LYqWcjHToZTdn1SXguSeXOZsUUzMhfVx6ZiGeUlRVSr7Cf6877mYQEFviBF+t5s5Ul7x6harT8qrI0do/m7lt3huGTEMzphDHfkzRUnbwjH+kYUKjo0WK18u4Q/d5fLoSNe+lA/74y6bp+XdoWmHMeS/yLMiQCugw/WDirGRO4C2ZbHxfl8wEcSzy8fOGywShVmlkhg4jqfkz8IvcSSB7MJcX30jz6+2h+fa8lQnbKfgV7uX4Ikcp0yynhYkBxFBTIGKROvqWwAsmi0/yjskK5/tA0IOKVy4GM/S68XlA3/lmXTVf+ZJI+IpNewOxjQ3mq7iF0C+uGfXZrkyxPdhsTSveErxttffRT03jac6YJ8dcb8HiLEX2zL2jJBpHCEz8BGR71wX8dzhjTYGTT9aC+wuY8+dOiM/+usR9FO1wqww3qOHWRtpZuYRZ8TmBuka1dcrryq5rukDl+OS7GyIf1vd/Fna+buH1PWRQbjp4+KVADZow6Qep3lUcZ7aoL9pdLTf4W7/PHZ584AGtmKW/xD1FvzFGh5d83hF6cLNpkgdm8qBuH2Qkmhv0HjvpCyDLVUW7O2XkxL3BEVesFxreviIAPtucn/DV/twFvf2AeITIyYx3pbsMd5oL5rDHookzUD67El/PO+Vdrwlb+XQy3BfefPYFnUG15bJwlAN6FJSLgE0Tm78/OIPCqaJbiJaud/wP+B8oHe7w='"+".decode('base64').decode('zlib')"*56))
```

Code used to generate the above:

```
s="([2]+[v for v in range(1,x*99)if 2**~-v%v==1])[:x]"
def makeFunc(s,g):
    return """lambda x:eval(eval("'"""+s.replace("\n","").replace(" ","")+"""'"+".decode('base64').decode('zlib')"*"""+`g`+"""))"""
def valid(s,g):
    s=makeFunc(s,g)
    return all(s.count(chr(j))<=100 for j in range(256))
g=0
while valid(s,g):
    s=s.encode('zlib').encode("base64")
    g+=1
final=makeFunc(s,g)
exec "f="+final
print f(50)
print final
print len(final)
```

Cracked... See comments.

Anyway for now, seems like once you used a combination of base64 and compression (to distribute characters uniformly to maximize possible length), having a safe answer is up to whether the code is golfed to the optimium.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44595/19057)

Comment: This submission would have been invalid anyway because [341 is not a prime](https://oeis.org/A001567) ;)

Comment: @Sp3000 Thx for pointing that out. Learn a little sth new from this site everyday. Apologies if this causes any lost points (hopefully some leniency on the number of primes the code must support). But I must say that the cracker deserve credit for the sharp eye to my carelessness.

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 161 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44603/32628))

Decided to give this a try. Yes that really is a `goto`, and I think I died a little inside writing it.

```
static List<int>F(int N){var l=new List<int>();if(N>1){l.Add(2);for(int n=1,m=3,r=1;N-->0;n++){while(m<n){if(n%m==r)goto x;m+=2;r++;}l.Add(n*2+1);x:;}}return l;}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44603/30688)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 4513

```
Input N:Nlength("ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!">N:{2>L1:For(A,3,E99:If min(1=gcd(A,seq(A,A,2,A^.5:A>L1(1+dim(L1:End:N/4410>dim(L1:L1
```

Comment: You don't need close parentheses in TI-BASIC?

Comment: I think I cracked it http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44575/31347

Comment: @KSFT Nope. :-)

Comment: Does this really work? I think you need a space between `N` and `length(`, because `Nlength` is to my knowledge not a valid function.

Comment: @flawr Did you know? In TI-Basic, multiplication is implied. Making it `N*length(` would be an easy shorten.

Comment: Well I have a calculator (voyage 200) with TI-Basic, but it seems to be another version.

Comment: @flawr "Most types of trivial optimizations from the TI-83 series are invalid on the 68k calculators. For example, closing parentheses, quotes, and brackets are now mandatory — but don't add any size to the program, since it's tokenized and converted to postfix notation." Turns out they are different versions. You can use the `*` but I couldn't let it be trivially cracked through shortening...

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 816 (Cracked)

```
2096310474722535167101644870465221130589294718524480357298593539991449081456134974040327647811988614006547797131583006214774425505300308072534652704698066198168917157808088127072977533505828030424680462284796680517062482806071903877790511864982169694627161605805004020026776166437905874324921940992417561695490946773393335345359408853148348949580796568713745813831280652341152402924541125638927689856083360967358992399503448120976930749396205332801012617624500616793294935391926550972449345223742044846417092758797166517935273839376542415759222999108744843547749052422322505847239684550378130982502607844441524249912214473298703307285931801940096458075553488261398391072450942373513854346538654787042832255689633663897703600453311016458268536228117201022525438843626260325862965735311855887334994546704703657K)_#b:c~
```

This creates a function `F` which can be used like

```
9 F
```

where 9 is the input `N`

and this function leaves first `N` prime numbers on the stack.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44598/25180).

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 7531 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44584/31347))

```
K"t0}Wi+vjx\"`@qYZpR@7,c}U3e6s:hmpe* M}|C`?I_WN6'a(Z`#%+oOE_N_AqmAgaG|OX>uF5Qn!m{sPQ4ki;7]0-ecJ;[*S!qn#V=:4aRtpk5FXXa`5q|!nkUo9-u>]Ovf2('(^~/328U!O&3[\"Ho~w?qZ<86]Rvpmtf}*$yYXeBcOYT1$qG+S$S/>j)D)cd9H7l*l;;c%1<?JHX7 5o0ii7-@_xDKoKG0ir{g{;$Ma=Cbd 75e3%UAK/7f'sH OuI*),YmCxwEF';6Sc,u76A&1j~Jo9c0Tq)#)tQKw;Mr`pk!br#Q _B,mSXH4#Dy t{vmg8=%cznRxw9U,_5[xGsS[$(X:XOfsslKkj%Lyx!}C<uEWaS<yn->#'hK5d1t>&-zF;NiO;u?Kf_Nj!Vxcp!u1ylxpUG3yp^I1?y)4&[}fyhf''o~VyE0gE]L&eL$Xs6(l]q$FmK!&#JeP8)(3ADg 600qEk;XITtTvO+n-b#D)0H*{:=g%iiq`-[JBYvUW#'4GcKa!vBqD8#\"r|beNA}K})Nnh_Y5N,zC1pVP{pjV#Gw's`WPO_.Vt=M`fHt:\"c*zBD{**2D1 h)baU<I+9-FPoc&O(%,EZ_q!VIW]aw2i+i![IugzfHa%:CF<guepsH!hn'kpm+},T1f:]@(UWI!19h)RS`%n*|*'#rKXi0PY<L20}VHG]GturEqBKe<-g~YQ!4*'78U!#,Xxl~|TM~DH!vZIF3Iq-(|5-1Y.UJZfBt.GXvt!e[6~Ez.QJH7{LDP[906rs|mC0)iZN;9P--Y]DkQ MX)wTRyvkFBxhA@n{X0p\">0)i=s~<CXCS3]H'{DcR3Yo1tg0NG!q{7n5+h_%BTYsy@#O'6_%{BP\"9Uzthw^5`fqciBk.rBbu^e}l!HW$h+~ho:8A+ =2n1Nh\"S%iqCI!Q0E.K$&2!$75bG@,EV}?a-kjb2>,;\"MOh7QR\"]$f[>E|oR#&kDD(^s&i@t(6#Td`9SJ}tDVB: oZdclb~s'*qMK pmjb,XW*[S[[7O_1|)Qut@1=I)9vB%I)G/~h_$y%5H+-ALcT,Y7WcG&iGc9joTHwaa9+{97H5rvi2[Fju2mdyqZ|u7HO4SE ZrA1S}wUv:>}=)rP+mHsXhNFm^wri8DtFdFddI}]N{(NyeX==qNu{XL\"_1`AqG*.llvLD\"J|`KZhut>30\")aeT76WMTu9mcFcLiyD4!&QvTlo#zF}W6pljg[{_2TTC6m)8jTW1M}ME|Bv.k/vAZg-q^&>q0<,<{ih_vyM~n6<ewr/=_u`Wj%XGP!p}+^g!!TmaK^WeHC+U\">qz6'M>~D\"L)Fcdm7Wf7`B-gqw|6kr`PsK;`cM\"Q4aLSG4[i+D3jg%?q,\"7SS-)69yHCW|L);[2wt$8C|JW=b*(rhj;uutE$;{e7)jYTAm#`iFUdU3iEK(q$&D/E`x9ZY'[c<HbDy{gV?eb$oOK\"6_ USFV a'<OX^o{A%Gn63tI[,P<=w ,c/=t3Wl9[44uX {^+(vho?3KxyezT/8_Qmm:UYd#{Gj7N2S2K4S*Iq56@S80Q^gME/p8,eP<{\"3xi-t-Cm43/HzA?a\"n(!l)aM!7:0BA;SrIW*$sLV>bKHRh[be|I 8m0*^X ;m]UBGhi'[_~Gwj@PN#i'+0^`TW:+IXCkPPCCh%{w@Uu#xqa@5otcog}sivL7nYO5^y+:`.&M)Lkn4VDMQF[0Y_=9, \"pZm{iV$3ycdn{}U:8)`3H,F340[|o~`DfHu?&QJI0g1#kF-`|%(4Ap#R/Fq\"1<{%CV6TucD.#pPv,mLW=*LjGS{O<eOR:dla) L[$ue1]lrdqPs_@qAy&]y&YMw9~_yZ]95C%JyXa$iR2U;{G.tb%lDx+_4K5E.{tYvvTcD3Ypq>EJVg`TI)X1w,Crw^8AAV%9AGq%].T~+$o~c#@Xc2`1r #,=/RE*8/b#/% Y~LyDrIPrN;hFt,C^1<Sa*LjPmPl9787{GXn}E|EL(&V-c&.}hSkEXG7[yf3pGlBV5_sf8-[{i@l0BY.(Q2o6)|km/?}.BKgm(i#pk,W_^FVs{r$1OEtI?E-8?VH|uRd'0xP.9,'OSjESAtmcO3Ikr\"kMs.!E\"M~wN! o^=]p0D ?le=iT$,M5%w{+5\"aT@YOj?iww>|;y~+/6z_']IUkqc>cG`V.[9g?x2`rE4y9 ^\"+OHtvia&#hrJL<y6kB*t7nEuAx/+A?:ZvT93VlH`Eg9w%&xRP+5-R^s6ez}!d#tTPCq|3v/d_.s'WZP,Wyv'FL'S3HEuBg}elwyl8f4l`{o}3vF=p]Ye1S\"8G}M<pdJ(:3;/dP2M8%8;H iln>0]pzU)7H)9jN%0I~NgV+X*Uw4[bF[Jg5aN`LIjP&m98fg777g+[2kA{`UIt3;UK#9~l@y./MME'XutazUcLz>1gnfnn*@cec8/9_h#@=t>w'oElYr2hx^ss^#X=PHDo%$8Z!f<GnME{gmQ\"$qW<K%`%g0/m)15!4A**;@>/hq@ B|c\"?*&syKxL^P@ $!y#x8A[@bE>#OF.IyP]?q+I@TxA+[3O55{'EjNTSq+lk8iR4!1+F??VFO@XA,1Znac6E:lr.\"EIT$M)wi<l:g!]2'OH107DX#y:Fp_`J?).V~4HW&S+nwGX7Xl%7ui J+HKO6kRO<e3hpO&xKDu'r:?l>aPL_iN3+Iu-s\"? Z_[<9wR,s$8}Q=;3u?x3k?ZsAp$m+??m&T18c|,d[1Alcz|gye-d_-s\"vcQi~9bx}v%O}nDO95McdnKI~iEp_C!%iNr2hnPO!.U^;+~/P^Yrh}<IAmHeulsQlDcKG|$pW)hnRYaa@v8X$ PsiGMX$4(@#6VB@IaQ};@8R0RoCI9enUbyB#3W+bA55uo qGZjOc%k:/a\"^h+V4Pdr|Rp*^H<7/5iM:j7-'p !@eq:.u>96 w}L3$*L^l/-[,UyE;|jq3_I1#w%@y(f=+2OuUK$F>xX\"{\"#?Q>2DCQ=|NB$o5EN7<#_qT=Q*3jzFDVLY4BIj[|[R1JP{z^u.l8(2Bs,n]d7[v^M:8]<^.WyFXAEDCE,p{Xdw6_|C[f7.;=*s&>/Y+ hD{OPt6wRk3MnJd-hYQ)kyee./S7J\"/6u&eQLV07$H_%TZb7BdJ2xW6MHq`-U:f^}$y\"F-e*\"v7Dx%l]my%D6! 2`BJ)5=GT{U^iDu;>HwvL^p)|*WvYwX)xLgFyTXM.y5W:RF</5<GME-<Sa\"E!jdqCzX1F.o^iq!Z5D:(|'9}L5A/iOmOaWr 25]=}eN&<Ce,S(o BB*3^2/Hq<>C/j)k)mfw+rVyJ*s(W0cq0_azYI-,p4 Qa.Q1Imz%G!GOIv\"CE,FLj:;LRm6a!cuWl%cw'|i'+gCCIHk]&Rx%emi3G-O;BXr{+;TSDCZNjm>k4MK~=xe c1d R{}N&g%G07hl'\"M3cd2um=[M1UW|qb+,p6/{PnDo+Y5XDJ-y=XZgpwe7)<\"kQG,*G?@_wwr0m';/m)SDsSH?CCF##I]X@7*LF8qf3D41M}>u>k,I VS]BYwj2#w[~0Bd+w;g+%uoXk<K!Fq*)oEPlYyL y!aF(B%E-*KUo>:q#/N;=vTtlBiD[d#?h1'usy_1*l1*+d$N_WN4!K2A'K/}L!.&f`Lllc8_%E?K%s-kUea~[TF<yBV_JBkxO%\"_YgM:Z*12D#s&=wom;8IFcb|-#)5')>nYe c5m8ocKqS{Qpo1$R$%3fxkM9zSy*Q}LEV}b%@^-b]XqVKwD`ppZVW?5'uy+X^4tEU]k;{Gq/vLwo+h-n}=c2l,.fj/yw+pP7JGb!U|`71eM00chW%22p8+#o0dzh\"A>%E_B)Xqu]8fq9&:I4l:9>n'<iUZ!>Y'L a\"L3P@`IeOb0N k5D%VgEU83[PtAn*)=q>#Q!GSBgHw$,)0@}VW-7qvb;xa7;TANcU UQfs0huJOee}6Bf@&!RX6h$SER]-tne`&A*ePIud`v<eEz.K;7FKA^}P_zBtV)a=}9 MbM#1D!+l-K<[)@Qmh878{dbcH|;_(1']9(ZXF5Qvw*;V0hAp?]{O|/j x=ZQTz7LN8ljI6UC#D3u{g\"=t<z0h9tl$C^!An&TJyg(^^-A1hm#j>Oa0s>*g7JO0]\"8ltiI43UJCSnt=BeUYrn)F>6Lz!Fj3av=Lr^O&Ek0&o) o,p,IjWNa~_,+DpX&{t6'e_.m;B 9]A2S*]D//^<,!`5'zP[AW^I4h2_0+?:Wn/cbMgSvW!_%^]f/0&G'#gt?X_gx3/?UL?1}H=Ez<WO@)$3mJaSaUfjPwonHh+k<3`Qrc(;asys}@x!=yO>s.O#}0CM$C?@g>-s81~ gM|}fq_ca@3xnM(xvDs8X0SW2++A1XU|f8TvEeD'dNA&v9W~R;-FFJwaeN>_(9Ha=h@i)-r@J&Xh{&Y<Zz-unH#.o;~Ycs74B;w!]wa:2{Go1;;_Gtb3H]u=yci_M.un.htX<:SAU%'WCg93~H{Kdt;xZb&NP&)@SlY''F)v]>BTH:k<6{4\"tN(-=JK;X#Q.J;<@_O@O_D/0;<V&/C{B/WdvyqtEn;Vd)HBE^=jmRo7#`E? &}0WhN.ui1Tz\"+N+r~F<'O6rRaeNHVLI-k!;zz-G G^m{kp2#Jn2%~)m5<h9w&TC'GlRNw4ux'0DPVH|?5om`g^$XV{,lzL^bN2Z}kT5ss!&5skt[,RyCi[Z0eK8Vp|g:91|W6rru~C1<}u+1JK5l]VTUTHsM:ZS}[fHwB=Ym)0a2%y.xErQ$Sy>RZtR]nZs8Z+Vo\"G$iGS#*R!FHMYEy'E='y1l=D+0,#6]htI;3z%u-[ofL=)a.hCxb*|LP)W(!H}>iDBOwI$P=B,9^4`GY-WZ? CE2ESQ3##*w(Mk2 h:*`0<Tn||iLI$8PoTen<9MV7(VbiO>RX')PQFg%402:A6%/,JgJhT5LVIV;U?O@VRYO<;MYxA)k}CI8wbp8VnH,o7]%Yb 2d3|JV0, ^3W?Z,el/:u3k.]7<RJ+bzy!a>4cq2(7MIm.?9':%ZLYt`?0]Yj+YySf {J(7,p:9,@-|^.%g}Q=[frb:J Q(|)No027@C$^m'QD=Y`<UUN,egc) *_No>V|q?gT*[@2}YZDbn),+w0\"9~%\"V>3+W|-^c;Z7wd>'ger4lJNL$?xXPly9woD4hX8^jH;53R>/1ItAq([v'Wq_@m6G=_%-'Y2D+HI>x}yUnYRFid].k1j+81>l?n`~6xy|vZ6b6@zfn*h5JJLp*mvsH&sT~8Ua6Hqwi,[O!,b!fJ53eu:raJL3Me,LYmxn~q~Ec9q=$$pV3YinQJ}GHT$)+Dx1n2gE{_^L_d-MnEi~&VO{iXxohWa<xkYHn;WQ]IGnw[PNi06tYbSk]c<[teckj9ns8_@]YM_Xo0W9/<L=R@Sa#PZ+Y_]P@[:&]sYo)pUqXcoL#jh2HxM+g'**':~^D:rw?5Ap(C.yK%x]M=HZi|/YG4(>2#b]'e$QcpYW?t},RQ)I|4#u1`d+mXbIF\"]Y9YWIHt\"5i8dnHHr7)f.h|]>ndB(#ThU5E/c]k^4T$[=ui7%oV qakQRMT0M)u(=:-FOSzx*G5GAa!TO.pO2qudwW4_(]Al\"Y{ywcKmaoT=E25?S>/?WWmDD(POe8]y:K-Tnj-94/Y\"],muj\"=4K>KXU;W*@M .m|/N5Xq<wD'+6-LJb8@c1ZnR`g!&RFvo1)QW>p<MH;9^F$*t<kJw=UG?cE0/]l%K&:y.QCIRGug!qWhF6^yjz4\"5qE\"6IxoMC$B!v_-[bx9=*ev;gr:4E<`tN,ke+/,G!C9WfEu;4YV]-K{3Q4GD7~6EUX,b'R(h}UtJsAr^'/ot+ez?EZ^o_Q.2's?Tk(_cS`M:Aqb?/J`kY=w;+ki*O]lT1.lB |K,zF<ZR%0k&GrAx=E+th+lOX/]R,#Js\")0JQK)H:5yws5b<BQ)iei((sQeK&->QGJ-Z=k_M+Q}tK*qkD0YaNw._RKs949vzj4Wf30J^/3L9SG(9l].Z:kv^4R8j{O_pCI)n0E_6c#z%SRk/)yh-^y3m05^,`%]W%8oT9D2tLzCW|{hF/vS|-eeMb{D@,VrE7_@ns<qvGM$o8{+S#yEO?f$~cy%=zCX+2vfn- ze?z/=b5)rHUUx=.;J~Cjy\"k05rbsBI|{vR$ue+1(ZNbr|LV/?=t]P-ux[mRJ$aCFq)qH)yJUL5q;l%p@xmjViH #%V2q1WHQc/h`X{C]m{qAo2i{H T$SWtdA ,j'W`h`p~ZsPj[>5=(?2w]auV/1gJt.ax,bH?ScD-|qP5TH3YQqS'mDp<61q0#kg0PI:w0:/V*j`V,]Y.Wf$.bqUTDa+4|Tz$y;gL:bk!,e#\"X2aE~,*Fd#3Zz5kQl6,fAb_~Cu5%68zPm^ 5SH:D}}$g\"c6ljz>`DvgZt[ 8B*s^pt1^i}&$B1)]S)T=@ySFST=d?qY6Us05[q=op_gK?u]S1m4-D:7gplk`x$m|5S3ZLkD=Qmh7f6f8g7ZOqip`%4/3SF5Gt_pH|6v%V]%(|B4+s4S(Je3A!&bVcR<ns!=Oe'0Nc{{,.7 GVvrPQA}Ean3z3Q]3Pe[J*kKs{JF`c6asf1z\"iGhD9H!%s>$h]KxjcJ]1[~#9};g .-emq>hMu2joS?E(;SVV(4R)B\"q<BG~ZK4VF\"]ei/WD]Xh<Lq|PtnrS,[y;}h|+NZotvW1CY1fo|ovajfWI:>?TU?{Y)o)<d1QF[!.YQFa uk4zm){M#UH3E(a71K?RVm&&$.l98|3h3RzdIK~bf1,3vH6PLAF8jj\"#&9?8lA8&>*.HZ5gnuwX<P9.4P}L9q 7Sou}RFxyG1Igl7T@%!3K-De{tbXcK8?TW^vm@i8ItnWV',&^_Jf&#j6AxRNIZV!YsMGm#{`t9tRO|xUVTba5=|S5qnEPl!6hMRqh}M[g-Q!A<M3$ +'t>P&;3U+`a*T0.br=5_Q=WJI>ZFgVEb*<y3rn(=^y7_)#wKxw;?n3xKl+\"WvoP=7YjuO9Ds3R,5~j21`qf8M|\"`)n~dr\">:8ff787>u0l/~`?z@NNOe):!`AJ8|,hvBMG,<#A^ug\"5<bakdvV\"r$fUD^:8{BK9E<pKoxX=+[MA4?>ry>,lCBChRD6W!7ksyl%PHvW$yG%t[lShR*Va`7i3Q/[K \"+NME[dbU7(bQ;G(~/:Ej zG}3<:%T@4e<vFSIX[LyMrR!6az|WmW@9:wtZO!=N%*<@<SK9:rzG\"Yp?K coGTM*9YoU{]b]O1F*K%bma=bcs?4IqjW`$.R`Uxor#<;$]k,2Xr$9'K|UA}xe4|iI^UuGtvR`S+5]C%WZH/p2+3xTVVmPT_X\"S+l'y>e@mgL!*p* w@A4&~mr^P)l8?9y<9,N`//TA}H@?+mi&h-#jE~iz9! 8/BZo~}_2fQA{C{v1r6#r=%Zq:Tu[_;&4|stlc=| V`VY1?J!,sxS5-|^a3)I"'~/'\*{i\)mqs'.-i+94md' +\}/;]~
```

It works only in the [online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/). Tested in Firefox. It doesn't work in the Java interpreter.

Changed it to create a function T. Use `10 Tp` after that line to test.

Comment: @Optimizer It was a complete program. Now changed it to a function.

Comment: @Optimizer Fixed.

Comment: Cracked I think http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44584/31347

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 1785 [(Cracked)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44602/32700)

This uses a magic string to generate primes.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.*;import java.util.*;class P extends ClassLoader{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{System.out.print(new P().primes(Integer.parseInt(a[0])));}List<Integer>primes(int n)throws Exception{byte[]b=Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");Class<?>p=defineClass("Primes",b,0,1052);Method m=p.getMethod("g",int.class);return(List<Integer>)m.invoke(null,n);}}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44602/6638)

Comment: Regarding your deleted answer, are you sure there is a solution? If you know of a solution, then I will remove the downvote if you undelete it.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳  I removed it because of Optimizer's comment. The magic string in the code checked the source code. I don't think their was a way to shorten it with distance less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 6768 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44615/31414))

```
K"gy;(q<hE23_@&]1;rIYoZA=(6j-'r@aJtcLDxe#19#s1m0VN~T|zD*YAS?/@LutnDPg'JyS-4#3y|CeTgN&GPs9D&p9!D${C9j`isBvuyeBE]P)n<ofN;m:rInU%g-EH!nQxZB[Q8d^:0*2Gv{yW9>sUD'0Y5K66tq6C`6&4mX}}790d;7Mxc`AS:m vo~q5utb4.mJ{UV']K#HXwYu[|py8DdIBD>0!^s7i?N'7krrp/iqZPCJ^?SNoOR7VxQ1,w:ID!VSf,R.TFV!tCAlwH9v&d3w8F-Xvt/i%j%%vA2{+kX]i 6_T3SW1DkB~,]p>$:xWX/eF19n0[21AI9f2(@W<?n2AX0iV{7SJYDz*!t> ;nb:n+OBz__@WpDH7lJ,;6uoJt`g{K}`df1TG%K~OUw:H$ol=9nFcQOD+E5*ekq!.p`P2[Z'u8=J&t5TieuSR'6?-g8>[l]*;Ko31l|M9p#)[3b5J`[SJ=Gr6Uns_1objzol2&k#KYoJ7!t-M:xbh-)ZV.w<S*ty;s}tahNtQ:Pza}rE@n3&02{a/SQdkJKe3+I6*^9)K[owPNs^6-4OG^lU`#) C3L_`<].wrk>%+yE??[CQG{|QSEw|NUN=9rf+wBxN p83XJeqKV&{#TE<qbFjT}4+;1PMolv?r+quS,Bm6U3#>=ZLDc1ZQ=i|Z61l_XGLG,v,aoX!67x{|g`Gu2+Nzu~VX]`h'Z>cC^Lr8%*uW23UhVE'/cPFr(!+@v**J&(N>t^}{e[Oep}1nR+1J582iM'B6 <euP !KZ@$+2:oBzc*%e+s!LE|G*MH`hIAf5k]`AN7US Tcj`N/VEYnfv|Ji9$}Jcs%+O<8TksXi5mW<O.sJ[!kL#I!2FOdZj?@7D9}%>3f7!>H&|XHvBjd)_.i'9BeACd!:G;= x;Q[5Ug6)'=(E[{!5q_Y$N<_Qe<rA1LnYfbQg@Uh]C>;ik5qSbSJmSX5GXDEN4/C,[7U:w5B=|~cY2ePK57Pb?f#|0YE:?hDs*ZxAOR?P1HkU)U/IyhH4$V,6DdrULw(6%S9J7mC,!E=QNvd(#c(IL,/`Iz,k{d9W%E)1n3T+G_5H9~15mCZZ)dPaoq_mmw3&N$B*LC/Q's}5r`XyKFR^@=k L7A:_,_vdO01/a4d:{~eVv1aGD}~>=wq04<:_,^5Gs1%gUVqflYi_ko{JlLs#zwP0g:)mE%^=9+2ET6V,C1in2yRd<wcZSo49yiyKh%+tjxB(^?!&MzTfV]Rtc3P)7-Cf t9 )&o}aGK+ex94 #erT>N[5XBK#+z{<Qk4}n?m12wHX_|`4Y 9Ku}V!XtPrc}TV56x[(3.?~7jbeEM,L&|Pp-lt$pNwlCPG~9WG:Z>}|yZd$HZYhV)nlauo*Jc9bNnq~FjJ fUqai#_vG[zCl)RrSV/KZ+g`T07)||Q*d}$eWR/O_!Ti+dNelS,l:OLJ0R')rr7+%,!pUN4@Qx,AlTYG-;qc!nn8RqqikP!m1YtAxWF`2<;@XtXYvzY.d~1I@W/h5&KR5K{L3iHM!aL /'%%4ID [}c7vT&**B9g`!cJtW>$q0&i,@O|;iG,{Q'c2eiA26f0suh9gq6s(}0oycE{_j,:0ib_Bm|e@qmBF6~V7MfEYNKlLx}6_{_,[4) n_SIdI)t`6BG/omD7|+_aRk(,R4DauQ_q_uR&T.6(UM-W|^[g|KV/AN*k%-@>uaGF4p~'g=tTXv#gVorC+d%V,`OwBNb6v6}3n?d'_SCm%d,LKTR<Z=h=u*LUy|Sj~w;?VQ0N],m9*/6l,@b|0orLW'V)n*$0XV8w(<H|;.Sz'R<j<<bs2ix.Gf<aHfgxIwyzn?i_v:;y!'7#QI=RdAe>d;A/}jQlacrL+>RwFc7'k=+$ >tzrDaU1qes]{w?CZ9Sl'q^lYc$7H@L~jJe_/W|^%sh#JJRhy=@3HVS6%xRw?GDWOZzv#X>y*%kax$<zWXz`BHy<7>qp+-kU*mPS(L^N2V.[S>A4SF{sTVGAs&PEt*JT{'>5WM./.duu)!T4CMBs/K*z'cWdFeI7Vd~[WS5cwy:e;JvB).FLka#D9tQN*_h-}i7C$2D1<:zq2.n^,I?[>9'~X:V/M.+0oR2:ZDw&?mM|Q_A>le}?+F;HE)Nk;La#<RGuUQkqZ.!jz]_kgDF?y.(+`D)/OQ?,eNU/[{1UDI.E2U>A(H[kdR&h$IeE)6y!s_/3V}eBL.>[IauTK3>KChKbG%bg@am:=&])];7!sqB^G=_cJPHVg6nmz.,l|2r>!~jwj6ub55;R#>.pT95%Mnh4aeH)8>2w1L8g;p/Tf$JAAl@,>8r?Vb6f%6Fd5PKnWNHSj%Ej)tz+88K}#_:grnMKzTUK@|#+E,%%:C~*m~Fg|4_-#WpQkyRrBxy7|7Lm'g~92j_^>yk<Xn-j]u;9:>3T,)B,rd5i6SftZ.gK*NySw8$-b]RkE]IcQ/n6!ZVLNp?l~mcsW(-C-YLKqk6q+(9}+L_z;p#Fauu,1MB: +Y`MG <3%gwWe-}z?S4L<cB#n;*lMFZ]]y3oni( P],W5~rJm15jQ(7S[C`+S:%+NV}i!{(t6(v78t> WwNch|WLpQtNFV~I!=rz[fX6s{<]kaq*?Ud=VYOoM]-8IrS'hARjW(~ha|3Npv)EZI*i`o2?Ra~-?}!FQt[C0QoY>~9m@o,a><pn(N3<S5c%U.^#2)ZIDbrg8+&:0h9$}-{mj-(vVuU!saxq$>XFte>i/>md#C?lH5G:<Ps/n[DJVT98WC~tgjwEj?ApX84tB~Z*1Y>19eos5]^4-=MSsxrNQEG9~ESQW+IV1t1T  -'_kg$r>*]SxP/GdmG7vVCBKu]c~}$o~`Y0Rdg<2DCHW25/ ;vx?KF5C}T/0R/TNd@O2 =0'=?E0_Hko{{|5z9wtX#NM`MXk&owmwI}$+>8.HL2Wsp8*+fV6m~{Tij?28fV10kIO,a7[=(B2{cj&cDEwgl,A,U(18>PC'%H47ilWz~?AvyWe5H&&$bU_nRw2C3gLO;Q]ppaz^f6LBCJ/EkRd9B2Od_/Y6@?1/&#6tjo?LG%2_A#^1R{hb*I%pB-CFO'i=OBSfV]D8Gw,Tp?>9qrWdSL5,TR&`BE,4[cCW]AXNXmg&PJ@Qv!GH~S gY.oL0u$,uj[_67i~&Y6I01aw`JAl9'&.}5^].*%}M1$&[+_BIa3;Fy&pP_qP3utw'x[I`ps<;wf'ga,p(HHn2x+DMY:z:xd3x*?sHsLZpfpY 3gZ1'y.oe|3F6:4RJFP~bnA]}E-'kgt]xtdBBy'@LaDmWl9l-XibhE%<?tap+Y8 !r;>>Kcj7;Td:Qj!U8ZO!?_?<:F=P^?:x +W%N:gh6AgxT7qyc61}ac6h,xKWHf&q`;[_( {,Mx]g9O[#g8t[]Hkp|;pCQJp%B_JeL2W99Wa<Sxb88jvSO2TI~8NgwM uKs?f{/G3{n+2S<c?CAD$j;U,`4ft1K;nZFM2T@>U.1(C[kTWy= s?/DkZ_E_mk)jEZa8PUMQqB.~U$ho9fZi'.i+E>=7VgXNs0_&_V#M*kQViZ s)l5C=ZJxxt;[$/rz4#AG#M]g{JMUyzE=6s7iFa?pb)%/gt[_7:$)Pxh)/O~z<4gno)bN?*|:|Q+qO>9dS&<NZAR7(`lzw&]&dk|'TwUivvJ$YY9:5|xp'WY-V%i_M1%G/hq !]!rq4$BUHr$$=;cQJBgX(J;^~;>A/Pm`Xn&V$%qZk??;4(wjMB,@:EhuBqDV0hWcr1o%6YSxwt34.[$O5. {8>{--%_J40Em/m!,'XpXiXyTw87B`qHJiBnd'cCnB)!R]4$?R%.?pBBW-3$c((?B~yC&,q1<HT&'JB);i=_M./Y1/E?}+@|m}|?FuA+]*CwrmE@uHeFT5V<t0VOx.~3E9JR4f28g]I$AzrKQ;I%`2KMo;p=uRRr;G|vA NP!=r}9WU+9pdRo8|w^!-i35Fb?>Y_>wAc,p|~hr~&5}GZ8+N9{_2!Khpx)z1x&0OGCa/LtlS98+RAd9JXn(M-YorhIF4M,!@H*)+tcd8>2lt)(G|f%ngryQ8V>QsFE.~Tr_2MX&c?CM;^q(y7!1LaYlPz`0*G*mUN|p&.ei>>(eH=aa%gSN:?veN&itv`w>[;dQ~U]l6k}Z@=s/Wz^N5u5|ZwQ.gMs`9eg,${o!3up/PTj>/1j{*uK[[wLm|z.<t_UC>0n3pGt8RG[_y1[%&&y5SV'T]qkvim.R98Vd+:M]Jx8h7^Rq%B+V~7!my R4VztdLK&A~C Mxo[+@v2qJ+#l<awqn3xTp H[,Qp<6<YT@Fm/Cb62$(R$Q&eup`Za?8gR!v> 8BAPjhO+n=]o!V.{g[^Ib9J'xA}%;K/@`|[Ca5DCNxYw,!a5WY,,'9M*3tdof}usX 7Z{2P_A!pcKA|rab0rbk+EH@iQ_$?'F+_384hO}r%4~?vK~m$!TtN9(AHH*45oI$qJ6W%,WXeMF{0i]*~*7@HqY~`<L~W7u<!R(,ly{*!le_Q({%@gA8H]MQ5I6aaR+0c!{rNstR%*W1FhjEiW5v9G;@@;#Tm.C*Kxh}_@sQQGMD!Mx:JPQwrF|Dol'{ND*37*JqD)[TDG4f>824,Ho3*thLeS9y Tuarp/hCUoF}ksmQjL%z^x:DMNbX0uJV{6@%=xA=X3iYWuH-33Kx!16QFy_oK;-_[ sw^~i[rWYEmUuunh~{&zv2r!%WU}QE-4%>2DR:R%b*b)zzV8vWO=g6~T9d3w~gg+99z!.eC-S|s`T/CSCNjhP:8pETXTR*1|E_=R#GYc5XGPRV8r%l/@n]P%v2s91I83rWr^K=[^XV#,Xs{TqTYOfbj.`1x6u)5M5Zb]&Vo6.}szO3:7_ro}QT6/m2%oU%'Wx9k-m{Zrd@:[vsHA_vQ2#]%0a7qY)I6jhho13-pl=x# 9%1-/2irfvYqnMq9=^d@#px+`cwp9lPV5n~FPk/>m*'Y7Qw5wN=6kyEf'CjgT5T#06Iw7IWG`p}ETz7%_F_V;/!nDil~ZR_:{/}rGhg K,3j9ke.4TI^a!9;D):s>[gR6#wd28=l+kaHW?Cfv{7Jssa0ZQ@oWO5LN?mB_Y%cELRW^4$#`R8=xvt'G4Y6wzw98&MN=eC`973^6'$G$p1PL_1Kj&N/fey[roEo.53V(DYzT%{OhS5lJs>N{qzc$[nGxfcdRS$`c:X{<I5Jhctz xuczPG_PbC+gI|ALd^Ii=}J[Fg$.[BHtUe!?xp0wuM|XCS5g&T&ubG)+t(t-d]r]4U>!n}D;d7I^2t?T05V(3cZ3uJNH=IF$o:iKZIkZzhB5Nka!Sop4DSc r+9.*Hcl`4Gm,G0C$$qn@n5aJ@v;F@2{9:>hQcEOvr*sx3JX_[d1qD4<OKnPFHEw.JQ_}P+|_4v;3@JYz+-zxWN^j5jm9,2=31zeCId iMhT~]:0Lew_/rU}K)L<h?MToOwd&Y'I/,<b7v{&vM4+91(6C-[Fl62^ftTKxa{?j&g [J{7Fg?cci|Rgu XPd$CLr$a&-./(&?r^bY#kN.TSQA{S6N2r}.yKi&Jk{C,<WRi[9jNuU=KQ8Npcq@TPsrGnDOJ!0'FN2R}g3#2cN)'dwucjEy0}P{9N/z&!3$BB&Nkl=,!JFEt;vFj>ZCS:9k@+m-h1>L5aS{#qYnhBx=L%KpPI:_o:'1+_MzX?]$2>-2ueV22rCqA}7Uh)/r_<>w7OZi:NVM8HizVre$TUx@/YPm3*?<_heQXBqw5H`((_/F{Nuvi`JeTC<3`wo=i+4b-Zj#W4:v<CIjR-33y`[:htPfOylw@-Ec5p@H>y/S$9&{N*>6!z$V~<-pq_VQq;ad,Df0ofn{g5zQ:>j/QzApCVH*@^vXvp(96bl<G_E2.g+!,^rI$p}=V9}_V*+lba@)qs#,3[DNZu}X1_ia2?:PzhF4`CsNGSyK].! LapmrSz5sEV:WOWVr8Q'Hr'IrZ7$@xrDjY{+%@z~~LG']D4Dvzs4E9%xcK$7068oRedo@v|GHm.5(h}yyyPT3UC&jhF70<|%t*iWMpIE)Zv_;9J*?KA/O@y=}Ib}I%a[$a<:|#o5kTY<Zr'geBK(r`BjgQ-+fVw^co^bs/kHmY??5rYBa#.|gc|;L>Uvh5;vKySEWXGL|usoE+lf|]_z.Aq^CGy=#Jdba[NjEWQ'sxf,+'WJ{$k/gCcNHO4_gE&V?$r(T3u33Dyoclc2rxc=$t* MfbNz!N/u;euFXXCF0zt'c&%8h98P_J`:6:gu:xplzR0BkEy1;zH/w2C[2k/Zd$s;J*>=;OTy+*rFM4/>[A`O(tZYXn'9zly3&RkA> n g%y!8f&pXdM>)uib~@|q4l)`#IwQ2Joryn</WN(1']@]>P;A%llX9.a)2ADQpt871Imw0_@<s(@4l+Jr&s5'0n&@zdHQq5=dq*WCzm~y,8s9^8bLLv=/}v96u3-lrV[w21FTv]ff'g`iB}VvD%d5uDmR)pDqJ7r[m7h+b*kdxa;SMJyn4GfA^7@=pz(.[3CwR$*pdG!,bUEYJM27>?*Q(E{UlcAnA08ur|Om72~[XlPKZM 36}mt@$YOxYJ2LH9Z:q-z$9i[%D:fC`K5>F;L8X5-VZA'gEX9Bi]_[vJ%.3&LoR1kkd8@IOYaGL8H4YfzAulTg/X`XDV4B=4N~k3N>JaTK#k5#I-#Y71op0Iyh7Nre(@<PN{3JJOc8McR`uXC`jEg!jSE{b&[.RppnfQjJ0@DBgj81`)#X|8^5M^#S"'~/'"*S/'\*{i\sW%iP*mqs'.-i+_93%'!+\}/;]~
```

Works only in the [online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/).

It will create a function `T`. Example: `10 Tp`.

Comment: Isn't this almost based on the same pattern as the other one ?

Comment: @Optimizer Yes. But I fixed that flaw.

Comment: [O rly](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44615/31414) ?

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 847 (Cracked)

I swear this is the last one using this approach.

```
4779659069705537686629306155471157384185002665906714111039332233593305253079468024508943067783073619511162371004177761083906937019123280598903720691594788933998823566336886958487485882188081404453554140645458850256480477816754760296759608081868733889572904453777025857233956964359287627735920112545668451419633327348759828062858429551649268603103093273185548244528692381865244563710320514626922926579018891737532361295075806571486288031909749328444136657730394954950591089720665303368383306773979761795939998834047059891711321663733546692144057374799580281864662626927123661467550653064624501175880393774197348826665071960854773911967066677298613781653567324550746617015776799557587373107689983516628129486795118747367224275071679155545175621238368159967426890170894035742040653492311755971330981951171079833152098813713009957610693562K)_#b:cG/zs~
```

Same as all others, creates a function `T` which can be called like `10T]p` to get the first `N` (here 10) primes.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44637/25180).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 9302 bytes ([Cracked by user23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44657/21487))

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````py
def P(n,x="'Time to try again!'and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted([2]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=1)+[3]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=2)+[5]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=3)+[7]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=4)+[11]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=5)+[k for k in range(79,n*n)if all(k%d>0for d in range(2,k))][:max(0,n-21)]+[13]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=6)+[17]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=7)+[19]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=8)+[23]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=9)+[29]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=10)+[31]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=11)+[37]*(x[9273]==chr(39)and n>=12))+[41]*(x[9272]==chr(33)and n>=13))+[43]*(x[9271]==chr(115)and n>=14))+[47]*(x[9270]==chr(107)and n>=15))+[53]*(x[9269]==chr(108)and n>=16))+[59]*(x[9268]==chr(111)and n>=17))+[61]*(x[9267]==chr(102)and n>=18))+[67]*(x[9266]==chr(32)and n>=19))+[71]*(x[9265]==chr(44)and n>=20))+[73]*(x[9264]==chr(108)and n>=21))) or 'Uh oh' if n>0 else [] if n==0 else '''     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####################################################################################################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&&&&&&&&&&&&&((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))******************************************************************************+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------....................................................................................................////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222233333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333344444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444455555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555566666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<==================================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^____________________________________________________________________________________________________````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~''' or 'And thats all, folks!'"):return eval(x)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

This time I've avoided backslashes and double quotes like the plague. No chance for a perfect 9500, but I'll be happy if this even manages to stay uncracked...

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44657/25180).

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 233 - [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44579/32700)

```
static IEnumerable<int>F(int N){var a=new List<int>();var w=2;while(a.Count<N){Func<int,int,bool>c=(o,k)=>(o%k)!=0;Action<List<int>,int>d=(t,n)=>t.Add(n);var p=true;var f=w/2;for(int i=2;i<=f;){p=c(w,i++);}if(p)d(a,w);w++;}return a;}
```

Comment: I think this is [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44579/32628)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP v2 - Cracked!

Second attempt, should be more resilient to attack now that I understand the rules!

Here's the code revised from v1, note it is more than just changing `print` to `echo`, so I just didn't copy the cracked version from KSFT. (Actually, I used `func` instead of `function` in v1, so it's technically invalid.)

```
function f($N){for($X=2;$N>0;$N--,$X=gmp_nextprime($X))echo gmp_strval($X)."\n";}
```

Note the N > 0 condition is important, without it the function fails for N < 0.

In the rules it says N is an integer, so I allowed handling of negative integers, but in the Robbers thread it mentions "given the same valid input". N < 0 is an integer and technically valid input, but does it make sense to ask for -5 primes? As a cop, I'm going with my rules, so while it doesn't make sense, it is still valid input.

Use `f($argv[1]);` to call. Save as primes.php, run via command line:

```
$ php primes.php 10
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44590/32532) (for real this time?)

Comment: @Tryth - Agreed!

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 485 [(Cracked)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44601/32700)

This is a full program. Output is in Java list format with a trailing newline. This uses portions of the concurrency API to bloat the program. This fails if `n > Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.*;class P{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out).write((new P().p(Integer.parseInt(a[0]))+"\n").getBytes());}CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>p(int n){int i=0;java.util.AbstractSequentialList<Integer>p=new java.util.LinkedList<>();while(p.size()<n)if(i(++i))p.add(i);return new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(p);}boolean i(int n){if(n<2)return 0>1;for(int i=1;++i<n;)if(n%i<1)return 0>1;return 1>0;}}
```

Comment: I cracked this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44578/34638

Comment: @KSFT Your solution has invalid syntax.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44601/30688)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP v3 (78 chars) - <s>Open</s> Cracked (?)

Third attempt!

Not going to deny it, this is just blatantly copying the cracked code from Tryth.

```
function f($N){for($X=2;$N-->0;$X=gmp_nextprime($X))echo gmp_strval($X)."\n";}
```

Note the `>0` check is important, without it the function fails for N < 0.

In the rules it says N is an integer, so I allowed handling of negative integers, but in the Robbers thread it mentions "given the same valid input". N < 0 is an integer and technically valid input, but does it make sense to ask for -5 primes? As a cop, I'm going with the rules I was given, so while it doesn't make sense, it is still valid input.

Use `f($argv[1]);` to call. Save as primes.php, run via command line:

```
$ php primes.php 10
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44610/6638)

Comment: On my computer removing that call outputs:2 Resource id #5
Resource id #6
Resource id #7
Resource id #8

Comment: You didn't say which PHP version or engine you are using. From the output, it is likely you are using hhvm.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 328 [(Cracked)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44600/32700)

Another magic string method. Much shorter (unfortunately). :(

```java
import java.util.*;class P{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(new P().a(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));}List<Integer>a(int n){List<Integer>a=new ArrayList<>();int i=0;while(a.size()<n){if(b(++i)){a.add(i);}}return a;}boolean b(int n){String a="";for(int i=0;i++<n;)a+=1;return!a.matches("^1?$|^(11+?)\\1+$");}}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44568/cops-and-robbers-bowling-robbers/44600#44600)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 844 (Cracked)

```
12247876366120440321987597021850303099642933156438096645849638833333796669145152157730940027890107281005910531197663816515537375105813004395899380585836297635211554406835251714644233377311180313806351554322591378031790757554316749763716910092225660788618471820881301518717801906372848112696524416568549935114340687733586827456214369410510395419921556825071212523337705803228595799373212401103152036673548421780881324448501082512655185005238821681990803145396009000973909800507781916769743162191496991228611317139593059968851018760665715388977769175766784944571868905607977583735512313028165561919771363465459087009309674834093296148584222690589604662407057035011740513343663528793002419282203653286073637418998298970726277476827911767544330705406278724865591029429120559455120218309440233354746066412254694019741678988828410289014532382K)_#b:c~
```

Creates a function `T` takes in the input `N` as input and leaves first `N` prime numbers on stack. Use it like `10T]p`

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44617/25180).

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 21 (Cracked)

```
Table[Prime@n,{n,#}]&
```

I am still new to Mathematica, but I think this cannot be golfed further with a max distance of 10.

This is an anonymous function which can be called like

```
Table[Prime@n,{n,#}]&[5]
```

to get

```
{2,3,5,7,11}
```

*PS: I created a trial account of Mathematica Online just to prove Martin wrong :)*

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44647/8478)

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 6765 (Open)

```
"gy;(q<hE23_@&]1;rIYoZA=(6j-'r@aJtcLDxe#19#s1m0VN~T|zD*YAS?/@LutnDPg'JyS-4#3y|CeTgN&GPs9D&p9!D${C9j`isBvuyeBE]P)n<ofN;m:rInU%g-EH!nQxZB[Q8d^:0*2Gv{yW9>sUD'0Y5K66tq6C`6&4mX}}790d;7Mxc`AS:m vo~q5utb4.mJ{UV']K#HXwYu[|py8DdIBD>0!^s7i?N'7krrp/iqZPCJ^?SNoOR7VxQ1,w:ID!VSf,R.TFV!tCAlwH9v&d3w8F-Xvt/i%j%%vA2{+kX]i 6_T3SW1DkB~,]p>$:xWX/eF19n0[21AI9f2(@W<?n2AX0iV{7SJYDz*!t> ;nb:n+OBz__@WpDH7lJ,;6uoJt`g{K}`df1TG%K~OUw:H$ol=9nFcQOD+E5*ekq!.p`P2[Z'u8=J&t5TieuSR'6?-g8>[l]*;Ko31l|M9p#)[3b5J`[SJ=Gr6Uns_1objzol2&k#KYoJ7!t-M:xbh-)ZV.w<S*ty;s}tahNtQ:Pza}rE@n3&02{a/SQdkJKe3+I6*^9)K[owPNs^6-4OG^lU`#) C3L_`<].wrk>%+yE??[CQG{|QSEw|NUN=9rf+wBxN p83XJeqKV&{#TE<qbFjT}4+;1PMolv?r+quS,Bm6U3#>=ZLDc1ZQ=i|Z61l_XGLG,v,aoX!67x{|g`Gu2+Nzu~VX]`h'Z>cC^Lr8%*uW23UhVE'/cPFr(!+@v**J&(N>t^}{e[Oep}1nR+1J582iM'B6 <euP !KZ@$+2:oBzc*%e+s!LE|G*MH`hIAf5k]`AN7US Tcj`N/VEYnfv|Ji9$}Jcs%+O<8TksXi5mW<O.sJ[!kL#I!2FOdZj?@7D9}%>3f7!>H&|XHvBjd)_.i'9BeACd!:G;= x;Q[5Ug6)'=(E[{!5q_Y$N<_Qe<rA1LnYfbQg@Uh]C>;ik5qSbSJmSX5GXDEN4/C,[7U:w5B=|~cY2ePK57Pb?f#|0YE:?hDs*ZxAOR?P1HkU)U/IyhH4$V,6DdrULw(6%S9J7mC,!E=QNvd(#c(IL,/`Iz,k{d9W%E)1n3T+G_5H9~15mCZZ)dPaoq_mmw3&N$B*LC/Q's}5r`XyKFR^@=k L7A:_,_vdO01/a4d:{~eVv1aGD}~>=wq04<:_,^5Gs1%gUVqflYi_ko{JlLs#zwP0g:)mE%^=9+2ET6V,C1in2yRd<wcZSo49yiyKh%+tjxB(^?!&MzTfV]Rtc3P)7-Cf t9 )&o}aGK+ex94 #erT>N[5XBK#+z{<Qk4}n?m12wHX_|`4Y 9Ku}V!XtPrc}TV56x[(3.?~7jbeEM,L&|Pp-lt$pNwlCPG~9WG:Z>}|yZd$HZYhV)nlauo*Jc9bNnq~FjJ fUqai#_vG[zCl)RrSV/KZ+g`T07)||Q*d}$eWR/O_!Ti+dNelS,l:OLJ0R')rr7+%,!pUN4@Qx,AlTYG-;qc!nn8RqqikP!m1YtAxWF`2<;@XtXYvzY.d~1I@W/h5&KR5K{L3iHM!aL /'%%4ID [}c7vT&**B9g`!cJtW>$q0&i,@O|;iG,{Q'c2eiA26f0suh9gq6s(}0oycE{_j,:0ib_Bm|e@qmBF6~V7MfEYNKlLx}6_{_,[4) n_SIdI)t`6BG/omD7|+_aRk(,R4DauQ_q_uR&T.6(UM-W|^[g|KV/AN*k%-@>uaGF4p~'g=tTXv#gVorC+d%V,`OwBNb6v6}3n?d'_SCm%d,LKTR<Z=h=u*LUy|Sj~w;?VQ0N],m9*/6l,@b|0orLW'V)n*$0XV8w(<H|;.Sz'R<j<<bs2ix.Gf<aHfgxIwyzn?i_v:;y!'7#QI=RdAe>d;A/}jQlacrL+>RwFc7'k=+$ >tzrDaU1qes]{w?CZ9Sl'q^lYc$7H@L~jJe_/W|^%sh#JJRhy=@3HVS6%xRw?GDWOZzv#X>y*%kax$<zWXz`BHy<7>qp+-kU*mPS(L^N2V.[S>A4SF{sTVGAs&PEt*JT{'>5WM./.duu)!T4CMBs/K*z'cWdFeI7Vd~[WS5cwy:e;JvB).FLka#D9tQN*_h-}i7C$2D1<:zq2.n^,I?[>9'~X:V/M.+0oR2:ZDw&?mM|Q_A>le}?+F;HE)Nk;La#<RGuUQkqZ.!jz]_kgDF?y.(+`D)/OQ?,eNU/[{1UDI.E2U>A(H[kdR&h$IeE)6y!s_/3V}eBL.>[IauTK3>KChKbG%bg@am:=&])];7!sqB^G=_cJPHVg6nmz.,l|2r>!~jwj6ub55;R#>.pT95%Mnh4aeH)8>2w1L8g;p/Tf$JAAl@,>8r?Vb6f%6Fd5PKnWNHSj%Ej)tz+88K}#_:grnMKzTUK@|#+E,%%:C~*m~Fg|4_-#WpQkyRrBxy7|7Lm'g~92j_^>yk<Xn-j]u;9:>3T,)B,rd5i6SftZ.gK*NySw8$-b]RkE]IcQ/n6!ZVLNp?l~mcsW(-C-YLKqk6q+(9}+L_z;p#Fauu,1MB: +Y`MG <3%gwWe-}z?S4L<cB#n;*lMFZ]]y3oni( P],W5~rJm15jQ(7S[C`+S:%+NV}i!{(t6(v78t> WwNch|WLpQtNFV~I!=rz[fX6s{<]kaq*?Ud=VYOoM]-8IrS'hARjW(~ha|3Npv)EZI*i`o2?Ra~-?}!FQt[C0QoY>~9m@o,a><pn(N3<S5c%U.^#2)ZIDbrg8+&:0h9$}-{mj-(vVuU!saxq$>XFte>i/>md#C?lH5G:<Ps/n[DJVT98WC~tgjwEj?ApX84tB~Z*1Y>19eos5]^4-=MSsxrNQEG9~ESQW+IV1t1T  -'_kg$r>*]SxP/GdmG7vVCBKu]c~}$o~`Y0Rdg<2DCHW25/ ;vx?KF5C}T/0R/TNd@O2 =0'=?E0_Hko{{|5z9wtX#NM`MXk&owmwI}$+>8.HL2Wsp8*+fV6m~{Tij?28fV10kIO,a7[=(B2{cj&cDEwgl,A,U(18>PC'%H47ilWz~?AvyWe5H&&$bU_nRw2C3gLO;Q]ppaz^f6LBCJ/EkRd9B2Od_/Y6@?1/&#6tjo?LG%2_A#^1R{hb*I%pB-CFO'i=OBSfV]D8Gw,Tp?>9qrWdSL5,TR&`BE,4[cCW]AXNXmg&PJ@Qv!GH~S gY.oL0u$,uj[_67i~&Y6I01aw`JAl9'&.}5^].*%}M1$&[+_BIa3;Fy&pP_qP3utw'x[I`ps<;wf'ga,p(HHn2x+DMY:z:xd3x*?sHsLZpfpY 3gZ1'y.oe|3F6:4RJFP~bnA]}E-'kgt]xtdBBy'@LaDmWl9l-XibhE%<?tap+Y8 !r;>>Kcj7;Td:Qj!U8ZO!?_?<:F=P^?:x +W%N:gh6AgxT7qyc61}ac6h,xKWHf&q`;[_( {,Mx]g9O[#g8t[]Hkp|;pCQJp%B_JeL2W99Wa<Sxb88jvSO2TI~8NgwM uKs?f{/G3{n+2S<c?CAD$j;U,`4ft1K;nZFM2T@>U.1(C[kTWy= s?/DkZ_E_mk)jEZa8PUMQqB.~U$ho9fZi'.i+E>=7VgXNs0_&_V#M*kQViZ s)l5C=ZJxxt;[$/rz4#AG#M]g{JMUyzE=6s7iFa?pb)%/gt[_7:$)Pxh)/O~z<4gno)bN?*|:|Q+qO>9dS&<NZAR7(`lzw&]&dk|'TwUivvJ$YY9:5|xp'WY-V%i_M1%G/hq !]!rq4$BUHr$$=;cQJBgX(J;^~;>A/Pm`Xn&V$%qZk??;4(wjMB,@:EhuBqDV0hWcr1o%6YSxwt34.[$O5. {8>{--%_J40Em/m!,'XpXiXyTw87B`qHJiBnd'cCnB)!R]4$?R%.?pBBW-3$c((?B~yC&,q1<HT&'JB);i=_M./Y1/E?}+@|m}|?FuA+]*CwrmE@uHeFT5V<t0VOx.~3E9JR4f28g]I$AzrKQ;I%`2KMo;p=uRRr;G|vA NP!=r}9WU+9pdRo8|w^!-i35Fb?>Y_>wAc,p|~hr~&5}GZ8+N9{_2!Khpx)z1x&0OGCa/LtlS98+RAd9JXn(M-YorhIF4M,!@H*)+tcd8>2lt)(G|f%ngryQ8V>QsFE.~Tr_2MX&c?CM;^q(y7!1LaYlPz`0*G*mUN|p&.ei>>(eH=aa%gSN:?veN&itv`w>[;dQ~U]l6k}Z@=s/Wz^N5u5|ZwQ.gMs`9eg,${o!3up/PTj>/1j{*uK[[wLm|z.<t_UC>0n3pGt8RG[_y1[%&&y5SV'T]qkvim.R98Vd+:M]Jx8h7^Rq%B+V~7!my R4VztdLK&A~C Mxo[+@v2qJ+#l<awqn3xTp H[,Qp<6<YT@Fm/Cb62$(R$Q&eup`Za?8gR!v> 8BAPjhO+n=]o!V.{g[^Ib9J'xA}%;K/@`|[Ca5DCNxYw,!a5WY,,'9M*3tdof}usX 7Z{2P_A!pcKA|rab0rbk+EH@iQ_$?'F+_384hO}r%4~?vK~m$!TtN9(AHH*45oI$qJ6W%,WXeMF{0i]*~*7@HqY~`<L~W7u<!R(,ly{*!le_Q({%@gA8H]MQ5I6aaR+0c!{rNstR%*W1FhjEiW5v9G;@@;#Tm.C*Kxh}_@sQQGMD!Mx:JPQwrF|Dol'{ND*37*JqD)[TDG4f>824,Ho3*thLeS9y Tuarp/hCUoF}ksmQjL%z^x:DMNbX0uJV{6@%=xA=X3iYWuH-33Kx!16QFy_oK;-_[ sw^~i[rWYEmUuunh~{&zv2r!%WU}QE-4%>2DR:R%b*b)zzV8vWO=g6~T9d3w~gg+99z!.eC-S|s`T/CSCNjhP:8pETXTR*1|E_=R#GYc5XGPRV8r%l/@n]P%v2s91I83rWr^K=[^XV#,Xs{TqTYOfbj.`1x6u)5M5Zb]&Vo6.}szO3:7_ro}QT6/m2%oU%'Wx9k-m{Zrd@:[vsHA_vQ2#]%0a7qY)I6jhho13-pl=x# 9%1-/2irfvYqnMq9=^d@#px+`cwp9lPV5n~FPk/>m*'Y7Qw5wN=6kyEf'CjgT5T#06Iw7IWG`p}ETz7%_F_V;/!nDil~ZR_:{/}rGhg K,3j9ke.4TI^a!9;D):s>[gR6#wd28=l+kaHW?Cfv{7Jssa0ZQ@oWO5LN?mB_Y%cELRW^4$#`R8=xvt'G4Y6wzw98&MN=eC`973^6'$G$p1PL_1Kj&N/fey[roEo.53V(DYzT%{OhS5lJs>N{qzc$[nGxfcdRS$`c:X{<I5Jhctz xuczPG_PbC+gI|ALd^Ii=}J[Fg$.[BHtUe!?xp0wuM|XCS5g&T&ubG)+t(t-d]r]4U>!n}D;d7I^2t?T05V(3cZ3uJNH=IF$o:iKZIkZzhB5Nka!Sop4DSc r+9.*Hcl`4Gm,G0C$$qn@n5aJ@v;F@2{9:>hQcEOvr*sx3JX_[d1qD4<OKnPFHEw.JQ_}P+|_4v;3@JYz+-zxWN^j5jm9,2=31zeCId iMhT~]:0Lew_/rU}K)L<h?MToOwd&Y'I/,<b7v{&vM4+91(6C-[Fl62^ftTKxa{?j&g [J{7Fg?cci|Rgu XPd$CLr$a&-./(&?r^bY#kN.TSQA{S6N2r}.yKi&Jk{C,<WRi[9jNuU=KQ8Npcq@TPsrGnDOJ!0'FN2R}g3#2cN)'dwucjEy0}P{9N/z&!3$BB&Nkl=,!JFEt;vFj>ZCS:9k@+m-h1>L5aS{#qYnhBx=L%KpPI:_o:'1+_MzX?]$2>-2ueV22rCqA}7Uh)/r_<>w7OZi:NVM8HizVre$TUx@/YPm3*?<_heQXBqw5H`((_/F{Nuvi`JeTC<3`wo=i+4b-Zj#W4:v<CIjR-33y`[:htPfOylw@-Ec5p@H>y/S$9&{N*>6!z$V~<-pq_VQq;ad,Df0ofn{g5zQ:>j/QzApCVH*@^vXvp(96bl<G_E2.g+!,^rI$p}=V9}_V*+lba@)qs#,3[DNZu}X1_ia2?:PzhF4`CsNGSyK].! LapmrSz5sEV:WOWVr8Q'Hr'IrZ7$@xrDjY{+%@z~~LG']D4Dvzs4E9%xcK$7068oRedo@v|GHm.5(h}yyyPT3UC&jhF70<|%t*iWMpIE)Zv_;9J*?KA/O@y=}Ib}I%a[$a<:|#o5kTY<Zr'geBK(r`BjgQ-+fVw^co^bs/kHmY??5rYBa#.|gc|;L>Uvh5;vKySEWXGL|usoE+lf|]_z.Aq^CGy=#Jdba[NjEWQ'sxf,+'WJ{$k/gCcNHO4_gE&V?$r(T3u33Dyoclc2rxc=$t* MfbNz!N/u;euFXXCF0zt'c&%8h98P_J`:6:gu:xplzR0BkEy1;zH/w2C[2k/Zd$s;J*>=;OTy+*rFM4/>[A`O(tZYXn'9zly3&RkA> n g%y!8f&pXdM>)uib~@|q4l)`#IwQ2Joryn</WN(1']@]>P;A%llX9.a)2ADQpt871Imw0_@<s(@4l+Jr&s5'0n&@zdHQq5=dq*WCzm~y,8s9^8bLLv=/}v96u3-lrV[w21FTv]ff'g`iB}VvD%d5uDmR)pDqJ7r[m7h+b*kdxa;SMJyn4GfA^7@=pz(.[3CwR$*pdG!,bUEYJM27>?*Q(E{UlcAnA08ur|Om72~[XlPKZM 36}mt@$YOxYJ2LH9Z:q-z$9i[%D:fC`K5>F;L8X5-VZA'gEX9Bi]_[vJ%.3&LoR1kkd8@IOYaGL8H4YfzAulTg/X`XDV4B=4N~k3N>JaTK#k5#I-#Y71op0Iyh7Nre(@<PN{3JJOc8McR`uXC`jEg!jSE{b&[.RppnfQjJ0@DBgj81`)#X|8^5M^#S"'~/'"*S/'\*{iKsW%iP*mqs'.-i+:K93%'!+}%~
```

I'm not sure how safe it is. But have fun cracking it.

It works only in the [online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/).

It will create a function T. Example: 10 Tp.

Comment: Isn't this [my cracked solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44615/31414) to your last submission ? With a deliberately added extra byte removed ?

Comment: @Optimizer It is.

Comment: Even after I clearly mentioned that the cracked attempt is uncrackable ?

Comment: @Optimizer I guess many of the robbers' answers are considered uncrackable when they are posted, but didn't survive too long.

Comment: Even if that is true, this algorithm specifically is hard to crack. Also, do keep in mind that right now, its not a cop vs a robber, but a robber vs a robber as you simply used one of the answers from the robber's post. [I have raised](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44567/cops-and-robbers-bowling-cops/44650?noredirect=1#comment104859_44567) a point with OP to see if this should be banned.

Comment: Then let's wait for OP. But if I can't post this answer, I think it would be better either CW it or let the robber (you) post it. For a QA site, we are not posting just for winning, but also to let the readers to see how a winning answer looks like. It's bad if people know a good solution for a task but cannot post it.

Comment: The algorithm is devised by you, so I certainly cannot claim it as my answer. In the worst case, lets CW it.

Comment: @Optimizer In fact you can of course use similar algorithms. This worked well in the regex cops-and-robbers. It's just uninteresting if an answer is too similar to a previous one and doesn't have big improvement on the score.

Comment: "I guess many of the cops' answers..." a typo.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 24 bytes (cracked)

```
{1{)__mp{@(_@\}*}g@?}:F;
```

This creates a function `F` which takes argument on stack and leaves that many first prime numbers.

Example usage:

```
10 F]p
```

Result:

```
[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29]
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44661/8478)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 924 bytes (Safe)

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
f n=take n$id=<<id=<<fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)fmap(<$>)id[[primes]]
```

That's a total of 192 fmaps. If you had enough memory to actually compile this (you don't), ghc would factorize it to `fmap.fmap.fmap`. You crack my answer if you can prove that a `(<$>)` can be replaced with a `(.)`.

I could make this longer, but I'm just going for the best Haskell answer really..

### Edit:

Safe! I might come back to this actually. This is the same kind of problem as RSA; it is provably possible to factorize, it just takes silly amounts of computational power.