# Cops and Robbers bowling (Robbers)

Tags: primes, code-bowling, cops-and-robbers

## Robbers' Thread

In this challenge, your goal is to *crack* some code written by the Cops (their code is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44567/bowling-with-the-robbers)) by modifying it.  You have *cracked* their code if:

1. Your modified code has a maximum [levenshtein-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of 10 from theirs, and has fewer characters
2. The function, given the same valid input, will produce the same output in the same language of the same version
3. You posted your modified version within 168 hours (1 week) of the original post.

Your modified code must only have printable ASCII.

After posting a cracked version, you should leave a comment in the original code saying that it has been cracked with a link to your crack.

Your score is the total [Levenshtien distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) among all of your answers.   Highest score wins.

The accompanying Cops' thread can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44567/bowling-with-the-robbers).

Comment: The goal is to change the code without changing what the program does?

Comment: Yes, except that you have to reduce the number of characters.

Comment: I missed that the first time I read it. I was very confused.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the lowest score winning criteria on this one. The cops thread contains a TI-BASIC answer with 4500+ characters. That means the best score someone could obtain cracking that is 450, right? I posted a cop answer that is 233 characters, so by anyone cracking my code, they've already beaten the lowest possible score for the other answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm confused for a different reason about it. The goal is to have as high a distance a possible without exceeding ten?

Comment: Yeah because if you were allowed something like 50 or 100 for example, you could just re-write the function almost entirely... Well, if it was short enough. 50 Gives you too much room for change

Comment: @Brandon you make a good point.  I've updated the scoring.

Comment: I don't know that that's the best scoring either because it forces people to answer multiple times but I can't think of a better system.

Comment: Wasn't paying a great deal of attention to the scoring when I posted my crack.  Is it OK to change it?

Comment: @Brandon I was confused about making the goal to have change it as much as possible. I understand why the limit is low.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I liked the old scoring system.

Comment: If someone cracks an answer, but I can crack it with a higher distance, will my version count?

Comment: @KSFT no, it does not.

Comment: Can't we always pad the distance to 10 using spaces?

Comment: @user23013 But remember that your crack has to be shorter than the original answer... So if you want to insert 4 spaces you'll have to get rid of 5 characters first, which will be hard if the code is golfed!

Comment: Would it make sense for the robber score to be the number of bytes reduced (as much as I don't want scoring to change again)? The max score is still 10, it rewards smarter changes, and avoids the variable rename issue mentioned by @YiminRong in the Cop thread comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Python 3, 9500 to 9499, by Sp3000, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44605/25180)

### Original

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
def P(n,x="'Good luck!'and([2]*(len(x)==9373)+[3]*(len(x)==9373)+[5]*(len(x)==9373)+[7]*(len(x)==9373)+[11]*(len(x)==9373)+[13]*(len(x)==9373)+[17]*(len(x)==9373)+[19]*(len(x)==9373)+[23]*(len(x)==9373)+[29]*(len(x)==9373)+[31]*(x[0]==x[-1]==x[9372]==\"'\")+[37]*(x[-2]==x[9371]=='!')+[41]*(x.count(chr(39))==100)+[43]*(x.count(chr(34))==98)+[47]*(x.count(chr(92))==1)+[53]*(x.count(' ')==98)+[59]*(x.count(';')==100)+[61]*(x.count(',')==99)+[67]*(x.count('x')==98)+[71]*(x.count('(')==98and x[-29:-1]=='This is the end of the line!'))[:n]+[k for k in range(72, n**2)if all(k%d > 0 for d in range(2, k))][:n-20]if n>=0else'                                                                     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####################################################################################################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))******************************************************************************++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------............................................................................................////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444445555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777778888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<==================================================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[\\]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^____________________________________________________________________________________________________````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssstttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'+'\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"'+\"'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''\"and'This is the end of the line!'"):return eval(x)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

### Modified

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
def P(n,x="'Good luck!'and([2]*(len(x)==9373)+[3]*(len(x)==9373)+[5]*(len(x)==9373)+[7]*(len(x)==9373)+[11]*(len(x)==9373)+[13]*(len(x)==9373)+[17]*(len(x)==9373)+[19]*(len(x)==9373)+[23]*(len(x)==9373)+[29]*(len(x)==9373)+[31]*(x[0]==x[-1]==x[9372]==\"'\")+[37]*(x[-2]==x[9371]=='!')+[41]*(x.count(chr(39))==100)+[43]*(x.count(chr(34))==98)+[47]*(x.count(chr(92))==1)+[53]*(x.count(' ')==98)+[59]*(x.count(';')==100)+[61]*(x.count(',')==99)+[67]*(x.count('x')==98)+[71]*(x.count('(')==98and x[-29:-1]=='This is the end of the line!'))[:n]+[k for k in range(72, n**2)if all(k%d > 0 for d in range(2, k))][:n-20]if n>=0   else'                                                                  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!$###################################################################################################%$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))******************************************************************************++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------............................................................................................////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444445555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777778888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<==================================================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[\]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^____________________________________________________________________________________________________````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssstttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'+'\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"'+\"'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''\"and'This is the end of the line!'"):return eval(x)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Changed the `\\` to `\`, and moved some random characters to get a better score.

Comment: Nice catch, that was fast :)

Answer (score 7):

[Original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44594/19057) by bitpwner, **Python, 5199**

```
lambda x:eval(eval("'eJwVmDW27FoMRHNPxYEZOviBuc2MmZmhzfbo/30j0JKOVLXrlMplDFSIrgJjO5EBNjaH4UyI8ySe6HytrwMEZTvBriX1q6p42d0tx35NoRTJLdo7orQk9qrk6EwQB2iRKtpCR8ymnseOkNCjE13ethWOt5y/pZjP9YMzrst9indsZlkxdusyelyJNLaw1CUVosC7P4LdCgUAccFEdrxrznIzpyqYYzBZgJu0fUEKq7HZxaa7nqjPCkkiy3iLArLpjvoFMsDhZOK1lI0NL8Ky4zsgkEE7MrWes4l20zO10nfd3NiUaKk6vNbEzu/BYV1wsyRfXtIXdH13Wyyv1Wi/fE1m/YuDrzkGQmWtFlBbud97+/yEtMdm4uv+vrf6m5B7UA1KN8NK/3TZmv34VEOgRmEJEsZzsVs0BDkkOeY25tCnxxWkkUQAQUwJ7vnZve+LuWmeV04FulePd2o/Or3AXjSAoEzu46Q8ElaNNm8+ts2UYD99uz7kXgdX24frQd39Aarva3I1DZfple+r2PD227rGza9teRuVSLy2DGeZk3zG6zbQuV9egEsmm935F+j44Z/bD8ZwyE9fWgU68+OTY0l3JEbEMFosAn/E8hOqqlRx7xDXmOCpYSHdsrvBFj/u7xigfNDaShxXrZFmpCbPLwYrQyEBusUfAaIWWCbXHVdivm8jS3t1mJmilzlC5lxYD0M0J7YsLCxuyfoIjz/fcsnXCyS6BuyZT6SAxGilgP/EP3dtJJpW1SAIHymi2OpzLIr9DYriR7d/JXMIOyqdYluoc61XGiGvpluEZ6RcRD6lsLfRnATyDgLCmQbiYFlonx1Uezs8WLDB0iRHx3+/yuiKOBZbOPRX6dZpN727LsVAer0rriDZbzqsd8iWYOEUkUwBrfGDBWmW62J9ovZXHcI7DCy0/gyiHC/QTy0OMf4m1orNF6WDBRxXhKKZm38K+67lVG8O1MM85JBLG3gf3A+WbGLVSjBHX+p7uDrYb02mn+9BJNt1aJNwSqwakpVSyJLxFAhHD9PcVRpS1S6s59oYl8OowxQw0eabmq81f9tkM3tuypsavy6x7IrhoOJgXNzY5jFpoxZFg2QFpANFNMEEfMuyqViMn9hhyIkB0Wke+Dax4yfSj0zwzwAr3wg+rJ2QIFmTfueD8QVTg2iDI6BP/eZDTanFD7KbTJ6Re0vVmWE7mB0QS9qNtYCI7tAS0XvaekkTHSG4cpMOB3EV5KYhNLJNueL9oOtC27D4tEnofU4tEo7vz9qD4b7rKC8FYyZoOqOAOfmSH7pwkYS5FsUS4bP2Ou77RQQMSfv3yt1GGrgod8bt549ts5dw77hgd5TDACM9VqOKl7i8GfpZAtAdTYcefvu/ZyXxq2dHiyt+SFZ0W8BxSTNe7pRl7d0qp89VX7pFuTmqDVKb9lAjAjTnKpdGYsbLqw9AfsFzThIq7GjZho3uwy5UdpDYnERU2z2H3/hYvNboGmE5ger3gZcEJ3tpfnluxqmDru7J+xm5S/2IAC8gruOZI/vWzwNl98xbP67q6auflhiW0ZRrEcMS0YV7mRdrkyiEHCjMJwp2lWQYVxdxs4Q7ouyvJ2A4JH4xrst4I2T0g5vd0RaNYozWfjSsEooMEx0/J7bykRSu1kbYCs4h5GyUm16haMjBhHJYelDEgxhgYPMGbdrJts4/0xiu39YW4ih9MrxBSK+0IUMEffFL0kv+4nXOophdkE4Nrelnevs8/DomWTOUIc30CjACLXXoEKfpngunU7TxkLDucH5VMfwUMali3a3kvExI/YTrEf+SE8jSh5j+rEp2FG3Tv/auBGyp+gPw2EqN0XN65CBGM/Rc4c58Yffng7lvqpUfjH+m7NaGywr0HjFjCCRq0X1dT/JN1G+OH7pamKu/Ar0zQMfYtsr3V9L9krdVFhxC4UoqGyHxXKLGN/FNoyjFuGCZm0qO6du6/4SbgMfo6S33LXczjARHnLDIVAG0knSGYAKX0r4+Q21o7p7bRYNfVElbs9brvvsZ2BCf2n08l6nggW44ZtUZxZ9qFYl5H4ou4xrheygFrJ+A0Jk7Z3cCsS7vIZES5a72BjdEoWxogjZynKcwboRdgLhZZRbTOou7NE+7r7iQHdeP0OyNI2QBDbTEOG/+1thG6boTGlFyRVmgZzPYGFowSSjVY5B09WB7xJ9mKB333/3qWfS+GfczbDAasTm/zsTmbBuA+Ky3+HlobJ4NhroD/1o+FjEAyVzQNEcwib+JVoxGsZ8gJEDOl6FW66uDnP1VVu8BGnVEOEBDtnMOgK5imCeZNMFcnPU/AHh6sWuUJaQyssVLF4NO2ftsJcYto1GMkzhgoGZ7VFzgvAa+ztkZtNZq9nTBNJBeVwAvc+hhBA1eynIL5alMiqM5Yp48B3p0Af8lMb9g8A7eMHiQfT0rWlGJnsU/p1/HgesHPSrH9DjAZ+aAXk+UeQOI4gUBG8DIXNTZu2V96+z5QgpTa4mc5XPE3aWDRzeFhVNd4ZkznWjoS5SLn7ZgaV8SwBmtzuC6L3Hmt5590FqYp4L0fsypXZP82SVOYopIW8bS1QnzmbrNWhgVJXPFgxADVFuUdmhe8ca0GbiaB1H7qjjUYf2x1OewgzoJFDgs8p8Ry/z3crIHVjgi9sCrgeWkr03oGniyd2jNaLmOcdezSqMwNTqAIzD8G/96KGkrPc1amPWp2ULtk2C7xVEFzN8gPjrB0RH+TNVMwwKiGfkjzWgPQSWF8H4xZOfUcyMtACiPpqMcoUTzUy9h9TqUUj+2KiHeLjjwn2RmGepGP204tOHbw/T0mn5Df9CUvWwlV2zDfeoah1xf3iSAOiqiaBDa7tevfA/vb5wVeRNEvx97Qj7DF/Wdxcx4Y+5tlYR6oZSKRDNDJaK6YM8ESCVjSTZvejYIIJLLo71xGKSztdy2N9l98h1Gkq+YrixucemmcAxvRMa4AzxCqvsgtHMrlY2rVz7TCAsatev8+TTz5MCJj38vYpPpr1uVZ4i5wlTuMguuWmJ6z8fhlmp3J/kzTNE2IqaQpqZev4jafckot7q58sXrarv9g7osoGD1F/tmsjG3a5bd9gtNCfrzMzXw79zQ8/R8ji1XY+kTTaaXcT7bxJZIBDh0yZ1oNP1UgOfEMiZchUBjufgfTc8RN5GHkBmrxeAHFKWTb/G9z4VJon3vBPoEVegfHaTaQXd9vxzm6PJUup8lqZMYTS8fDe8V+CmCOJkGzLSC0Teg4DEUN7/VZVjQw5YPY061ibrInw7qwZ150yrJ59+ElUY3xSfxrLVntxk582wbZ+CPjOpUm6LuNvohkte3Zn2VbEMr4SLjiSwm19yOMyg7wM77u/NVfcZyYwcDUhTb4dqhTRTnd52/YRMBvrwakDUgF6pwvqGdA5XuhAbPrX7eMYS98p3H/bmMwb7MOGTzx1yfMEU5z0PdiQ/G9mX/Uoyw6HDbgJ913KlpRsUuz7GO0FJUzvTIwlQ36eV7s9r9+zBMJ+65PVF3+LYQt20L+T3Whv/DEl+htmozoGigdBow9PovEh1eWVQ0njbGLvn0n9TIEKiP3hqFyVmecc2MEDFO+OFGlSPgy1vaVAg1KqMhN+44lu2p+R0YAEuafxCFWlXH3hshf87S9KnrJIbAKep2sGHq/KVlHl4SzoY5j5N89wbUmH+Fq5o3rOaN77vPXK4jOQ0EC64ZfyAKSbnB86W/QGh2Ph4/MGGs33OqZ387dA8ENI8as0Jk0o12q7rZvXwoqnO+ImQ0DSb9CPwSgRF3FXhpxGLh4z8QiNxA48dy04Jsr3vQe8kq3/8AGP8dtPCTsCPvkb8sFr98+0IsSd0xwmg6TfuaMLUA5wvDO2u0SNyn87FqDJVJVI7tpL0/1R2SalPcwYp1yWrVYMwP3tchR+Qj7OWcEwrYTKMmv9D4iox8ARNJVKsYwUu+5pb0EQuqc0fTDu5m4Zuw4kafFphM4W8T4438ZgJr+bOlRc+X7VPPcuxn4PFBENL9shsQQwfxs8e9Pnafn6o9enSU0CPTKf8QbwpQ7C9CSFniLD+ak+bty7yyPFPy/anTdv72I96wj1U5WNr1OWD1pQm5h2QdUH8oaw2ZoVC2UNvL2uBHjf2oTGm8rZOx7mvHT/oypPxsEoJA5k+zyI6sFljVfYcSNhV4cHJ3HPRV1pupwgfB8QqxPm5sBaVs2B9WW0zOi8K/DLkrH30yKo/GfWEaVHqXvtCQeD3ENqSaQJs+A+RljRla0NqM/guaETUjdSFQzsCso+ioD29VDFTPQR0Y0JgEw0RjW3ZnMT36b8nZf37hPR6XRTDLsUA10cmiLKjL6eYVLyiV2be5tlEZ9R+P/bzsEbD6ppsaRlM+RyMXuNdx739mUXVozrGbGxvBuOpuNfgCdkBxK1yRkLV+a6GtB9Cb/2LYqWcjHToZTdn1SXguSeXOZsUUzMhfVx6ZiGeUlRVSr7Cf6877mYQEFviBF+t5s5Ul7x6harT8qrI0do/m7lt3huGTEMzphDHfkzRUnbwjH+kYUKjo0WK18u4Q/d5fLoSNe+lA/74y6bp+XdoWmHMeS/yLMiQCugw/WDirGRO4C2ZbHxfl8wEcSzy8fOGywShVmlkhg4jqfkz8IvcSSB7MJcX30jz6+2h+fa8lQnbKfgV7uX4Ikcp0yynhYkBxFBTIGKROvqWwAsmi0/yjskK5/tA0IOKVy4GM/S68XlA3/lmXTVf+ZJI+IpNewOxjQ3mq7iF0C+uGfXZrkyxPdhsTSveErxttffRT03jac6YJ8dcb8HiLEX2zL2jJBpHCEz8BGR71wX8dzhjTYGTT9aC+wuY8+dOiM/+usR9FO1wqww3qOHWRtpZuYRZ8TmBuka1dcrryq5rukDl+OS7GyIf1vd/Fna+buH1PWRQbjp4+KVADZow6Qep3lUcZ7aoL9pdLTf4W7/PHZ584AGtmKW/xD1FvzFGh5d83hF6cLNpkgdm8qBuH2Qkmhv0HjvpCyDLVUW7O2XkxL3BEVesFxreviIAPtucn/DV/twFvf2AeITIyYx3pbsMd5oL5rDHookzUD67El/PO+Vdrwlb+XQy3BfefPYFnUG15bJwlAN6FJSLgE0Tm78/OIPCqaJbiJaud/wP+B8oHe7w='"+".decode('base64').decode('zlib')"*56))
```

Modified Version **Python, 5198** Levenshtein Distance **2**:

```
lambda x:eval(eval("'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'"+".decode('base64').decode('zip')"*56))
```

Replaced `'zlib'` with shorter alias `'zip'`.

Answer (score 3):

User23013 original **CJam 7531**

```
K"t0}Wi+vjx\"`@qYZpR@7,c}U3e6s:hmpe* M}|C`?I_WN6'a(Z`#%+oOE_N_AqmAgaG|OX>uF5Qn!m{sPQ4ki;7]0-ecJ;[*S!qn#V=:4aRtpk5FXXa`5q|!nkUo9-u>]Ovf2('(^~/328U!O&3[\"Ho~w?qZ<86]Rvpmtf}*$yYXeBcOYT1$qG+S$S/>j)D)cd9H7l*l;;c%1<?JHX7 5o0ii7-@_xDKoKG0ir{g{;$Ma=Cbd 75e3%UAK/7f'sH OuI*),YmCxwEF';6Sc,u76A&1j~Jo9c0Tq)#)tQKw;Mr`pk!br#Q _B,mSXH4#Dy t{vmg8=%cznRxw9U,_5[xGsS[$(X:XOfsslKkj%Lyx!}C<uEWaS<yn->#'hK5d1t>&-zF;NiO;u?Kf_Nj!Vxcp!u1ylxpUG3yp^I1?y)4&[}fyhf''o~VyE0gE]L&eL$Xs6(l]q$FmK!&#JeP8)(3ADg 600qEk;XITtTvO+n-b#D)0H*{:=g%iiq`-[JBYvUW#'4GcKa!vBqD8#\"r|beNA}K})Nnh_Y5N,zC1pVP{pjV#Gw's`WPO_.Vt=M`fHt:\"c*zBD{**2D1 h)baU<I+9-FPoc&O(%,EZ_q!VIW]aw2i+i![IugzfHa%:CF<guepsH!hn'kpm+},T1f:]@(UWI!19h)RS`%n*|*'#rKXi0PY<L20}VHG]GturEqBKe<-g~YQ!4*'78U!#,Xxl~|TM~DH!vZIF3Iq-(|5-1Y.UJZfBt.GXvt!e[6~Ez.QJH7{LDP[906rs|mC0)iZN;9P--Y]DkQ MX)wTRyvkFBxhA@n{X0p\">0)i=s~<CXCS3]H'{DcR3Yo1tg0NG!q{7n5+h_%BTYsy@#O'6_%{BP\"9Uzthw^5`fqciBk.rBbu^e}l!HW$h+~ho:8A+ =2n1Nh\"S%iqCI!Q0E.K$&2!$75bG@,EV}?a-kjb2>,;\"MOh7QR\"]$f[>E|oR#&kDD(^s&i@t(6#Td`9SJ}tDVB: oZdclb~s'*qMK pmjb,XW*[S[[7O_1|)Qut@1=I)9vB%I)G/~h_$y%5H+-ALcT,Y7WcG&iGc9joTHwaa9+{97H5rvi2[Fju2mdyqZ|u7HO4SE ZrA1S}wUv:>}=)rP+mHsXhNFm^wri8DtFdFddI}]N{(NyeX==qNu{XL\"_1`AqG*.llvLD\"J|`KZhut>30\")aeT76WMTu9mcFcLiyD4!&QvTlo#zF}W6pljg[{_2TTC6m)8jTW1M}ME|Bv.k/vAZg-q^&>q0<,<{ih_vyM~n6<ewr/=_u`Wj%XGP!p}+^g!!TmaK^WeHC+U\">qz6'M>~D\"L)Fcdm7Wf7`B-gqw|6kr`PsK;`cM\"Q4aLSG4[i+D3jg%?q,\"7SS-)69yHCW|L);[2wt$8C|JW=b*(rhj;uutE$;{e7)jYTAm#`iFUdU3iEK(q$&D/E`x9ZY'[c<HbDy{gV?eb$oOK\"6_ USFV a'<OX^o{A%Gn63tI[,P<=w ,c/=t3Wl9[44uX {^+(vho?3KxyezT/8_Qmm:UYd#{Gj7N2S2K4S*Iq56@S80Q^gME/p8,eP<{\"3xi-t-Cm43/HzA?a\"n(!l)aM!7:0BA;SrIW*$sLV>bKHRh[be|I 8m0*^X ;m]UBGhi'[_~Gwj@PN#i'+0^`TW:+IXCkPPCCh%{w@Uu#xqa@5otcog}sivL7nYO5^y+:`.&M)Lkn4VDMQF[0Y_=9, \"pZm{iV$3ycdn{}U:8)`3H,F340[|o~`DfHu?&QJI0g1#kF-`|%(4Ap#R/Fq\"1<{%CV6TucD.#pPv,mLW=*LjGS{O<eOR:dla) L[$ue1]lrdqPs_@qAy&]y&YMw9~_yZ]95C%JyXa$iR2U;{G.tb%lDx+_4K5E.{tYvvTcD3Ypq>EJVg`TI)X1w,Crw^8AAV%9AGq%].T~+$o~c#@Xc2`1r #,=/RE*8/b#/% Y~LyDrIPrN;hFt,C^1<Sa*LjPmPl9787{GXn}E|EL(&V-c&.}hSkEXG7[yf3pGlBV5_sf8-[{i@l0BY.(Q2o6)|km/?}.BKgm(i#pk,W_^FVs{r$1OEtI?E-8?VH|uRd'0xP.9,'OSjESAtmcO3Ikr\"kMs.!E\"M~wN! o^=]p0D ?le=iT$,M5%w{+5\"aT@YOj?iww>|;y~+/6z_']IUkqc>cG`V.[9g?x2`rE4y9 ^\"+OHtvia&#hrJL<y6kB*t7nEuAx/+A?:ZvT93VlH`Eg9w%&xRP+5-R^s6ez}!d#tTPCq|3v/d_.s'WZP,Wyv'FL'S3HEuBg}elwyl8f4l`{o}3vF=p]Ye1S\"8G}M<pdJ(:3;/dP2M8%8;H iln>0]pzU)7H)9jN%0I~NgV+X*Uw4[bF[Jg5aN`LIjP&m98fg777g+[2kA{`UIt3;UK#9~l@y./MME'XutazUcLz>1gnfnn*@cec8/9_h#@=t>w'oElYr2hx^ss^#X=PHDo%$8Z!f<GnME{gmQ\"$qW<K%`%g0/m)15!4A**;@>/hq@ B|c\"?*&syKxL^P@ $!y#x8A[@bE>#OF.IyP]?q+I@TxA+[3O55{'EjNTSq+lk8iR4!1+F??VFO@XA,1Znac6E:lr.\"EIT$M)wi<l:g!]2'OH107DX#y:Fp_`J?).V~4HW&S+nwGX7Xl%7ui J+HKO6kRO<e3hpO&xKDu'r:?l>aPL_iN3+Iu-s\"? Z_[<9wR,s$8}Q=;3u?x3k?ZsAp$m+??m&T18c|,d[1Alcz|gye-d_-s\"vcQi~9bx}v%O}nDO95McdnKI~iEp_C!%iNr2hnPO!.U^;+~/P^Yrh}<IAmHeulsQlDcKG|$pW)hnRYaa@v8X$ PsiGMX$4(@#6VB@IaQ};@8R0RoCI9enUbyB#3W+bA55uo qGZjOc%k:/a\"^h+V4Pdr|Rp*^H<7/5iM:j7-'p !@eq:.u>96 w}L3$*L^l/-[,UyE;|jq3_I1#w%@y(f=+2OuUK$F>xX\"{\"#?Q>2DCQ=|NB$o5EN7<#_qT=Q*3jzFDVLY4BIj[|[R1JP{z^u.l8(2Bs,n]d7[v^M:8]<^.WyFXAEDCE,p{Xdw6_|C[f7.;=*s&>/Y+ hD{OPt6wRk3MnJd-hYQ)kyee./S7J\"/6u&eQLV07$H_%TZb7BdJ2xW6MHq`-U:f^}$y\"F-e*\"v7Dx%l]my%D6! 2`BJ)5=GT{U^iDu;>HwvL^p)|*WvYwX)xLgFyTXM.y5W:RF</5<GME-<Sa\"E!jdqCzX1F.o^iq!Z5D:(|'9}L5A/iOmOaWr 25]=}eN&<Ce,S(o BB*3^2/Hq<>C/j)k)mfw+rVyJ*s(W0cq0_azYI-,p4 Qa.Q1Imz%G!GOIv\"CE,FLj:;LRm6a!cuWl%cw'|i'+gCCIHk]&Rx%emi3G-O;BXr{+;TSDCZNjm>k4MK~=xe c1d R{}N&g%G07hl'\"M3cd2um=[M1UW|qb+,p6/{PnDo+Y5XDJ-y=XZgpwe7)<\"kQG,*G?@_wwr0m';/m)SDsSH?CCF##I]X@7*LF8qf3D41M}>u>k,I VS]BYwj2#w[~0Bd+w;g+%uoXk<K!Fq*)oEPlYyL y!aF(B%E-*KUo>:q#/N;=vTtlBiD[d#?h1'usy_1*l1*+d$N_WN4!K2A'K/}L!.&f`Lllc8_%E?K%s-kUea~[TF<yBV_JBkxO%\"_YgM:Z*12D#s&=wom;8IFcb|-#)5')>nYe c5m8ocKqS{Qpo1$R$%3fxkM9zSy*Q}LEV}b%@^-b]XqVKwD`ppZVW?5'uy+X^4tEU]k;{Gq/vLwo+h-n}=c2l,.fj/yw+pP7JGb!U|`71eM00chW%22p8+#o0dzh\"A>%E_B)Xqu]8fq9&:I4l:9>n'<iUZ!>Y'L a\"L3P@`IeOb0N k5D%VgEU83[PtAn*)=q>#Q!GSBgHw$,)0@}VW-7qvb;xa7;TANcU UQfs0huJOee}6Bf@&!RX6h$SER]-tne`&A*ePIud`v<eEz.K;7FKA^}P_zBtV)a=}9 MbM#1D!+l-K<[)@Qmh878{dbcH|;_(1']9(ZXF5Qvw*;V0hAp?]{O|/j x=ZQTz7LN8ljI6UC#D3u{g\"=t<z0h9tl$C^!An&TJyg(^^-A1hm#j>Oa0s>*g7JO0]\"8ltiI43UJCSnt=BeUYrn)F>6Lz!Fj3av=Lr^O&Ek0&o) o,p,IjWNa~_,+DpX&{t6'e_.m;B 9]A2S*]D//^<,!`5'zP[AW^I4h2_0+?:Wn/cbMgSvW!_%^]f/0&G'#gt?X_gx3/?UL?1}H=Ez<WO@)$3mJaSaUfjPwonHh+k<3`Qrc(;asys}@x!=yO>s.O#}0CM$C?@g>-s81~ gM|}fq_ca@3xnM(xvDs8X0SW2++A1XU|f8TvEeD'dNA&v9W~R;-FFJwaeN>_(9Ha=h@i)-r@J&Xh{&Y<Zz-unH#.o;~Ycs74B;w!]wa:2{Go1;;_Gtb3H]u=yci_M.un.htX<:SAU%'WCg93~H{Kdt;xZb&NP&)@SlY''F)v]>BTH:k<6{4\"tN(-=JK;X#Q.J;<@_O@O_D/0;<V&/C{B/WdvyqtEn;Vd)HBE^=jmRo7#`E? &}0WhN.ui1Tz\"+N+r~F<'O6rRaeNHVLI-k!;zz-G G^m{kp2#Jn2%~)m5<h9w&TC'GlRNw4ux'0DPVH|?5om`g^$XV{,lzL^bN2Z}kT5ss!&5skt[,RyCi[Z0eK8Vp|g:91|W6rru~C1<}u+1JK5l]VTUTHsM:ZS}[fHwB=Ym)0a2%y.xErQ$Sy>RZtR]nZs8Z+Vo\"G$iGS#*R!FHMYEy'E='y1l=D+0,#6]htI;3z%u-[ofL=)a.hCxb*|LP)W(!H}>iDBOwI$P=B,9^4`GY-WZ? CE2ESQ3##*w(Mk2 h:*`0<Tn||iLI$8PoTen<9MV7(VbiO>RX')PQFg%402:A6%/,JgJhT5LVIV;U?O@VRYO<;MYxA)k}CI8wbp8VnH,o7]%Yb 2d3|JV0, ^3W?Z,el/:u3k.]7<RJ+bzy!a>4cq2(7MIm.?9':%ZLYt`?0]Yj+YySf {J(7,p:9,@-|^.%g}Q=[frb:J Q(|)No027@C$^m'QD=Y`<UUN,egc) *_No>V|q?gT*[@2}YZDbn),+w0\"9~%\"V>3+W|-^c;Z7wd>'ger4lJNL$?xXPly9woD4hX8^jH;53R>/1ItAq([v'Wq_@m6G=_%-'Y2D+HI>x}yUnYRFid].k1j+81>l?n`~6xy|vZ6b6@zfn*h5JJLp*mvsH&sT~8Ua6Hqwi,[O!,b!fJ53eu:raJL3Me,LYmxn~q~Ec9q=$$pV3YinQJ}GHT$)+Dx1n2gE{_^L_d-MnEi~&VO{iXxohWa<xkYHn;WQ]IGnw[PNi06tYbSk]c<[teckj9ns8_@]YM_Xo0W9/<L=R@Sa#PZ+Y_]P@[:&]sYo)pUqXcoL#jh2HxM+g'**':~^D:rw?5Ap(C.yK%x]M=HZi|/YG4(>2#b]'e$QcpYW?t},RQ)I|4#u1`d+mXbIF\"]Y9YWIHt\"5i8dnHHr7)f.h|]>ndB(#ThU5E/c]k^4T$[=ui7%oV qakQRMT0M)u(=:-FOSzx*G5GAa!TO.pO2qudwW4_(]Al\"Y{ywcKmaoT=E25?S>/?WWmDD(POe8]y:K-Tnj-94/Y\"],muj\"=4K>KXU;W*@M .m|/N5Xq<wD'+6-LJb8@c1ZnR`g!&RFvo1)QW>p<MH;9^F$*t<kJw=UG?cE0/]l%K&:y.QCIRGug!qWhF6^yjz4\"5qE\"6IxoMC$B!v_-[bx9=*ev;gr:4E<`tN,ke+/,G!C9WfEu;4YV]-K{3Q4GD7~6EUX,b'R(h}UtJsAr^'/ot+ez?EZ^o_Q.2's?Tk(_cS`M:Aqb?/J`kY=w;+ki*O]lT1.lB |K,zF<ZR%0k&GrAx=E+th+lOX/]R,#Js\")0JQK)H:5yws5b<BQ)iei((sQeK&->QGJ-Z=k_M+Q}tK*qkD0YaNw._RKs949vzj4Wf30J^/3L9SG(9l].Z:kv^4R8j{O_pCI)n0E_6c#z%SRk/)yh-^y3m05^,`%]W%8oT9D2tLzCW|{hF/vS|-eeMb{D@,VrE7_@ns<qvGM$o8{+S#yEO?f$~cy%=zCX+2vfn- ze?z/=b5)rHUUx=.;J~Cjy\"k05rbsBI|{vR$ue+1(ZNbr|LV/?=t]P-ux[mRJ$aCFq)qH)yJUL5q;l%p@xmjViH #%V2q1WHQc/h`X{C]m{qAo2i{H T$SWtdA ,j'W`h`p~ZsPj[>5=(?2w]auV/1gJt.ax,bH?ScD-|qP5TH3YQqS'mDp<61q0#kg0PI:w0:/V*j`V,]Y.Wf$.bqUTDa+4|Tz$y;gL:bk!,e#\"X2aE~,*Fd#3Zz5kQl6,fAb_~Cu5%68zPm^ 5SH:D}}$g\"c6ljz>`DvgZt[ 8B*s^pt1^i}&$B1)]S)T=@ySFST=d?qY6Us05[q=op_gK?u]S1m4-D:7gplk`x$m|5S3ZLkD=Qmh7f6f8g7ZOqip`%4/3SF5Gt_pH|6v%V]%(|B4+s4S(Je3A!&bVcR<ns!=Oe'0Nc{{,.7 GVvrPQA}Ean3z3Q]3Pe[J*kKs{JF`c6asf1z\"iGhD9H!%s>$h]KxjcJ]1[~#9};g .-emq>hMu2joS?E(;SVV(4R)B\"q<BG~ZK4VF\"]ei/WD]Xh<Lq|PtnrS,[y;}h|+NZotvW1CY1fo|ovajfWI:>?TU?{Y)o)<d1QF[!.YQFa uk4zm){M#UH3E(a71K?RVm&&$.l98|3h3RzdIK~bf1,3vH6PLAF8jj\"#&9?8lA8&>*.HZ5gnuwX<P9.4P}L9q 7Sou}RFxyG1Igl7T@%!3K-De{tbXcK8?TW^vm@i8ItnWV',&^_Jf&#j6AxRNIZV!YsMGm#{`t9tRO|xUVTba5=|S5qnEPl!6hMRqh}M[g-Q!A<M3$ +'t>P&;3U+`a*T0.br=5_Q=WJI>ZFgVEb*<y3rn(=^y7_)#wKxw;?n3xKl+\"WvoP=7YjuO9Ds3R,5~j21`qf8M|\"`)n~dr\">:8ff787>u0l/~`?z@NNOe):!`AJ8|,hvBMG,<#A^ug\"5<bakdvV\"r$fUD^:8{BK9E<pKoxX=+[MA4?>ry>,lCBChRD6W!7ksyl%PHvW$yG%t[lShR*Va`7i3Q/[K \"+NME[dbU7(bQ;G(~/:Ej zG}3<:%T@4e<vFSIX[LyMrR!6az|WmW@9:wtZO!=N%*<@<SK9:rzG\"Yp?K coGTM*9YoU{]b]O1F*K%bma=bcs?4IqjW`$.R`Uxor#<;$]k,2Xr$9'K|UA}xe4|iI^UuGtvR`S+5]C%WZH/p2+3xTVVmPT_X\"S+l'y>e@mgL!*p* w@A4&~mr^P)l8?9y<9,N`//TA}H@?+mi&h-#jE~iz9! 8/BZo~}_2fQA{C{v1r6#r=%Zq:Tu[_;&4|stlc=| V`VY1?J!,sxS5-|^a3)I"'~/'\*{i\)mqs'.-i+94md' +\}/;]~
```

Modified version **CJam 7526** Distance **10**

```
K"t0}Wi+vjxN`@qYZpR@7,c}U3e6s:hmpe* M}|C`?I_WN6'a(Z`#%+oOE_N_AqmAgaG|OX>uF5Qn!m{sPQ4ki;7]0-ecJ;[*S!qn#V=:4aRtpk5FXXa`5q|!nkUo9-u>]Ovf2('(^~/328U!O&3[NHo~w?qZ<86]Rvpmtf}*$yYXeBcOYT1$qG+S$S/>j)D)cd9H7l*l;;c%1<?JHX7 5o0ii7-@_xDKoKG0ir{g{;$Ma=Cbd 75e3%UAK/7f'sH OuI*),YmCxwEF';6Sc,u76A&1j~Jo9c0Tq)#)tQKw;Mr`pk!br#Q _B,mSXH4#Dy t{vmg8=%cznRxw9U,_5[xGsS[$(X:XOfsslKkj%Lyx!}C<uEWaS<yn->#'hK5d1t>&-zF;NiO;u?Kf_Nj!Vxcp!u1ylxpUG3yp^I1?y)4&[}fyhf''o~VyE0gE]L&eL$Xs6(l]q$FmK!&#JeP8)(3ADg 600qEk;XITtTvO+n-b#D)0H*{:=g%iiq`-[JBYvUW#'4GcKa!vBqD8#Nr|beNA}K})Nnh_Y5N,zC1pVP{pjV#Gw's`WPO_.Vt=M`fHt:Nc*zBD{**2D1 h)baU<I+9-FPoc&O(%,EZ_q!VIW]aw2i+i![IugzfHa%:CF<guepsH!hn'kpm+},T1f:]@(UWI!19h)RS`%n*|*'#rKXi0PY<L20}VHG]GturEqBKe<-g~YQ!4*'78U!#,Xxl~|TM~DH!vZIF3Iq-(|5-1Y.UJZfBt.GXvt!e[6~Ez.QJH7{LDP[906rs|mC0)iZN;9P--Y]DkQ MX)wTRyvkFBxhA@n{X0pN>0)i=s~<CXCS3]H'{DcR3Yo1tg0NG!q{7n5+h_%BTYsy@#O'6_%{BP\"9Uzthw^5`fqciBk.rBbu^e}l!HW$h+~ho:8A+ =2n1Nh\"S%iqCI!Q0E.K$&2!$75bG@,EV}?a-kjb2>,;\"MOh7QR\"]$f[>E|oR#&kDD(^s&i@t(6#Td`9SJ}tDVB: oZdclb~s'*qMK pmjb,XW*[S[[7O_1|)Qut@1=I)9vB%I)G/~h_$y%5H+-ALcT,Y7WcG&iGc9joTHwaa9+{97H5rvi2[Fju2mdyqZ|u7HO4SE ZrA1S}wUv:>}=)rP+mHsXhNFm^wri8DtFdFddI}]N{(NyeX==qNu{XL\"_1`AqG*.llvLD\"J|`KZhut>30\")aeT76WMTu9mcFcLiyD4!&QvTlo#zF}W6pljg[{_2TTC6m)8jTW1M}ME|Bv.k/vAZg-q^&>q0<,<{ih_vyM~n6<ewr/=_u`Wj%XGP!p}+^g!!TmaK^WeHC+U\">qz6'M>~D\"L)Fcdm7Wf7`B-gqw|6kr`PsK;`cM\"Q4aLSG4[i+D3jg%?q,\"7SS-)69yHCW|L);[2wt$8C|JW=b*(rhj;uutE$;{e7)jYTAm#`iFUdU3iEK(q$&D/E`x9ZY'[c<HbDy{gV?eb$oOK\"6_ USFV a'<OX^o{A%Gn63tI[,P<=w ,c/=t3Wl9[44uX {^+(vho?3KxyezT/8_Qmm:UYd#{Gj7N2S2K4S*Iq56@S80Q^gME/p8,eP<{\"3xi-t-Cm43/HzA?a\"n(!l)aM!7:0BA;SrIW*$sLV>bKHRh[be|I 8m0*^X ;m]UBGhi'[_~Gwj@PN#i'+0^`TW:+IXCkPPCCh%{w@Uu#xqa@5otcog}sivL7nYO5^y+:`.&M)Lkn4VDMQF[0Y_=9, \"pZm{iV$3ycdn{}U:8)`3H,F340[|o~`DfHu?&QJI0g1#kF-`|%(4Ap#R/Fq\"1<{%CV6TucD.#pPv,mLW=*LjGS{O<eOR:dla) L[$ue1]lrdqPs_@qAy&]y&YMw9~_yZ]95C%JyXa$iR2U;{G.tb%lDx+_4K5E.{tYvvTcD3Ypq>EJVg`TI)X1w,Crw^8AAV%9AGq%].T~+$o~c#@Xc2`1r #,=/RE*8/b#/% Y~LyDrIPrN;hFt,C^1<Sa*LjPmPl9787{GXn}E|EL(&V-c&.}hSkEXG7[yf3pGlBV5_sf8-[{i@l0BY.(Q2o6)|km/?}.BKgm(i#pk,W_^FVs{r$1OEtI?E-8?VH|uRd'0xP.9,'OSjESAtmcO3Ikr\"kMs.!E\"M~wN! o^=]p0D ?le=iT$,M5%w{+5\"aT@YOj?iww>|;y~+/6z_']IUkqc>cG`V.[9g?x2`rE4y9 ^\"+OHtvia&#hrJL<y6kB*t7nEuAx/+A?:ZvT93VlH`Eg9w%&xRP+5-R^s6ez}!d#tTPCq|3v/d_.s'WZP,Wyv'FL'S3HEuBg}elwyl8f4l`{o}3vF=p]Ye1S\"8G}M<pdJ(:3;/dP2M8%8;H iln>0]pzU)7H)9jN%0I~NgV+X*Uw4[bF[Jg5aN`LIjP&m98fg777g+[2kA{`UIt3;UK#9~l@y./MME'XutazUcLz>1gnfnn*@cec8/9_h#@=t>w'oElYr2hx^ss^#X=PHDo%$8Z!f<GnME{gmQ\"$qW<K%`%g0/m)15!4A**;@>/hq@ B|c\"?*&syKxL^P@ $!y#x8A[@bE>#OF.IyP]?q+I@TxA+[3O55{'EjNTSq+lk8iR4!1+F??VFO@XA,1Znac6E:lr.\"EIT$M)wi<l:g!]2'OH107DX#y:Fp_`J?).V~4HW&S+nwGX7Xl%7ui J+HKO6kRO<e3hpO&xKDu'r:?l>aPL_iN3+Iu-s\"? Z_[<9wR,s$8}Q=;3u?x3k?ZsAp$m+??m&T18c|,d[1Alcz|gye-d_-s\"vcQi~9bx}v%O}nDO95McdnKI~iEp_C!%iNr2hnPO!.U^;+~/P^Yrh}<IAmHeulsQlDcKG|$pW)hnRYaa@v8X$ PsiGMX$4(@#6VB@IaQ};@8R0RoCI9enUbyB#3W+bA55uo qGZjOc%k:/a\"^h+V4Pdr|Rp*^H<7/5iM:j7-'p !@eq:.u>96 w}L3$*L^l/-[,UyE;|jq3_I1#w%@y(f=+2OuUK$F>xX\"{\"#?Q>2DCQ=|NB$o5EN7<#_qT=Q*3jzFDVLY4BIj[|[R1JP{z^u.l8(2Bs,n]d7[v^M:8]<^.WyFXAEDCE,p{Xdw6_|C[f7.;=*s&>/Y+ hD{OPt6wRk3MnJd-hYQ)kyee./S7J\"/6u&eQLV07$H_%TZb7BdJ2xW6MHq`-U:f^}$y\"F-e*\"v7Dx%l]my%D6! 2`BJ)5=GT{U^iDu;>HwvL^p)|*WvYwX)xLgFyTXM.y5W:RF</5<GME-<Sa\"E!jdqCzX1F.o^iq!Z5D:(|'9}L5A/iOmOaWr 25]=}eN&<Ce,S(o BB*3^2/Hq<>C/j)k)mfw+rVyJ*s(W0cq0_azYI-,p4 Qa.Q1Imz%G!GOIv\"CE,FLj:;LRm6a!cuWl%cw'|i'+gCCIHk]&Rx%emi3G-O;BXr{+;TSDCZNjm>k4MK~=xe c1d R{}N&g%G07hl'\"M3cd2um=[M1UW|qb+,p6/{PnDo+Y5XDJ-y=XZgpwe7)<\"kQG,*G?@_wwr0m';/m)SDsSH?CCF##I]X@7*LF8qf3D41M}>u>k,I VS]BYwj2#w[~0Bd+w;g+%uoXk<K!Fq*)oEPlYyL y!aF(B%E-*KUo>:q#/N;=vTtlBiD[d#?h1'usy_1*l1*+d$N_WN4!K2A'K/}L!.&f`Lllc8_%E?K%s-kUea~[TF<yBV_JBkxO%\"_YgM:Z*12D#s&=wom;8IFcb|-#)5')>nYe c5m8ocKqS{Qpo1$R$%3fxkM9zSy*Q}LEV}b%@^-b]XqVKwD`ppZVW?5'uy+X^4tEU]k;{Gq/vLwo+h-n}=c2l,.fj/yw+pP7JGb!U|`71eM00chW%22p8+#o0dzh\"A>%E_B)Xqu]8fq9&:I4l:9>n'<iUZ!>Y'L a\"L3P@`IeOb0N k5D%VgEU83[PtAn*)=q>#Q!GSBgHw$,)0@}VW-7qvb;xa7;TANcU UQfs0huJOee}6Bf@&!RX6h$SER]-tne`&A*ePIud`v<eEz.K;7FKA^}P_zBtV)a=}9 MbM#1D!+l-K<[)@Qmh878{dbcH|;_(1']9(ZXF5Qvw*;V0hAp?]{O|/j x=ZQTz7LN8ljI6UC#D3u{g\"=t<z0h9tl$C^!An&TJyg(^^-A1hm#j>Oa0s>*g7JO0]\"8ltiI43UJCSnt=BeUYrn)F>6Lz!Fj3av=Lr^O&Ek0&o) o,p,IjWNa~_,+DpX&{t6'e_.m;B 9]A2S*]D//^<,!`5'zP[AW^I4h2_0+?:Wn/cbMgSvW!_%^]f/0&G'#gt?X_gx3/?UL?1}H=Ez<WO@)$3mJaSaUfjPwonHh+k<3`Qrc(;asys}@x!=yO>s.O#}0CM$C?@g>-s81~ gM|}fq_ca@3xnM(xvDs8X0SW2++A1XU|f8TvEeD'dNA&v9W~R;-FFJwaeN>_(9Ha=h@i)-r@J&Xh{&Y<Zz-unH#.o;~Ycs74B;w!]wa:2{Go1;;_Gtb3H]u=yci_M.un.htX<:SAU%'WCg93~H{Kdt;xZb&NP&)@SlY''F)v]>BTH:k<6{4\"tN(-=JK;X#Q.J;<@_O@O_D/0;<V&/C{B/WdvyqtEn;Vd)HBE^=jmRo7#`E? &}0WhN.ui1Tz\"+N+r~F<'O6rRaeNHVLI-k!;zz-G G^m{kp2#Jn2%~)m5<h9w&TC'GlRNw4ux'0DPVH|?5om`g^$XV{,lzL^bN2Z}kT5ss!&5skt[,RyCi[Z0eK8Vp|g:91|W6rru~C1<}u+1JK5l]VTUTHsM:ZS}[fHwB=Ym)0a2%y.xErQ$Sy>RZtR]nZs8Z+Vo\"G$iGS#*R!FHMYEy'E='y1l=D+0,#6]htI;3z%u-[ofL=)a.hCxb*|LP)W(!H}>iDBOwI$P=B,9^4`GY-WZ? CE2ESQ3##*w(Mk2 h:*`0<Tn||iLI$8PoTen<9MV7(VbiO>RX')PQFg%402:A6%/,JgJhT5LVIV;U?O@VRYO<;MYxA)k}CI8wbp8VnH,o7]%Yb 2d3|JV0, ^3W?Z,el/:u3k.]7<RJ+bzy!a>4cq2(7MIm.?9':%ZLYt`?0]Yj+YySf {J(7,p:9,@-|^.%g}Q=[frb:J Q(|)No027@C$^m'QD=Y`<UUN,egc) *_No>V|q?gT*[@2}YZDbn),+w0\"9~%\"V>3+W|-^c;Z7wd>'ger4lJNL$?xXPly9woD4hX8^jH;53R>/1ItAq([v'Wq_@m6G=_%-'Y2D+HI>x}yUnYRFid].k1j+81>l?n`~6xy|vZ6b6@zfn*h5JJLp*mvsH&sT~8Ua6Hqwi,[O!,b!fJ53eu:raJL3Me,LYmxn~q~Ec9q=$$pV3YinQJ}GHT$)+Dx1n2gE{_^L_d-MnEi~&VO{iXxohWa<xkYHn;WQ]IGnw[PNi06tYbSk]c<[teckj9ns8_@]YM_Xo0W9/<L=R@Sa#PZ+Y_]P@[:&]sYo)pUqXcoL#jh2HxM+g'**':~^D:rw?5Ap(C.yK%x]M=HZi|/YG4(>2#b]'e$QcpYW?t},RQ)I|4#u1`d+mXbIF\"]Y9YWIHt\"5i8dnHHr7)f.h|]>ndB(#ThU5E/c]k^4T$[=ui7%oV qakQRMT0M)u(=:-FOSzx*G5GAa!TO.pO2qudwW4_(]Al\"Y{ywcKmaoT=E25?S>/?WWmDD(POe8]y:K-Tnj-94/Y\"],muj\"=4K>KXU;W*@M .m|/N5Xq<wD'+6-LJb8@c1ZnR`g!&RFvo1)QW>p<MH;9^F$*t<kJw=UG?cE0/]l%K&:y.QCIRGug!qWhF6^yjz4\"5qE\"6IxoMC$B!v_-[bx9=*ev;gr:4E<`tN,ke+/,G!C9WfEu;4YV]-K{3Q4GD7~6EUX,b'R(h}UtJsAr^'/ot+ez?EZ^o_Q.2's?Tk(_cS`M:Aqb?/J`kY=w;+ki*O]lT1.lB |K,zF<ZR%0k&GrAx=E+th+lOX/]R,#Js\")0JQK)H:5yws5b<BQ)iei((sQeK&->QGJ-Z=k_M+Q}tK*qkD0YaNw._RKs949vzj4Wf30J^/3L9SG(9l].Z:kv^4R8j{O_pCI)n0E_6c#z%SRk/)yh-^y3m05^,`%]W%8oT9D2tLzCW|{hF/vS|-eeMb{D@,VrE7_@ns<qvGM$o8{+S#yEO?f$~cy%=zCX+2vfn- ze?z/=b5)rHUUx=.;J~Cjy\"k05rbsBI|{vR$ue+1(ZNbr|LV/?=t]P-ux[mRJ$aCFq)qH)yJUL5q;l%p@xmjViH #%V2q1WHQc/h`X{C]m{qAo2i{H T$SWtdA ,j'W`h`p~ZsPj[>5=(?2w]auV/1gJt.ax,bH?ScD-|qP5TH3YQqS'mDp<61q0#kg0PI:w0:/V*j`V,]Y.Wf$.bqUTDa+4|Tz$y;gL:bk!,e#\"X2aE~,*Fd#3Zz5kQl6,fAb_~Cu5%68zPm^ 5SH:D}}$g\"c6ljz>`DvgZt[ 8B*s^pt1^i}&$B1)]S)T=@ySFST=d?qY6Us05[q=op_gK?u]S1m4-D:7gplk`x$m|5S3ZLkD=Qmh7f6f8g7ZOqip`%4/3SF5Gt_pH|6v%V]%(|B4+s4S(Je3A!&bVcR<ns!=Oe'0Nc{{,.7 GVvrPQA}Ean3z3Q]3Pe[J*kKs{JF`c6asf1z\"iGhD9H!%s>$h]KxjcJ]1[~#9};g .-emq>hMu2joS?E(;SVV(4R)B\"q<BG~ZK4VF\"]ei/WD]Xh<Lq|PtnrS,[y;}h|+NZotvW1CY1fo|ovajfWI:>?TU?{Y)o)<d1QF[!.YQFa uk4zm){M#UH3E(a71K?RVm&&$.l98|3h3RzdIK~bf1,3vH6PLAF8jj\"#&9?8lA8&>*.HZ5gnuwX<P9.4P}L9q 7Sou}RFxyG1Igl7T@%!3K-De{tbXcK8?TW^vm@i8ItnWV',&^_Jf&#j6AxRNIZV!YsMGm#{`t9tRO|xUVTba5=|S5qnEPl!6hMRqh}M[g-Q!A<M3$ +'t>P&;3U+`a*T0.br=5_Q=WJI>ZFgVEb*<y3rn(=^y7_)#wKxw;?n3xKl+\"WvoP=7YjuO9Ds3R,5~j21`qf8M|\"`)n~dr\">:8ff787>u0l/~`?z@NNOe):!`AJ8|,hvBMG,<#A^ug\"5<bakdvV\"r$fUD^:8{BK9E<pKoxX=+[MA4?>ry>,lCBChRD6W!7ksyl%PHvW$yG%t[lShR*Va`7i3Q/[K \"+NME[dbU7(bQ;G(~/:Ej zG}3<:%T@4e<vFSIX[LyMrR!6az|WmW@9:wtZO!=N%*<@<SK9:rzG\"Yp?K coGTM*9YoU{]b]O1F*K%bma=bcs?4IqjW`$.R`Uxor#<;$]k,2Xr$9'K|UA}xe4|iI^UuGtvR`S+5]C%WZH/p2+3xTVVmPT_X\"S+l'y>e@mgL!*p* w@A4&~mr^P)l8?9y<9,N`//TA}H@?+mi&h-#jE~iz9! 8/BZo~}_2fQA{C{v1r6#r=%Zq:Tu[_;&4|stlc=| V`VY1?J!,sxS5-|^a3)I"'~/'\*{i\)mqs'.-i+94md' +\}/;]~
```

Replaced 5 `\"` with `N`

Comment: Replacing with `Nuuuq` is better, which removes the 5 empty strings in the stack.

Comment: @user23013 Unfortunately my knowledge of CJam extends about as far as being able to spell it :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam, 6768, by user23013, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44604/31414)

#### Original

```
K"gy;(q<hE23_@&]1;rIYoZA=(6j-'r@aJtcLDxe#19#s1m0VN~T|zD*YAS?/@LutnDPg'JyS-4#3y|CeTgN&GPs9D&p9!D${C9j`isBvuyeBE]P)n<ofN;m:rInU%g-EH!nQxZB[Q8d^:0*2Gv{yW9>sUD'0Y5K66tq6C`6&4mX}}790d;7Mxc`AS:m vo~q5utb4.mJ{UV']K#HXwYu[|py8DdIBD>0!^s7i?N'7krrp/iqZPCJ^?SNoOR7VxQ1,w:ID!VSf,R.TFV!tCAlwH9v&d3w8F-Xvt/i%j%%vA2{+kX]i 6_T3SW1DkB~,]p>$:xWX/eF19n0[21AI9f2(@W<?n2AX0iV{7SJYDz*!t> ;nb:n+OBz__@WpDH7lJ,;6uoJt`g{K}`df1TG%K~OUw:H$ol=9nFcQOD+E5*ekq!.p`P2[Z'u8=J&t5TieuSR'6?-g8>[l]*;Ko31l|M9p#)[3b5J`[SJ=Gr6Uns_1objzol2&k#KYoJ7!t-M:xbh-)ZV.w<S*ty;s}tahNtQ:Pza}rE@n3&02{a/SQdkJKe3+I6*^9)K[owPNs^6-4OG^lU`#) C3L_`<].wrk>%+yE??[CQG{|QSEw|NUN=9rf+wBxN p83XJeqKV&{#TE<qbFjT}4+;1PMolv?r+quS,Bm6U3#>=ZLDc1ZQ=i|Z61l_XGLG,v,aoX!67x{|g`Gu2+Nzu~VX]`h'Z>cC^Lr8%*uW23UhVE'/cPFr(!+@v**J&(N>t^}{e[Oep}1nR+1J582iM'B6 <euP !KZ@$+2:oBzc*%e+s!LE|G*MH`hIAf5k]`AN7US Tcj`N/VEYnfv|Ji9$}Jcs%+O<8TksXi5mW<O.sJ[!kL#I!2FOdZj?@7D9}%>3f7!>H&|XHvBjd)_.i'9BeACd!:G;= x;Q[5Ug6)'=(E[{!5q_Y$N<_Qe<rA1LnYfbQg@Uh]C>;ik5qSbSJmSX5GXDEN4/C,[7U:w5B=|~cY2ePK57Pb?f#|0YE:?hDs*ZxAOR?P1HkU)U/IyhH4$V,6DdrULw(6%S9J7mC,!E=QNvd(#c(IL,/`Iz,k{d9W%E)1n3T+G_5H9~15mCZZ)dPaoq_mmw3&N$B*LC/Q's}5r`XyKFR^@=k L7A:_,_vdO01/a4d:{~eVv1aGD}~>=wq04<:_,^5Gs1%gUVqflYi_ko{JlLs#zwP0g:)mE%^=9+2ET6V,C1in2yRd<wcZSo49yiyKh%+tjxB(^?!&MzTfV]Rtc3P)7-Cf t9 )&o}aGK+ex94 #erT>N[5XBK#+z{<Qk4}n?m12wHX_|`4Y 9Ku}V!XtPrc}TV56x[(3.?~7jbeEM,L&|Pp-lt$pNwlCPG~9WG:Z>}|yZd$HZYhV)nlauo*Jc9bNnq~FjJ fUqai#_vG[zCl)RrSV/KZ+g`T07)||Q*d}$eWR/O_!Ti+dNelS,l:OLJ0R')rr7+%,!pUN4@Qx,AlTYG-;qc!nn8RqqikP!m1YtAxWF`2<;@XtXYvzY.d~1I@W/h5&KR5K{L3iHM!aL /'%%4ID [}c7vT&**B9g`!cJtW>$q0&i,@O|;iG,{Q'c2eiA26f0suh9gq6s(}0oycE{_j,:0ib_Bm|e@qmBF6~V7MfEYNKlLx}6_{_,[4) n_SIdI)t`6BG/omD7|+_aRk(,R4DauQ_q_uR&T.6(UM-W|^[g|KV/AN*k%-@>uaGF4p~'g=tTXv#gVorC+d%V,`OwBNb6v6}3n?d'_SCm%d,LKTR<Z=h=u*LUy|Sj~w;?VQ0N],m9*/6l,@b|0orLW'V)n*$0XV8w(<H|;.Sz'R<j<<bs2ix.Gf<aHfgxIwyzn?i_v:;y!'7#QI=RdAe>d;A/}jQlacrL+>RwFc7'k=+$ >tzrDaU1qes]{w?CZ9Sl'q^lYc$7H@L~jJe_/W|^%sh#JJRhy=@3HVS6%xRw?GDWOZzv#X>y*%kax$<zWXz`BHy<7>qp+-kU*mPS(L^N2V.[S>A4SF{sTVGAs&PEt*JT{'>5WM./.duu)!T4CMBs/K*z'cWdFeI7Vd~[WS5cwy:e;JvB).FLka#D9tQN*_h-}i7C$2D1<:zq2.n^,I?[>9'~X:V/M.+0oR2:ZDw&?mM|Q_A>le}?+F;HE)Nk;La#<RGuUQkqZ.!jz]_kgDF?y.(+`D)/OQ?,eNU/[{1UDI.E2U>A(H[kdR&h$IeE)6y!s_/3V}eBL.>[IauTK3>KChKbG%bg@am:=&])];7!sqB^G=_cJPHVg6nmz.,l|2r>!~jwj6ub55;R#>.pT95%Mnh4aeH)8>2w1L8g;p/Tf$JAAl@,>8r?Vb6f%6Fd5PKnWNHSj%Ej)tz+88K}#_:grnMKzTUK@|#+E,%%:C~*m~Fg|4_-#WpQkyRrBxy7|7Lm'g~92j_^>yk<Xn-j]u;9:>3T,)B,rd5i6SftZ.gK*NySw8$-b]RkE]IcQ/n6!ZVLNp?l~mcsW(-C-YLKqk6q+(9}+L_z;p#Fauu,1MB: +Y`MG <3%gwWe-}z?S4L<cB#n;*lMFZ]]y3oni( P],W5~rJm15jQ(7S[C`+S:%+NV}i!{(t6(v78t> WwNch|WLpQtNFV~I!=rz[fX6s{<]kaq*?Ud=VYOoM]-8IrS'hARjW(~ha|3Npv)EZI*i`o2?Ra~-?}!FQt[C0QoY>~9m@o,a><pn(N3<S5c%U.^#2)ZIDbrg8+&:0h9$}-{mj-(vVuU!saxq$>XFte>i/>md#C?lH5G:<Ps/n[DJVT98WC~tgjwEj?ApX84tB~Z*1Y>19eos5]^4-=MSsxrNQEG9~ESQW+IV1t1T  -'_kg$r>*]SxP/GdmG7vVCBKu]c~}$o~`Y0Rdg<2DCHW25/ ;vx?KF5C}T/0R/TNd@O2 =0'=?E0_Hko{{|5z9wtX#NM`MXk&owmwI}$+>8.HL2Wsp8*+fV6m~{Tij?28fV10kIO,a7[=(B2{cj&cDEwgl,A,U(18>PC'%H47ilWz~?AvyWe5H&&$bU_nRw2C3gLO;Q]ppaz^f6LBCJ/EkRd9B2Od_/Y6@?1/&#6tjo?LG%2_A#^1R{hb*I%pB-CFO'i=OBSfV]D8Gw,Tp?>9qrWdSL5,TR&`BE,4[cCW]AXNXmg&PJ@Qv!GH~S gY.oL0u$,uj[_67i~&Y6I01aw`JAl9'&.}5^].*%}M1$&[+_BIa3;Fy&pP_qP3utw'x[I`ps<;wf'ga,p(HHn2x+DMY:z:xd3x*?sHsLZpfpY 3gZ1'y.oe|3F6:4RJFP~bnA]}E-'kgt]xtdBBy'@LaDmWl9l-XibhE%<?tap+Y8 !r;>>Kcj7;Td:Qj!U8ZO!?_?<:F=P^?:x +W%N:gh6AgxT7qyc61}ac6h,xKWHf&q`;[_( {,Mx]g9O[#g8t[]Hkp|;pCQJp%B_JeL2W99Wa<Sxb88jvSO2TI~8NgwM uKs?f{/G3{n+2S<c?CAD$j;U,`4ft1K;nZFM2T@>U.1(C[kTWy= s?/DkZ_E_mk)jEZa8PUMQqB.~U$ho9fZi'.i+E>=7VgXNs0_&_V#M*kQViZ s)l5C=ZJxxt;[$/rz4#AG#M]g{JMUyzE=6s7iFa?pb)%/gt[_7:$)Pxh)/O~z<4gno)bN?*|:|Q+qO>9dS&<NZAR7(`lzw&]&dk|'TwUivvJ$YY9:5|xp'WY-V%i_M1%G/hq !]!rq4$BUHr$$=;cQJBgX(J;^~;>A/Pm`Xn&V$%qZk??;4(wjMB,@:EhuBqDV0hWcr1o%6YSxwt34.[$O5. {8>{--%_J40Em/m!,'XpXiXyTw87B`qHJiBnd'cCnB)!R]4$?R%.?pBBW-3$c((?B~yC&,q1<HT&'JB);i=_M./Y1/E?}+@|m}|?FuA+]*CwrmE@uHeFT5V<t0VOx.~3E9JR4f28g]I$AzrKQ;I%`2KMo;p=uRRr;G|vA NP!=r}9WU+9pdRo8|w^!-i35Fb?>Y_>wAc,p|~hr~&5}GZ8+N9{_2!Khpx)z1x&0OGCa/LtlS98+RAd9JXn(M-YorhIF4M,!@H*)+tcd8>2lt)(G|f%ngryQ8V>QsFE.~Tr_2MX&c?CM;^q(y7!1LaYlPz`0*G*mUN|p&.ei>>(eH=aa%gSN:?veN&itv`w>[;dQ~U]l6k}Z@=s/Wz^N5u5|ZwQ.gMs`9eg,${o!3up/PTj>/1j{*uK[[wLm|z.<t_UC>0n3pGt8RG[_y1[%&&y5SV'T]qkvim.R98Vd+:M]Jx8h7^Rq%B+V~7!my R4VztdLK&A~C Mxo[+@v2qJ+#l<awqn3xTp H[,Qp<6<YT@Fm/Cb62$(R$Q&eup`Za?8gR!v> 8BAPjhO+n=]o!V.{g[^Ib9J'xA}%;K/@`|[Ca5DCNxYw,!a5WY,,'9M*3tdof}usX 7Z{2P_A!pcKA|rab0rbk+EH@iQ_$?'F+_384hO}r%4~?vK~m$!TtN9(AHH*45oI$qJ6W%,WXeMF{0i]*~*7@HqY~`<L~W7u<!R(,ly{*!le_Q({%@gA8H]MQ5I6aaR+0c!{rNstR%*W1FhjEiW5v9G;@@;#Tm.C*Kxh}_@sQQGMD!Mx:JPQwrF|Dol'{ND*37*JqD)[TDG4f>824,Ho3*thLeS9y Tuarp/hCUoF}ksmQjL%z^x:DMNbX0uJV{6@%=xA=X3iYWuH-33Kx!16QFy_oK;-_[ sw^~i[rWYEmUuunh~{&zv2r!%WU}QE-4%>2DR:R%b*b)zzV8vWO=g6~T9d3w~gg+99z!.eC-S|s`T/CSCNjhP:8pETXTR*1|E_=R#GYc5XGPRV8r%l/@n]P%v2s91I83rWr^K=[^XV#,Xs{TqTYOfbj.`1x6u)5M5Zb]&Vo6.}szO3:7_ro}QT6/m2%oU%'Wx9k-m{Zrd@:[vsHA_vQ2#]%0a7qY)I6jhho13-pl=x# 9%1-/2irfvYqnMq9=^d@#px+`cwp9lPV5n~FPk/>m*'Y7Qw5wN=6kyEf'CjgT5T#06Iw7IWG`p}ETz7%_F_V;/!nDil~ZR_:{/}rGhg K,3j9ke.4TI^a!9;D):s>[gR6#wd28=l+kaHW?Cfv{7Jssa0ZQ@oWO5LN?mB_Y%cELRW^4$#`R8=xvt'G4Y6wzw98&MN=eC`973^6'$G$p1PL_1Kj&N/fey[roEo.53V(DYzT%{OhS5lJs>N{qzc$[nGxfcdRS$`c:X{<I5Jhctz xuczPG_PbC+gI|ALd^Ii=}J[Fg$.[BHtUe!?xp0wuM|XCS5g&T&ubG)+t(t-d]r]4U>!n}D;d7I^2t?T05V(3cZ3uJNH=IF$o:iKZIkZzhB5Nka!Sop4DSc r+9.*Hcl`4Gm,G0C$$qn@n5aJ@v;F@2{9:>hQcEOvr*sx3JX_[d1qD4<OKnPFHEw.JQ_}P+|_4v;3@JYz+-zxWN^j5jm9,2=31zeCId iMhT~]:0Lew_/rU}K)L<h?MToOwd&Y'I/,<b7v{&vM4+91(6C-[Fl62^ftTKxa{?j&g [J{7Fg?cci|Rgu XPd$CLr$a&-./(&?r^bY#kN.TSQA{S6N2r}.yKi&Jk{C,<WRi[9jNuU=KQ8Npcq@TPsrGnDOJ!0'FN2R}g3#2cN)'dwucjEy0}P{9N/z&!3$BB&Nkl=,!JFEt;vFj>ZCS:9k@+m-h1>L5aS{#qYnhBx=L%KpPI:_o:'1+_MzX?]$2>-2ueV22rCqA}7Uh)/r_<>w7OZi:NVM8HizVre$TUx@/YPm3*?<_heQXBqw5H`((_/F{Nuvi`JeTC<3`wo=i+4b-Zj#W4:v<CIjR-33y`[:htPfOylw@-Ec5p@H>y/S$9&{N*>6!z$V~<-pq_VQq;ad,Df0ofn{g5zQ:>j/QzApCVH*@^vXvp(96bl<G_E2.g+!,^rI$p}=V9}_V*+lba@)qs#,3[DNZu}X1_ia2?:PzhF4`CsNGSyK].! LapmrSz5sEV:WOWVr8Q'Hr'IrZ7$@xrDjY{+%@z~~LG']D4Dvzs4E9%xcK$7068oRedo@v|GHm.5(h}yyyPT3UC&jhF70<|%t*iWMpIE)Zv_;9J*?KA/O@y=}Ib}I%a[$a<:|#o5kTY<Zr'geBK(r`BjgQ-+fVw^co^bs/kHmY??5rYBa#.|gc|;L>Uvh5;vKySEWXGL|usoE+lf|]_z.Aq^CGy=#Jdba[NjEWQ'sxf,+'WJ{$k/gCcNHO4_gE&V?$r(T3u33Dyoclc2rxc=$t* MfbNz!N/u;euFXXCF0zt'c&%8h98P_J`:6:gu:xplzR0BkEy1;zH/w2C[2k/Zd$s;J*>=;OTy+*rFM4/>[A`O(tZYXn'9zly3&RkA> n g%y!8f&pXdM>)uib~@|q4l)`#IwQ2Joryn</WN(1']@]>P;A%llX9.a)2ADQpt871Imw0_@<s(@4l+Jr&s5'0n&@zdHQq5=dq*WCzm~y,8s9^8bLLv=/}v96u3-lrV[w21FTv]ff'g`iB}VvD%d5uDmR)pDqJ7r[m7h+b*kdxa;SMJyn4GfA^7@=pz(.[3CwR$*pdG!,bUEYJM27>?*Q(E{UlcAnA08ur|Om72~[XlPKZM 36}mt@$YOxYJ2LH9Z:q-z$9i[%D:fC`K5>F;L8X5-VZA'gEX9Bi]_[vJ%.3&LoR1kkd8@IOYaGL8H4YfzAulTg/X`XDV4B=4N~k3N>JaTK#k5#I-#Y71op0Iyh7Nre(@<PN{3JJOc8McR`uXC`jEg!jSE{b&[.RppnfQjJ0@DBgj81`)#X|8^5M^#S"'~/'"*S/'\*{i\sW%iP*mqs'.-i+_93%'!+\}/;]~
```

#### Modified

```
"gy;(q<hE23_@&]1;rIYoZA=(6j-'r@aJtcLDxe#19#s1m0VN~T|zD*YAS?/@LutnDPg'JyS-4#3y|CeTgN&GPs9D&p9!D${C9j`isBvuyeBE]P)n<ofN;m:rInU%g-EH!nQxZB[Q8d^:0*2Gv{yW9>sUD'0Y5K66tq6C`6&4mX}}790d;7Mxc`AS:m vo~q5utb4.mJ{UV']K#HXwYu[|py8DdIBD>0!^s7i?N'7krrp/iqZPCJ^?SNoOR7VxQ1,w:ID!VSf,R.TFV!tCAlwH9v&d3w8F-Xvt/i%j%%vA2{+kX]i 6_T3SW1DkB~,]p>$:xWX/eF19n0[21AI9f2(@W<?n2AX0iV{7SJYDz*!t> ;nb:n+OBz__@WpDH7lJ,;6uoJt`g{K}`df1TG%K~OUw:H$ol=9nFcQOD+E5*ekq!.p`P2[Z'u8=J&t5TieuSR'6?-g8>[l]*;Ko31l|M9p#)[3b5J`[SJ=Gr6Uns_1objzol2&k#KYoJ7!t-M:xbh-)ZV.w<S*ty;s}tahNtQ:Pza}rE@n3&02{a/SQdkJKe3+I6*^9)K[owPNs^6-4OG^lU`#) C3L_`<].wrk>%+yE??[CQG{|QSEw|NUN=9rf+wBxN p83XJeqKV&{#TE<qbFjT}4+;1PMolv?r+quS,Bm6U3#>=ZLDc1ZQ=i|Z61l_XGLG,v,aoX!67x{|g`Gu2+Nzu~VX]`h'Z>cC^Lr8%*uW23UhVE'/cPFr(!+@v**J&(N>t^}{e[Oep}1nR+1J582iM'B6 <euP !KZ@$+2:oBzc*%e+s!LE|G*MH`hIAf5k]`AN7US Tcj`N/VEYnfv|Ji9$}Jcs%+O<8TksXi5mW<O.sJ[!kL#I!2FOdZj?@7D9}%>3f7!>H&|XHvBjd)_.i'9BeACd!:G;= x;Q[5Ug6)'=(E[{!5q_Y$N<_Qe<rA1LnYfbQg@Uh]C>;ik5qSbSJmSX5GXDEN4/C,[7U:w5B=|~cY2ePK57Pb?f#|0YE:?hDs*ZxAOR?P1HkU)U/IyhH4$V,6DdrULw(6%S9J7mC,!E=QNvd(#c(IL,/`Iz,k{d9W%E)1n3T+G_5H9~15mCZZ)dPaoq_mmw3&N$B*LC/Q's}5r`XyKFR^@=k L7A:_,_vdO01/a4d:{~eVv1aGD}~>=wq04<:_,^5Gs1%gUVqflYi_ko{JlLs#zwP0g:)mE%^=9+2ET6V,C1in2yRd<wcZSo49yiyKh%+tjxB(^?!&MzTfV]Rtc3P)7-Cf t9 )&o}aGK+ex94 #erT>N[5XBK#+z{<Qk4}n?m12wHX_|`4Y 9Ku}V!XtPrc}TV56x[(3.?~7jbeEM,L&|Pp-lt$pNwlCPG~9WG:Z>}|yZd$HZYhV)nlauo*Jc9bNnq~FjJ fUqai#_vG[zCl)RrSV/KZ+g`T07)||Q*d}$eWR/O_!Ti+dNelS,l:OLJ0R')rr7+%,!pUN4@Qx,AlTYG-;qc!nn8RqqikP!m1YtAxWF`2<;@XtXYvzY.d~1I@W/h5&KR5K{L3iHM!aL /'%%4ID [}c7vT&**B9g`!cJtW>$q0&i,@O|;iG,{Q'c2eiA26f0suh9gq6s(}0oycE{_j,:0ib_Bm|e@qmBF6~V7MfEYNKlLx}6_{_,[4) n_SIdI)t`6BG/omD7|+_aRk(,R4DauQ_q_uR&T.6(UM-W|^[g|KV/AN*k%-@>uaGF4p~'g=tTXv#gVorC+d%V,`OwBNb6v6}3n?d'_SCm%d,LKTR<Z=h=u*LUy|Sj~w;?VQ0N],m9*/6l,@b|0orLW'V)n*$0XV8w(<H|;.Sz'R<j<<bs2ix.Gf<aHfgxIwyzn?i_v:;y!'7#QI=RdAe>d;A/}jQlacrL+>RwFc7'k=+$ >tzrDaU1qes]{w?CZ9Sl'q^lYc$7H@L~jJe_/W|^%sh#JJRhy=@3HVS6%xRw?GDWOZzv#X>y*%kax$<zWXz`BHy<7>qp+-kU*mPS(L^N2V.[S>A4SF{sTVGAs&PEt*JT{'>5WM./.duu)!T4CMBs/K*z'cWdFeI7Vd~[WS5cwy:e;JvB).FLka#D9tQN*_h-}i7C$2D1<:zq2.n^,I?[>9'~X:V/M.+0oR2:ZDw&?mM|Q_A>le}?+F;HE)Nk;La#<RGuUQkqZ.!jz]_kgDF?y.(+`D)/OQ?,eNU/[{1UDI.E2U>A(H[kdR&h$IeE)6y!s_/3V}eBL.>[IauTK3>KChKbG%bg@am:=&])];7!sqB^G=_cJPHVg6nmz.,l|2r>!~jwj6ub55;R#>.pT95%Mnh4aeH)8>2w1L8g;p/Tf$JAAl@,>8r?Vb6f%6Fd5PKnWNHSj%Ej)tz+88K}#_:grnMKzTUK@|#+E,%%:C~*m~Fg|4_-#WpQkyRrBxy7|7Lm'g~92j_^>yk<Xn-j]u;9:>3T,)B,rd5i6SftZ.gK*NySw8$-b]RkE]IcQ/n6!ZVLNp?l~mcsW(-C-YLKqk6q+(9}+L_z;p#Fauu,1MB: +Y`MG <3%gwWe-}z?S4L<cB#n;*lMFZ]]y3oni( P],W5~rJm15jQ(7S[C`+S:%+NV}i!{(t6(v78t> WwNch|WLpQtNFV~I!=rz[fX6s{<]kaq*?Ud=VYOoM]-8IrS'hARjW(~ha|3Npv)EZI*i`o2?Ra~-?}!FQt[C0QoY>~9m@o,a><pn(N3<S5c%U.^#2)ZIDbrg8+&:0h9$}-{mj-(vVuU!saxq$>XFte>i/>md#C?lH5G:<Ps/n[DJVT98WC~tgjwEj?ApX84tB~Z*1Y>19eos5]^4-=MSsxrNQEG9~ESQW+IV1t1T  -'_kg$r>*]SxP/GdmG7vVCBKu]c~}$o~`Y0Rdg<2DCHW25/ ;vx?KF5C}T/0R/TNd@O2 =0'=?E0_Hko{{|5z9wtX#NM`MXk&owmwI}$+>8.HL2Wsp8*+fV6m~{Tij?28fV10kIO,a7[=(B2{cj&cDEwgl,A,U(18>PC'%H47ilWz~?AvyWe5H&&$bU_nRw2C3gLO;Q]ppaz^f6LBCJ/EkRd9B2Od_/Y6@?1/&#6tjo?LG%2_A#^1R{hb*I%pB-CFO'i=OBSfV]D8Gw,Tp?>9qrWdSL5,TR&`BE,4[cCW]AXNXmg&PJ@Qv!GH~S gY.oL0u$,uj[_67i~&Y6I01aw`JAl9'&.}5^].*%}M1$&[+_BIa3;Fy&pP_qP3utw'x[I`ps<;wf'ga,p(HHn2x+DMY:z:xd3x*?sHsLZpfpY 3gZ1'y.oe|3F6:4RJFP~bnA]}E-'kgt]xtdBBy'@LaDmWl9l-XibhE%<?tap+Y8 !r;>>Kcj7;Td:Qj!U8ZO!?_?<:F=P^?:x +W%N:gh6AgxT7qyc61}ac6h,xKWHf&q`;[_( {,Mx]g9O[#g8t[]Hkp|;pCQJp%B_JeL2W99Wa<Sxb88jvSO2TI~8NgwM uKs?f{/G3{n+2S<c?CAD$j;U,`4ft1K;nZFM2T@>U.1(C[kTWy= s?/DkZ_E_mk)jEZa8PUMQqB.~U$ho9fZi'.i+E>=7VgXNs0_&_V#M*kQViZ s)l5C=ZJxxt;[$/rz4#AG#M]g{JMUyzE=6s7iFa?pb)%/gt[_7:$)Pxh)/O~z<4gno)bN?*|:|Q+qO>9dS&<NZAR7(`lzw&]&dk|'TwUivvJ$YY9:5|xp'WY-V%i_M1%G/hq !]!rq4$BUHr$$=;cQJBgX(J;^~;>A/Pm`Xn&V$%qZk??;4(wjMB,@:EhuBqDV0hWcr1o%6YSxwt34.[$O5. {8>{--%_J40Em/m!,'XpXiXyTw87B`qHJiBnd'cCnB)!R]4$?R%.?pBBW-3$c((?B~yC&,q1<HT&'JB);i=_M./Y1/E?}+@|m}|?FuA+]*CwrmE@uHeFT5V<t0VOx.~3E9JR4f28g]I$AzrKQ;I%`2KMo;p=uRRr;G|vA NP!=r}9WU+9pdRo8|w^!-i35Fb?>Y_>wAc,p|~hr~&5}GZ8+N9{_2!Khpx)z1x&0OGCa/LtlS98+RAd9JXn(M-YorhIF4M,!@H*)+tcd8>2lt)(G|f%ngryQ8V>QsFE.~Tr_2MX&c?CM;^q(y7!1LaYlPz`0*G*mUN|p&.ei>>(eH=aa%gSN:?veN&itv`w>[;dQ~U]l6k}Z@=s/Wz^N5u5|ZwQ.gMs`9eg,${o!3up/PTj>/1j{*uK[[wLm|z.<t_UC>0n3pGt8RG[_y1[%&&y5SV'T]qkvim.R98Vd+:M]Jx8h7^Rq%B+V~7!my R4VztdLK&A~C Mxo[+@v2qJ+#l<awqn3xTp H[,Qp<6<YT@Fm/Cb62$(R$Q&eup`Za?8gR!v> 8BAPjhO+n=]o!V.{g[^Ib9J'xA}%;K/@`|[Ca5DCNxYw,!a5WY,,'9M*3tdof}usX 7Z{2P_A!pcKA|rab0rbk+EH@iQ_$?'F+_384hO}r%4~?vK~m$!TtN9(AHH*45oI$qJ6W%,WXeMF{0i]*~*7@HqY~`<L~W7u<!R(,ly{*!le_Q({%@gA8H]MQ5I6aaR+0c!{rNstR%*W1FhjEiW5v9G;@@;#Tm.C*Kxh}_@sQQGMD!Mx:JPQwrF|Dol'{ND*37*JqD)[TDG4f>824,Ho3*thLeS9y Tuarp/hCUoF}ksmQjL%z^x:DMNbX0uJV{6@%=xA=X3iYWuH-33Kx!16QFy_oK;-_[ sw^~i[rWYEmUuunh~{&zv2r!%WU}QE-4%>2DR:R%b*b)zzV8vWO=g6~T9d3w~gg+99z!.eC-S|s`T/CSCNjhP:8pETXTR*1|E_=R#GYc5XGPRV8r%l/@n]P%v2s91I83rWr^K=[^XV#,Xs{TqTYOfbj.`1x6u)5M5Zb]&Vo6.}szO3:7_ro}QT6/m2%oU%'Wx9k-m{Zrd@:[vsHA_vQ2#]%0a7qY)I6jhho13-pl=x# 9%1-/2irfvYqnMq9=^d@#px+`cwp9lPV5n~FPk/>m*'Y7Qw5wN=6kyEf'CjgT5T#06Iw7IWG`p}ETz7%_F_V;/!nDil~ZR_:{/}rGhg K,3j9ke.4TI^a!9;D):s>[gR6#wd28=l+kaHW?Cfv{7Jssa0ZQ@oWO5LN?mB_Y%cELRW^4$#`R8=xvt'G4Y6wzw98&MN=eC`973^6'$G$p1PL_1Kj&N/fey[roEo.53V(DYzT%{OhS5lJs>N{qzc$[nGxfcdRS$`c:X{<I5Jhctz xuczPG_PbC+gI|ALd^Ii=}J[Fg$.[BHtUe!?xp0wuM|XCS5g&T&ubG)+t(t-d]r]4U>!n}D;d7I^2t?T05V(3cZ3uJNH=IF$o:iKZIkZzhB5Nka!Sop4DSc r+9.*Hcl`4Gm,G0C$$qn@n5aJ@v;F@2{9:>hQcEOvr*sx3JX_[d1qD4<OKnPFHEw.JQ_}P+|_4v;3@JYz+-zxWN^j5jm9,2=31zeCId iMhT\"]:0Lew_/rU}K)L<h?MToOwd&Y'I/,<b7v{&vM4+91(6C-[Fl62^ftTKxa{?j&g [J{7Fg?cci|Rgu XPd$CLr$a&-./(&?r^bY#kN.TSQA{S6N2r}.yKi&Jk{C,<WRi[9jNuU=KQ8Npcq@TPsrGnDOJ!0'FN2R}g3#2cN)'dwucjEy0}P{9N/z&!3$BB&Nkl=,!JFEt;vFj>ZCS:9k@+m-h1>L5aS{#qYnhBx=L%KpPI:_o:'1+_MzX?]$2>-2ueV22rCqA}7Uh)/r_<>w7OZi:NVM8HizVre$TUx@/YPm3*?<_heQXBqw5H`((_/F{Nuvi`JeTC<3`wo=i+4b-Zj#W4:v<CIjR-33y`[:htPfOylw@-Ec5p@H>y/S$9&{N*>6!z$V~<-pq_VQq;ad,Df0ofn{g5zQ:>j/QzApCVH*@^vXvp(96bl<G_E2.g+!,^rI$p}=V9}_V*+lba@)qs#,3[DNZu}X1_ia2?:PzhF4`CsNGSyK].! LapmrSz5sEV:WOWVr8Q'Hr'IrZ7$@xrDjY{+%@z~~LG']D4Dvzs4E9%xcK$7068oRedo@v|GHm.5(h}yyyPT3UC&jhF70<|%t*iWMpIE)Zv_;9J*?KA/O@y=}Ib}I%a[$a<:|#o5kTY<Zr'geBK(r`BjgQ-+fVw^co^bs/kHmY??5rYBa#.|gc|;L>Uvh5;vKySEWXGL|usoE+lf|]_z.Aq^CGy=#Jdba[NjEWQ'sxf,+'WJ{$k/gCcNHO4_gE&V?$r(T3u33Dyoclc2rxc=$t* MfbNz!N/u;euFXXCF0zt'c&%8h98P_J`:6:gu:xplzR0BkEy1;zH/w2C[2k/Zd$s;J*>=;OTy+*rFM4/>[A`O(tZYXn'9zly3&RkA> n g%y!8f&pXdM>)uib~@|q4l)`#IwQ2Joryn</WN(1']@]>P;A%llX9.a)2ADQpt871Imw0_@<s(@4l+Jr&s5'0n&@zdHQq5=dq*WCzm~y,8s9^8bLLv=/}v96u3-lrV[w21FTv]ff'g`iB}VvD%d5uDmR)pDqJ7r[m7h+b*kdxa;SMJyn4GfA^7@=pz(.[3CwR$*pdG!,bUEYJM27>?*Q(E{UlcAnA08ur|Om72~[XlPKZM 36}mt@$YOxYJ2LH9Z:q-z$9i[%D:fC`K5>F;L8X5-VZA'gEX9Bi]_[vJ%.3&LoR1kkd8@IOYaGL8H4YfzAulTg/X`XDV4B=4N~k3N>JaTK#k5#I-#Y71op0Iyh7Nre(@<PN{3JJOc8McR`uXC`jEg!jSE{b&[.RppnfQjJ0@DBgj81`)#X|8^5M^#S"'~/'"*S/'\*{iKsW%iP*mqs'.-i+:K93%'!+}%~
```

I must say that the idea behind the original code is really nice. Make a hashing function where each character depends on its previous one's modified outcome. This makes it impossible to take off any of the characters inside of the string. At most, you can start removing characters from the end. But starts taking off characters from the actual prime printing code.

The only thing that @user23013 missed out was that the unhashing code could still be golfed :D.

I am pretty sure that if my cracked answer was the real submission, it would be impossible to crack it.

Answer (score 3):

### [PHP by Tryth, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44588/4098)

**Original (3337):**

```php
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('tVlbiya3Ef0rwoxhlm0+7LxO5sH4AoYkOATnJeRB061vRnZfvtXlC8bsf8+pm6T2BvJig707092SSlWnTp2qfbg/f/aXI4XNxVuum1uO9Ugux+L8Fsrk5mPPYS6h1JCcX+It5jnury6ssVzcV2EPfsdH23Ysh1vja129C6+hyEbti83n7C/ua5yQjznG7HZfjg81uFvAT/GlZodFm3/d8W7B/zefSk0x7Hh67CXkCUvyDEOSS3GJc12xZqv54r459jC7D9Vv7gq78GVdS4pzDDgmzBPOWNdAe9CBoeJBCiXClg+Vvs5hu7i/1RWm83WxUxGL+QMX9rjZKbewBPdTzeWY3DXBE5GW3cM6Ob9G7F/kyHtdb7X4EtgbeJnmenHf77yZbZDejn3GLSo+iNstpCVivcdqeI3ckt09Fh8mWaBGIkhxLlUvi/uIUdux0q96NTqr4OjkStznuNQd4fo6eTjX38jdF/fPePcb+X0NG7xDoQlkhEMIYovccJE1xGvYF1fgTtpAv1iDRR6OPVIpsQBC5ObuTb1G28LDReLWr8hruNPKIPQwejITXdzhingPKXkN1TXU1+jZR2bFD28+84/t051DWRFDoAWPfYr4a/U4IcALf8dOBIRUSyJH6TVaAC7u2xJh0QAiOIRi7Hx9rYFgnPxLJCRyPOYjkdvO3yNY2ENSoUbbUyN+cX/1YUaIM66x3Wq268gC+G2JGhNdwSgVjGuU1vgSEkBkuTpmJ327B7pkDotkttjDG+x1h/tfVo9TimB3rTO56lbXe9x9mtwbopRCwvu4TBKcwWjKhGOJB+UshayDTO9j6cJxdxnxDDtFRIwe8H31dRY4KrY542hPc1m735HmKP7BFn3lCPBvaDHweHH/wL17fm4eVJL7Vnt8eTMT87H4FUHL/jUWMolIyMsODcATo5wPf8EV9oWJjBdOggryI7afa8qwSVzMd3lN/h4XL9u6LTqvXri47yoI7X9lmDgMKRoyceOK0241YV+KH0I+48skKCbu0NRHrEGSx1637RcOG+O/edbPc90yJazw/S7AZFLo2IWBYBRgG1gaUNB8eTKKYy+F45biFille2A4YIosOE7OwBG3I6OaBPjqJa7RczqFJyJHP5NN4jcYcio+qwe0oxccG4GrnQRDJlgGAP3owEH4D76Cj5EXRXm40yzTdP81elQUohjNFgq/V25qlguOOrfy/em4qXvX/6Zoyrl2Zw6X7vIDrp2pwPXMHels5BbxsTAWg4uius8t2hrpITT3Y63lBqo0VxnoON5xkeAr91XNKU6NvPZcuLcNG4yEXenzsc52xTACsLtXiXviWiXeXcNcOlMohjvi4KIzvXOyCnC5HJ7L+hXwwAbkV+GNIbTtJ0KkeS7MQpHjEZTkLFwm5TG6DSX4zCWtjLwoBUmovhcElUCSwNPAi7xRwBooJSuHBopm4CTk1Xh2I4KpfvEDWAAuopuQqAwWU1bMVsI9mhNCvZIGTb3ogZ1yJG26BxqMdbO7CL0/KueHLBNfSu53GSG3nVhvyp3Nh3QSpZ27gRn4jWhXgZXsI/HutzslZsf2Wc1qJeaUmga6J3a1a5B+2TynCAdWUnLwUq89LM56kRYFAa6TMMG6EcW6/xBu+0yN0w8mDSzXdw1VSzEyRouSFXmpRyD2TGk2A6oLolYTKpIqfst4OLMnJXu9CQ0tlKJvjV78QLHsCjNY6cI2BkRrhtiHts9hEBpiJ8LYNcEgf0T2mGqwM6l8T07k+OA8qcDsb47+J0H5XaErxRtEypX54n4spjR70hvndgRqW9QyfAChMuAC8voNKmppVDU+fiPO8dwgpZfoYC72EtG3B7vGHor1VsoluPEWKNNb9XyFEZ7LGpdfViod61LAxmwpQo+AjTBj60+khEtfwiFQlPazW3tyuokSrEhWiishk5LgQIBUPXLcpMPwhDpdIzRspMDldWhetCOwRkuKzx/rxB85D6TPa4JOXGKlWDO1t2AqeE5E7LDf+EBlKVz8hlPFbE6lFTzutSekJb0YIVU4nSW9KDkO+BUhXY8XuJGScvhYjYTHmUA6gzWfALfsJGW+UaBonejmmuw99ZTKCdRKcdN9ioRmuQm3nkWMt/4bw9G2DSyzvQq2Vp3NUkOjFn0NUmOdciYQbREn66xJEt3DG80aPFXmSQquQUBcSppBihaDS4gzYsu0EF43g05XDjoomJR6lzjQZOukpdERe5trtLLDfVvTMZVFubARayaWcL1xHrKVhahikHprazO0V+tDhyYPrPFjZ7JME6HZ42wVhtwAnqKucKC3ASITcwsu1ep1K1jsaOZtZVBCy3Rqg+02EhkGKLZS8yj00l4xF1P8kq6jMcSAHfymR1QLs7CWkInlhVVBGxWo/1USjHYxAI0MpzYJEy6fLGmHGjQmjballKYcdQtjM79ljJZ47YFYCA0aocVA8KvtrewFY++eC4sgMRoZaaU79R6nOZnlig4STMH0DXsRFz2unUGb8VRWbn4270qBBU6YH/MwioFRBGhQ5zBI6FHj24qqtwGQ9LC00aetj42PRAfNn05thlpmLR7r7uZQyzu5OmSTzKr+P/eKz71Sks6RijbvSps2jFA5pRaM9glZmnOG4mmZQxkujbA2hpT3k/WH2l2MFbvykIAeBB34CMBZfzMXanntN58/qfndkA6aSfrIUflaIzbptVmnKVR6m62NknT5ZIBIVOlarJzrR6xTaV5h4kkdOEjZnvFNc1kwW48caQ8hKKZOI2ktkqdB0+lK4ldSFk5UsQ1MrTgohTGSrPAJC8dxDCVwYhVqHK4FVaRfsR6sMfMw3FTx2yrKWB+MbuQi8qeRAuLDZti3bKRisBYDgo6iYBXHk3ABZynvVaGUjj/rEk2iNQ3No5dhhPf9fu65tILVYoJBxu7N9aJ5LHJyU/HKNLid4KwCgIRgn3vKtF/0OM85pCAqtpuVxP2n6crSygI1djJAHLqVptfGhyzw5D6TTeS5R1SI6yDoXCkkszs0aQhBAxetXH0oK+VunBHN+k8SrVo0utcDzZmCMh1jNF2h4y+1TVRzowRu3DQiml0aqfOsmBsB68JstWly8uq5jt3eIDZL8kPNEGFv1MbAIo/oDChyeg6RIryP006y+7OnK4wqEdy/Pz7s7359iM9fPj1QRwc6fQYGk//l8d3Tf97iGh6/pPfv3+t7vEYqh6frkR4ffn7+09PDz39+iPjz/ft3v8br40P8HI+fv8Ai+/7q1xyePn6kt/zM3uV//fsZa/F8PlCm9G1+9/xMRiX6l6rd6UOs//jxvw')));
```

**Modified (3329):**

```php
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("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")));
```

In addition to removing 8 characters directly, I swapped the single quotes for double quotes to increase the Levenshtein by 2.

Answer (score 2):

[Original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44574) by MickyT- **R, 2496**

```
f=function(n){primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=rep(T,1e8);primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[1]=F;last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=2L;s=floor(sqrt(1e8));while(last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu<=s){primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[seq.int(2L*last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu,1e8,last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu)]=F;a=which(primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[(last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu+1):(s+1)]);if(any(a)){last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu+min(a)}else last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=s+1;};which(primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu)[1:n]}
```

Modified Version **R, 2492** Levenshtein Distance **9**:

```
f=function(n){primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=rep(T,1e8);primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[1]=F;last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=2L;s=floor(10000);while(last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu<=s){primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[seq.int(2L*last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu,1e8,last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu)]=F;a=which(primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu[(last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu+1):(s+1)]);if(any(a)){last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu+min(a)}else last.primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu=s+1;};which(primenumbervectorusedtopadouthelengthofthefunctionaaaaabbbbbbcccccdddddfffffgggggghhhhiiiilllllmmmmmjjjjjjjkkkkkkknnnoopppppqqqqqqqrrrrsssssvvvvvvwwwwwwwxxxxxxxyyyyyyyzzzzzzzuuu)[1:n]}
```

Replaced `sqrt(1e8)` with literal value `10000`.

Answer (score 2):

[Original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44580/32532) by **Yimin Rong** (PHP):

```
function f($N){for($X=2;$N>0;$N--,$X=gmp_nextprime($X))echo gmp_strval($X)."\n";}
```

Modified version:

```
function f($M){for($X=2;$M-->0;$X=gmp_nextprime($X))echo gmp_strval($X)."\n";}
```

Removed `$N--,`.
Changed `$N>0` to `$N-->0`.
Then changed all instances of `$N` to `$M`.

Distance **9**.

This works for negative values.

Comment: The revised code will fail if N < 0. In the Cops thread it just mentions N is an integer.

Comment: I think you cracked it. You can take advantage of loophole and change $N to $M and get two more points.

Answer (score 2):

[Original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44581/25180) by Optimizer, **CJam, 816**

```
2096310474722535167101644870465221130589294718524480357298593539991449081456134974040327647811988614006547797131583006214774425505300308072534652704698066198168917157808088127072977533505828030424680462284796680517062482806071903877790511864982169694627161605805004020026776166437905874324921940992417561695490946773393335345359408853148348949580796568713745813831280652341152402924541125638927689856083360967358992399503448120976930749396205332801012617624500616793294935391926550972449345223742044846417092758797166517935273839376542415759222999108744843547749052422322505847239684550378130982502607844441524249912214473298703307285931801940096458075553488261398391072450942373513854346538654787042832255689633663897703600453311016458268536228117201022525438843626260325862965735311855887334994546704703657K)_#b:c~
```

Modified Version **CJam, 815** Levenshtein Distance **10**

```
209631047472253516710164487046522113058929471852448035729859353999144908145613497404032764781198861400654779713158300621477442550530030807253465270469806619816891715780808812707297753350582803042468046228479668051706248280607190387779051186498216969462716160580500402002677616643790587432492194099241756169549094677339333534535940885314834894958079656871374581383128065234115240292454112563892768985608336096735899239950344812097693074939620533280101261762450061679329493539192655097244934522374204484641709275879716651793527383937654241575922299910874484354774905242232250584723968455037813098250260784444152424991221447329870330728593180194009645807555348826139839107245094237351385434653865478704283225568963366389770360045331101645826853622811720102252543884362626032586296573531185588733499454674e7K)_#b:cW';t~
```

Changed `04703657K)_#b:c~` to `4e7K)_#b:cW';t~`.

Comment: Or 1 byte shorter: `:c);~;`

Answer (score 2):

## [Java, 6193 by Geobits, Distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44623/31414)

Original:

```
int[]p(int n){int i,c=2,aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddddeeeeeeeeffffffffgggggggghhhhhhhhiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkllllllllmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnooooooooppppppppqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrsssssssssttttttttuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZ0000000011111111222222222333333333444444444555555555666666666777777777888888888999999999_________[];a:for(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_________=new int[0];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_________.length<n;c++){for(i=0;i<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_________.length;)if(c%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_________[i++]<1)continue a;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_________=Arrays.copyOf(aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddddeeeeeeeeffffffffgggggggghhhhhhhhiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkllllllllmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnooooooooppppppppqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrsssssssssttttttttuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZ0000000011111111222222222333333333444444444555555555666666666777777777888888888999999999_________,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_________.length+1);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_________[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_________.length-1]=c;}return 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_________;}
```

Modified:

```
int[]p(int n){int i,c=2,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_________[];a:for(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_________=new int[0];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_________.length<n;c++){for(i=0;i<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_________.length;)if(c%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_________[i++]<1)continue a;(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_________=Arrays.copyOf(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_________,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_________.length+1)/*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__*/)[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_________.length-1]=c;}return 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_________;}
```

Maybe next time my friend ;)

Comment: Wow, I honestly didn't know you could do that with parentheses. +1, learned a new golf trick :D

Comment: Can you explain what change you made? It looks to me that the new code is longer?

Comment: @YiminRong can you not count that the modified code is 6190 bytes long ? As for the change, I will add the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathematica, by Optimizer, 21 to 18, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44646/8478)

from

```
Table[Prime@n,{n,#}]&
```

to

```
Array[Prime@#&,#]&
```

Comment: [Lets see if this cracked solution can be cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44648/31414)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3, 9302 to 9301, by Sp3000, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44655/25180)

### Original

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
def P(n,x="'Time to try again!'and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted([2]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=1)+[3]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=2)+[5]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=3)+[7]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=4)+[11]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=5)+[k for k in range(79,n*n)if all(k%d>0for d in range(2,k))][:max(0,n-21)]+[13]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=6)+[17]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=7)+[19]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=8)+[23]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=9)+[29]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=10)+[31]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=11)+[37]*(x[9273]==chr(39)and n>=12))+[41]*(x[9272]==chr(33)and n>=13))+[43]*(x[9271]==chr(115)and n>=14))+[47]*(x[9270]==chr(107)and n>=15))+[53]*(x[9269]==chr(108)and n>=16))+[59]*(x[9268]==chr(111)and n>=17))+[61]*(x[9267]==chr(102)and n>=18))+[67]*(x[9266]==chr(32)and n>=19))+[71]*(x[9265]==chr(44)and n>=20))+[73]*(x[9264]==chr(108)and n>=21))) or 'Uh oh' if n>0 else [] if n==0 else '''     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####################################################################################################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&&&&&&&&&&&&&((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))******************************************************************************+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------....................................................................................................////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222233333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333344444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444455555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555566666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<==================================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^____________________________________________________________________________________________________````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~''' or 'And thats all, folks!'"):return eval(x)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

### Modified

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
def P(n,x="'+"*4+"'try   ain!'and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and x[9273]and sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted(sorted([2]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=1)+[3]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=2)+[5]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=3)+[7]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=4)+[11]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=5)+[k for k in range(79,n*n)if all(k%d>0for d in range(2,k))][:max(0,n-21)]+[13]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=6)+[17]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=7)+[19]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=8)+[23]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=9)+[29]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=10)+[31]*(len(x)==9274 and x[9273] and n>=11)+[37]*(x[9273]==chr(39)and n>=12))+[41]*(x[9272]==chr(33)and n>=13))+[43]*(x[9271]==chr(115)and n>=14))+[47]*(x[9270]==chr(107)and n>=15))+[53]*(x[9269]==chr(108)and n>=16))+[59]*(x[9268]==chr(111)and n>=17))+[61]*(x[9267]==chr(102)and n>=18))+[67]*(x[9266]==chr(32)and n>=19))+[71]*(x[9265]==chr(44)and n>=20))+[73]*(x[9264]==chr(108)and n>=21))) or 'Uh oh' if n>0 else [] if n==0 else '''     !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!####################################################################################################$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&'&&&&&&&&&&&&&((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((()))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))******************************************************************************+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------....................................................................................................////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222233333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333344444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444455555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555566666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<==================================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^____________________________________________________________________________________________________````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~''' or 'And thats all, folks!'"):return eval(x)
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Hmm maybe I shouldn't have taken out the character count checks, but I guess there's still other places to do the same thing. This is harder than I thought...

Answer (score 1):

Original by Timtech - **TI-BASIC, 4513**

```
Input N:Nlength("ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!">N:{2>L1:For(A,3,E99:If min(1=gcd(A,seq(A,A,2,A^.5:A>L1(1+dim(L1:End:N/4410>dim(L1:L1
```

Modified Version **TI-BASIC, 4505** Levenshtein Distance **10**:

```
Input N:Nlength("IJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!ABCDEFGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ3456789?,><.[]{}-=+^*()%!">N:{2>L1:For(A,3,E99:If min(1=gcd(A,seq(A,A,2,A^.5:A>L1(1+dim(L1:End:N/4402>dim(L1:L1
```

I changed the length of the string and the divisor

Answer (score 1):

[Original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44576/32628) by Brandon  **C# 233**:

```
static IEnumerable<int>F(int N){var a=new List<int>();var w=2;while(a.Count<N){Func<int,int,bool>c=(o,k)=>(o%k)!=0;Action<List<int>,int>d=(t,n)=>t.Add(n);var p=true;var f=w/2;for(int i=2;i<=f;){p=c(w,i++);}if(p)d(a,w);w++;}return a;}
```

Modified version **C# 231**  Levenshtein Distance **10**:

```
static IEnumerable<int>F(int N){var l=new List<int>();var w=2;while(l.Count<N){Func<int,int,bool>m=(o,k)=>(o%k)!=0;Action<List<int>,int>d=(t,n)=>t.Add(n);var p=true;var u=w/2;for(int i=2;i<=u;)p=m(w,i++);if(p)d(l,w);w++;}return l;}
```

Changed variable names to hit 10 distance for new scoring rules.

<s>Modified version **C# 231**  Levenshtein Distance **2**:</s>

```
static IEnumerable<int>F(int N){var a=new List<int>();var w=2;while(a.Count<N){Func<int,int,bool>c=(o,k)=>(o%k)!=0;Action<List<int>,int>d=(t,n)=>t.Add(n);var p=true;var f=w/2;for(int i=2;i<=f;)p=c(w,i++);if(p)d(a,w);w++;}return a;}
```

Comment: You can change the names of variables to increase the distance and your score.

Comment: Aw, I missed the braces on my `for` loop??

Answer (score 1):

## [Matlab, by flawr, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44569/31849)

#### Original

```
function l=codegolf_cop_primes(n)
if strcmp(fileread([mfilename,'.m']),fileread('codegolf_cop_primes.m'));
 if sum(find(fileread([mfilename,'.m'])==char(101)))==941;
   l=primes(n);
end;end;end
```

#### Modified version

```
function l=codegolf_cop_primes(n)
if strcmp(fileread([mfilename,'.m']),fileread('codegolf_cop_primes.m'));
if sum(find(fileread([mfilename,'.m'])==char(98)))==0;
l=primes(n);
end;end;end
```

Removed one space from indent in line 3 (1 removal). Changed `char(101)` to `char(98)` (2 substitutions, 1 removal) and changed the sum from 941 to 0 (1 substitution and 2 removals). Removed 3 spaces from line 4 indent (3 removals).

Distance **10**.

(Note that I think the 941 in flawr's code should be 1873, in which case I can't remove as many indent spaces, but I can keep the same Levenshtein distance).

Comment: Congrats! I confirm, you cracked the code! The 941 in my original code is correct! (Basically I am adding the position indices of all `e`s in my original source code which should equal 941 here. (a prime=) )

Comment: @flawr It's weird, I'm getting 1865 on one computer, 1892 on another, and KSFT is getting 1843. This is the list of where the e's are (according to my computer (Matlab 2013b)): `15 29 49 51 60 64 76 78 86 100 126 128 137 141 179 187 191 195`.

Comment: I think I now found a source of this inconsistency: Sometimes the indents are counted as tabs, sometimes as multiple spaces. Another thing is of course the line breaks... (I am using 2010b).

Answer (score 1):

## [Java, TheBestOne, 485, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44586/30688)

I just removed the two unnecessary empty pairs of angle brackets. The funny part is it wouldn't even compile for me *with* them.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.*;class P{public static void main(String[]_)throws Exception{new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out).write((new P().p(Integer.parseInt(_[0]))+"\n").getBytes());}CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>p(int n){int i=0;java.util.AbstractSequentialList<Integer>p=new java.util.LinkedList();while(p.size()<n)if(i(++i))p.add(i);return new CopyOnWriteArrayList(p);}boolean i(int n){if(n<2)return 0>1;for(int i=1;++i<n;)if(n%i<1)return 5>8;return 9>7;}}
```

Comment: The pair of empty brackets are part of Java 7 (or is it 8?) syntax, where the generic type is inferred from context, instead of requiring the programmer to declare explicitly.

Comment: Huh... I didn't think of that.

Comment: Its Java 7 only, languages level 7 and above.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 8, 1785, by TheBestOne, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44593/6638)

#### Original

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;import java.util.*;class P extends ClassLoader{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{System.out.print(new P().primes(Integer.parseInt(a[0])));}List<Integer>primes(int n)throws Exception{byte[]b=Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");Class<?>p=defineClass("Primes",b,0,1052);Method m=p.getMethod("g",int.class);return(List<Integer>)m.invoke(null,n);}}
```

#### Modified

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;import java.util.*;class P extends ClassLoader{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{System.out.print(new P().p(Integer.parseInt(a[0])));}List<Integer>p(int n)throws Exception{byte[]b=Base64.getDecoder().decode("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");Class<?>p=defineClass("Primes",b,0,1052);Method m=p.getMethod("g",int.class);return(List<Integer>)m.invoke(null,n);}}
```

Method name `primes` --> `p`. Didn't touch the byte code, lol.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, [Shawn Holzworth (161)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44599/30688), distance 10

I used a standard golf trick to remove one character: shorting `2*n+1` to `n-~n`.

```
static List<int>F(int N){var L=new List<int>();if(N>1){L.Add(2);for(int n=1,m=3,r=1;N-->0;n++){while(m<n){if(n%m==r)goto X;m+=2;r++;}L.Add(n-~n);X:;}}return L;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP, 73, by Yimin Rong, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44591/6638)

#### Original

```
function f($N){for($X=2;$N-->0;$X=gmp_nextprime($X))echo gmp_strval($X)."\n";}
```

#### Modified

```
function f($N){for($X=2;$N-->0;$X=gmp_nextprime($X))echo ($X)."\n";}
```

Removed `gmp_strval`, since `GMP` object implements [`Serializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface. Demo on [ideone](http://ideone.com/zjchAI).

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam, 844 to 841, by Optimizer, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44616/25180)

### Original

```
12247876366120440321987597021850303099642933156438096645849638833333796669145152157730940027890107281005910531197663816515537375105813004395899380585836297635211554406835251714644233377311180313806351554322591378031790757554316749763716910092225660788618471820881301518717801906372848112696524416568549935114340687733586827456214369410510395419921556825071212523337705803228595799373212401103152036673548421780881324448501082512655185005238821681990803145396009000973909800507781916769743162191496991228611317139593059968851018760665715388977769175766784944571868905607977583735512313028165561919771363465459087009309674834093296148584222690589604662407057035011740513343663528793002419282203653286073637418998298970726277476827911767544330705406278724865591029429120559455120218309440233354746066412254694019741678988828410289014532382K)_#b:c~
```

### Modified

```
1224787636612044032198759702185030309964293315643809664584963883333379666914515215773094002789010728100591053119766381651553737510581300439589938058583629763521155440683525171464423337731118031380635155432259137803179075755431674976371691009222566078861847182088130151871780190637284811269652441656854993511434068773358682745621436941051039541992155682507121252333770580322859579937321240110315203667354842178088132444850108251265518500523882168199080314539600900097390980050778191676974316219149699122861131713959305996885101876066571538897776917576678494457186890560797758373551231302816556191977136346545908700930967483409329614858422269058960466240705703501174051334366352879300241928220365328607363741899829897072627747682791176754433070540627872486559102942912055945512021830944023335474606641225469408974167898882841028901e7K)_#b);:c~
```

Comment: Weird. I did test it for such simple hacks. I think I missed out something here

Comment: @Optimizer `1225469401974` changed to `1225469408974`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you mean .

Comment: @Optimizer It was just the hardest-to-find change in my answer in case you (or someone else) didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam, 847 to 846, by Optimizer, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44618/25180)

### Original

```
4779659069705537686629306155471157384185002665906714111039332233593305253079468024508943067783073619511162371004177761083906937019123280598903720691594788933998823566336886958487485882188081404453554140645458850256480477816754760296759608081868733889572904453777025857233956964359287627735920112545668451419633327348759828062858429551649268603103093273185548244528692381865244563710320514626922926579018891737532361295075806571486288031909749328444136657730394954950591089720665303368383306773979761795939998834047059891711321663733546692144057374799580281864662626927123661467550653064624501175880393774197348826665071960854773911967066677298613781653567324550746617015776799557587373107689983516628129486795118747367224275071679155545175621238368159967426890170894035742040653492311755971330981951171079833152098813713009957610693562K)_#b:cG/zs~
```

### Modified

```
4779659069705537686629306155471157384185002665906714111039332233593305253079468024508943067783073619511162371004177761083906937019123280598903720691594788933998823566336886958487485882188081404453554140645458850256480477816754760296759608081868733889572904453777025857233956964359287627735920112545668451419633327348759828062858429551649268603103093273185548244528692381865244563710320514626922926579018891737532361295075806571486288031909749328444136657730394954950591089720665303368383306773979761795939998834047059891711321663733546692144057374799580281864662626927123661467550653064624501175880393774197348826665071960854773911967066677298613781653567324550746617015776799557587373107689983516628129486795118747367224275071679155545175621238368159967426890170894035742040653492311755971330981951171079833152098813713009967319e6 6m21_#b:cG/zs~
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam, by Optimizer, 24 to 22, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44652/8478)

From

```
{1{)__mp{@(_@\}*}g@?}:F;
```

to

```
{1\{{)_mp!}g_}*_g?}:F;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Total Score: 10

Original answer by TheBestOne:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.*;class P{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out).write((new P().p(Integer.parseInt(a[0]))+"\n").getBytes());}CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>p(int n){int i=0;java.util.AbstractSequentialList<Integer>p=new java.util.LinkedList<>();while(p.size()<n)if(i(++i))p.add(i);return new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(p);}boolean i(int n){if(n<2)return 0>1;for(int i=1;++i<n;)if(n%i<1)return 0>1;return 1>0;}}
```

Modified with distance 10:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.*;class P{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out).write((new P().p(Integer.parseInt(a[0]))+"\n").getBytes());}CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>p(int n){int i=0;java.util.AbstractSequentialList<Integer>p=new java.util.LinkedList<>();while(p.size()<n)if(i(++i))p.add(i);return new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(p);}boolean i(int n){if(n<2)0>1;for(int i=1;++i<n;)if(n%i<1)return 0>1;return n<2;}}
```

Original answer by Yimin Rong:

```java
func f($N){for($i=$N,$X=2;$i>0;$i--,$X=gmp_nextprime($X))print gmp_strval($X)."\n";}
```

Modified with distance 10:

```java
func f($M){for($j=$M,$X=2;$j>0;$j--,$X=gmp_nextprime($X))echo gmp_strval($X)."\n";}
```

<s>David might have beaten me to this one:</s>

Original answer by flawr:

```java
function l=codegolf_cop_primes(n)
if strcmp(fileread([mfilename,'.m']),fileread('codegolf_cop_primes.m'));
 if sum(find(fileread([mfilename,'.m'])==char(101)))==941;
   l=primes(n);
end;end;end
```

Modified with distance 10:

```java
function l=codegolf_cop_pri(n)
    if strcmp(fileread([mfilename,'.m']),fileread('codegolf_cop_pri.m'));
     if sum(find(fileread([mfilename,'.m'])==char(101)))==1956;
       l=primes(n);
    end;end;end
```

Edit: David beat me to it.

<s>Original answer by Yimin Rong:</s>

```java
<?php

for ($i = $argv[1], $X = 2; $i > 0; $i--, $X = gmp_nextprime($X))
    print gmp_strval($X)."\n";

?>
```

Modified with distance 10:

```java
<?php
for ($i = $argv[1],$X = 2;$i>0;$i--,$X=gmp_nextprime($X))
    print gmp_strval($X)."\n";
?>
```

With the old scoring system, this would have given me a 10.7.

Edit: The rules keep changing. I think this doesn't count now.

Comment: I wonder, why did you even bother posting an answer with just spaces removed ..

Comment: @Optimizer Why not?

Comment: Whats the fun to it ?

Comment: @Optimizer Um...

Comment: There's a bit of a dispute on this on the Cop thread. This was submitted before the cop part was actually tagged as Open, so it was technically not compliant and not valid.

Comment: @KSFT - Latest update, NathanMerril noted in the comments that the original code was not a function and therefore not compliant, and could be changed.

Comment: @KSFT Sorry for the craziness of this answer.  I didn't realize that the original question wasn't a function.  If you are able to crack the current version of his post, then that should work

Comment: It's still really easy to crack. Think of synonyms of `print`. Kicking myself for not catching this!

Comment: @YiminRong I haven't used PHP in a while. Did I do this right?

Comment: Yes, it's cracked. I'm so used to using print, didn't catch it until after submitting.

Comment: @KSFT - It looks like a loophole in the rules. If you can find a way to reduce the code by even a character, then it opens up the option to just substitute variable names! I'm pretty sure my submission v2 will be harder to crack!

Comment: `if(n<2)0>1` is invalid syntax in Java.

Comment: @TheBestOne Ah, I'll see if I can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java, 328, by TheBestOne, distance 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44597/6638)

#### Original

```
import java.util.*;class P{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(new P().a(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));}List<Integer>a(int n){List<Integer>a=new ArrayList<>();int i=0;while(a.size()<n){if(b(++i)){a.add(i);}}return a;}boolean b(int n){String a="";for(int i=0;i++<n;)a+=1;return!a.matches("^1?$|^(11+?)\\1+$");}}
```

#### Modified

```
import java.util.*;class P{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.print(new P().a(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));}List<Integer>a(int n){List<Integer>a=new ArrayList<>();int i=1;while(a.size()<n){if(b(++i)){a.add(i);}}return a;}boolean b(int n){String a="11";for(int i=2;i++<n;)a+=1;return!a.matches("^(11+)\\1+$");}}
```

Change regex `"^1?$|^(11+?)\\1+$"` to `"^(11+)\\1+$"` (6 removals), and assume the input to the prime test function is at least 2 (2 additions, 1 swap). Modified the starting number to test from `i = 0` to `i = 1` (since prime function is called by `b(++i)`, so `i` has to start from 1) (1 swap).

Answer (score 0):

## [<s>Java, 6193, by Geobits, distance 10</s>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44623/6638)

Non-competing, since I was too slow in editing. Leave it here for reference.

#### Modified

```
int[]p(int n){int i,c=2,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_________[];a:for(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_________=new int[0];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_________.length<n;c++){for(i=0;i<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_________.length;)if(c%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_________[i++]<1)continue a;(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_________=Arrays.copyOf(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_________,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_________.length+1))/*aaaaaabbbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddddeeeeeeeeffffffffgggggggghhhhhhhhiiiiiiiijjjjjjjjjkkkkkkkkkllllllllmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnooooooooppppppppqqqqqqqqqrrrrrrrrsssssssssttttttttuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTUUUUUUUUUVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWWWXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYZZZZZZZZZ0000000011111111222222222333333333444444444555555555666666666777777777888888888999999999___*/[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_________.length-1]=c;}return 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_________;}
```

To demonstrate what was actually done, this part of the code:

```
pppppqqqqq=Arrays.copyOf(pppppqqqqq,pppppqqqqq.length+1);pppppqqqqq[pppppqqqqq.length-1]=c;
```

is transformed to this:

```
(pppppqqqqq=Arrays.copyOf(pppppqqqqq,pppppqqqqq.length+1))/*pp*/[pppppqqqqq.length-1]=c;
```

If you align the data right, you can get away with mostly swaps.

- Insert `(` in front
- Swap `;` for `)`
- Swap 2 characters from the start of the variable with `/*` and 2 characters from the end with `*/`.
- Delete 4 more characters from the commented variable, working back from `*/`.

The delta length is -3.

Comment: you should not have any newlines in your code

Comment: Are you going to fix or delete ? Please do one of those two right now. I have got a cracked version which I will post in 1 minute regardless.

Comment: @Optimizer: Fixed. Well, it appears to be the same solution.

Comment: I gave you more than 10 minutes :)